# Change the way that /Review | Close Votes counts work done

Tags: feature-request, review

The all new /Review system is awesome. On SF we've burned through the Low Quality queue but the Close Vote queue seems stuck at 1.6k.

It appears that the size of the close vote queue is only reduced when a question is actually closed. 
This means that people can do considerable ammounts of work and have little to show for it as they didn't cast many final votes.

[image: Old Display]

I think a better way to count the work would be to sum the total votes currently required to clear the queue. 
Using this accounting method when people work on the task the total will drop by the number of close votes cast so they can see that the work they did achieved something. Presumably Don't Close would do something too.

[image: New Display]

Sure, it's just numbers but numbers matter and seeing them change is more incentive than seeing them stay the same.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting tired of asking people in Chat to cast some close votes...  If I use all my close votes, and harangue people a bit, the total goes down slightly, but it's been stuck at 1.1k (for me) for a couple weeks.

Comment: A problem is that number assumes all posts in the queue need to be closed to be removed; many may be voted "do not close" and thus slip out of the queue. I'm not sure a single number can accurately reflect both of those possible outcomes extrapolated to all posts. Close vote queue definitely needs some love though, it doesn't seem to be going down, unlike the other queues

Comment: @BenBrocka: Do Not close should just remove the question from the queue and remove the number of votes required to close that particular question.

Comment: @Iain it does, but it requires multiple votes. My point's just that it's really hard to estimate how many actions it will really take to wipe out the queue at any given moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The counter seems to be showing the number of questions *you* can vote on.  It's a little hard to tell if you're making progress on a queue with over 1600 votes, as you either have to review every question or have the question be closed (and thus removed from the queue).  However, on a [smaller site](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/review/) you can see this in action.

I see 0 close votes in the queue on JLU because I reviewed them all, but as an anonymous user, there are 15 questions still in the queue.  Clicking "Close", "Do Not Close", and "Not Sure" *all* lower the number for me.

Here's what I see (other queues included to show it's not a time difference):

> [image: Empty close vote queue]

Here's what an anonymous user sees:

> [image: Close vote queue with 15 items]

So unless the counting is different on high-volume and low-volume sites, which I don't think is likely, it already sort of works how you want.  As you review questions in the queue, the number goes down (until people add close votes to questions that previously didn't have any).