# No more low quality posts. Any stats on how they sorted out?

Tags: discussion, review, low-quality-posts

I note that the community has emptied the giant queue of low quality posts in /review.

Are there any statistics as to the disposition? What fraction got deleted?

Comment: Nice question. I've been wondering what it means that he queue is (mostly) empty now. Did we get rid of what we wanted to get rid off? How well have the reviewers done their job? Besides a deletion percentage it would be nice to get some idea about the quality of reviews.

Comment: I'm quite sure people are motivated by the ranking. But I'm not sure why I only see the LQ post queue shrinking...

Comment: Content is always deleted here. It helps keep the sites clean of noise.

Comment: Btw, the old LQ queue is still there, with 140k posts.

Comment: @nhahtdh the close vote queue is really hard to empty; that one gets by far my most "not sure"s on the sites I use. Low Quality posts are usually either fine, need editing, or need deleting, less gray area, and less actions needed, depending on the case

Comment: @nhahtdh: I think it's the way they [count the close vote queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144806/change-the-way-that-review-close-votes-counts-work-done)

Comment: I have to admit, they were some tasty tidbits. If my voting is any indication, about 99.9947565% were deleted. Approximately ;)

Comment: I'm tempted to roll back the humor-removal title edit here. Any opinions?

Comment: Go ahead, I was trying to bump the question before the bounty ended, but it didn't work, no answers still.

Answer (score 7):

Good grief... I *know* I had this on my list at one point, but here it is coming up on a year later already...

Well, better late than never. As of September 1st, 2012, 89,470 low-quality reviews had been conducted, with the following outcomes:

```
Reviews Review Result      Final outcome                                  
------- ------------------ ---------------------------------------------- 
   104  Close              90 closed, 11 deleted (0 author-deleted)       
   494  Delete             0 closed, 494 deleted (0 author-deleted)       
  3195  Recommend Deletion 0 closed, 3184 deleted (4 author-deleted)      
   274  Recommend Close    181 closed, 34 deleted (0 author-deleted)      
 81009  Looks Good         324 closed, 3789 deleted (1446 author-deleted) 
  4394  Edit               62 closed, 241 deleted (79 author-deleted)
```

(where "final outcome" represents the state of the questions involved as of 7/27/2013)

As of today, there've been 229,373 low-quality reviews performed, with the following breakdown:

```
Reviews Review Result      Final outcome                                   
------- ------------------ ----------------------------------------------- 
  3423  Delete             0 closed, 3403 deleted (12 author-deleted)      
   646  Recommend Close    417 closed, 161 deleted (13 author-deleted)     
 10029  Edit               151 closed, 953 deleted (291 author-deleted)    
 18311  Recommend Deletion 0 closed, 18065 deleted (65 author-deleted)     
   397  Close              336 closed, 88 deleted (12 author-deleted)      
196574  Looks Good         955 closed, 17329 deleted (9093 author-deleted)
```

Note that due to a bug fixed a few days ago, very few questions were ever reviewed - hence the paltry number of Close and Recommend Close outcomes.

Comment: So the community has started clicking "Looks Good" more regularly then... would you consider [having more than one Looks Good required](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160067/a-single-looks-good-should-not-mean-the-post-is-good)?

Comment: This is implemented for [flagged posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181165/can-flags-send-a-post-into-the-low-quality-posts-review-queue/190639#190639) with multiple flags, @ben.

Comment: Yes, feeling a bit stupid now, but it only applies to flagged posts. I guess how many of the subsequently closed/deleted 18k "looks good" questions had more than one VLQ flag? If it's say 8-9k then you're back to the same success-rate as you were at the beginning.

Comment: A couple hundred, @ben. But remember, about 9K were self-deleted, so not necessarily a great indicator of something that should've been removed in the queue. Of the ~8K remaining, 4700 were mod-deleted (most likely in response to flags) - assuming those were all correctly removed, that's only a hair over a 2% failure-rate. I think we can probably afford to err on the side of not making it *too* easy to delete posts this way: the stated criteria for VLQ flags (*embarrassingly* bad) **should** set a rather high bar for this.

Comment: Makes sense; thanks for the stats.