# A single "looks good" should not mean the post is "good"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, low-quality-posts

In the Low Quality review queue a single <kbd>Looks Good</kbd> click is enough to take the post out of the queue, I believe. I'm basing this on empirical observations but on Stack Overflow at least, this appears to be the case<sup>1</sup>.

The system should not be quite so simple as it enables a single mis-click or robo-reviewer to stop spam/non-answers from being deleted and allows a single "looks good" to override multiple people's delete votes. I had envisaged this more as a scoring system; say the post has to reach a score of -X to be deleted or +Y to be saved. A <kbd>Recommend Deletion</kbd> click would be a -1 and a <kbd>Looks Good</kbd> click would be a +1.

If Y is less than X then a minority of people can still save an answer from deletion by people not paying attention but they cannot overrule the majority easily. If, for instance, Y was 2 and X was 5, once 4 deletion "votes" had been gained it would take 6 looks good "votes" to save the answer. Equally, the one person who clicked <kbd>Looks Good</kbd> at the beginning cannot take the post out of the queue on their own and if an additional 6 people think the post should be deleted then it will be. (Obviously, these numbers are not necessarily appropriate for every/any site in the network).

<sub>1. Evidence - [Single "looks good" click](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1227704), ["looks good" after a deletion vote](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1227020).</sub>

Comment: Are you sure the posts are not removed from the queue because they have been deleted? Using the first link you report on the bottom of your question, I am redirected to a page where I read _answer not found_, and _question not found_. As I am not a 10K user on Stack Overflow, those phrases lead me to think the question has been deleted.

Comment: That was an extremely poor example then @kiamlaluno; the entire question was deleted there. I'm not _sure_ but I'm 99%. I've changed the example.

Comment: I'm not sure about the scoring system, but I definitely agree with the core issue:  a single "Looks Good" vote should not be enough to remove an item from the queue.  I don't see allowing more reviewers as a bad thing, since the queue pretty much sits at zero right now.

Comment: Similar problem: [Please require more reviewers on First Posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188457/please-require-more-reviewers-on-first-posts) (just linking it here, carry on)

Comment: it is worth noting that in this regard, VLQ flags per current system somehow manage to do the [magic of increasing the number of Looks-Good required to take the post out of the queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181165/can-flags-send-a-post-into-the-low-quality-posts-review-queue/190639?noredirect=1#comment654618_190639 "explained and discussed here in more details")

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A post enters the Low Quality queue based on either simple heuristics (the system's quality score) or [one person's flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181165/can-flags-send-a-post-into-the-low-quality-posts-review-queue/190639#190639).

At this point, there's a *reasonable* chance that the post should be deleted, but that's hardly a given: the system can't judge the context of the post or even the meaning of the content, and folks have a [long history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86984/please-take-care-when-flagging-answers-as-low-quality) of [misusing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93595/is-the-very-low-quality-flag-too-ambiguous) the VLQ flag.

In some cases, the quality of a post *changes* between the time it enters the queue and the time it leaves. Remember, reviewers are prompted to leave an explanatory comment when voting or recommending deletion - occasionally, an author will read this and edit his post.

Finally, this emphatically *is not* a scoring system - [we have one of those already](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). You're not collaborating here to judge the worth of a post, you're helping to answer a question:

- Is this post *complete, unsalvageable **garbage,*** an embarrassment to its author, a shame to his ancestors, and a blight upon the site?

This isn't a question to be taken lightly: if the answer is "yes", the post will be removed from the site, an action normally reserved for moderators and [trusted users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user). This isn't a choice between two equally-preferable outcomes: the burden *should* be on the folks who think a post should be removed, not equally-divided and *certainly* not the other way around. If the reviewers make a mistake and fail to delete a bad post, there's a fallback that involves the elected moderators; since the post is still visible to *everyone*, there's a good chance someone else will see it and flag it. This isn't the case for the reverse: if a reasonable post is deleted, only a handful of people can still even find it.

That said, although we don't have the fancy system you propose, it isn't *quite* as simple as you suppose either:

- If multiple readers flag a post, it'll take [multiple reviewers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181165/can-flags-send-a-post-into-the-low-quality-posts-review-queue/190639#190639) to override them.
- If both the system *and* a reader flag a post, it'll take two reviewers to override them (does not apply to Stack Overflow, since the system doesn't *flag* posts there).
- If [trusted users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) *vote* to delete, those votes persist regardless of how many people respond "Looks Good". Because we trust them.

So far, this seems to be working reasonably well, and has removed a great deal of fairly mindless work from the moderator queue.

Comment: Frankly, I think we should take inspiration from Mary Tyler Moore and change the text "Looks Good" to "Not Awful".

Comment: _"reviewers are prompted to leave an explanatory comment"_ -- worth noting that they are also presented with a No Comment option, which can eventually remove the post without comments

Comment: Since you didn't change it, don't you mean [tag:status-bydesign]?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer it's good to know that it's not quite as simple as it was/seemed.

Comment: _"If both the system and a reader flag a post, it'll take two reviewers to override them"_ - per my testing [performed here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204694/165773), this doesn't look like the case: despite the additional flag on the item that was in queue, single _Looks Good_ dropped the post off the queue

Comment: If the flag is handled by a mod, does that action remove the post from the review queue?

Comment: @Josh: well, it changed between the time this was written and now; I just forgot this post existed until gnat pointed it out.

Comment: @gnat: see my edit; LQ posts aren't auto-flagged on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Shog9 thanks... but still, I do not completely understand outcome of my test. Whatever was there that pushed the post into queue, I added an _additional_, my VLQ flag _over_ it - how comes that this did not result into increasing of number _Looks Good_ votes required to pull it out of queue?

Comment: There's only one flag on that post, gnat - it entered review because of its low quality score (in this case, triggered mostly by length), but did not garner a *flag* until you flagged it.

Comment: got it - thanks! that matches _specification_ - "If more than one VLQ flag accumulates..." condition wasn't triggered

Comment: @Monica: it is made ineligible for review at that point, removing it from the queue.

Comment: "If trusted users vote to delete, those votes persist ... " is incorrect. The present behavior is that if the post gets deleted from review before getting 3 trusted user votes, *and* the author undeletes, the trusted users' votes vanish in a puff.

Comment: That is not a scenario that I address in this answer, @This (the question is specifically concerned with the effect of Looks Good). However, this answer is out of date; I'll update it.