# Rescind Review Votes by Audited Reviewers

Tags: feature-request

[This question's first answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188457/please-require-more-reviewers-on-first-posts) has a comment by Brad Larson that indicates that there is a period of time between when a robo-reviewer starts doing bad reviews and hits an audit, stopping them. Is it possible to add a feature where a user who gets audited has their recent reviews put back into the appropriate queues?

The rationale here would be that recent reviews are probably bad and should not have been resolved. For the First Post/Late Answer/Low Quality queues where only one reviewer exists, this means that a robo-reviewer probably has had a significant negative impact. This could be tuned to a period (24 hours) or a certain number of reviews (10? 40?). Those queues are consistently empty, so it's probably unlikely to create a huge workload burden (though I don't know if there is a means to run actual numbers on that?). I'm not sure this would be a useful or easy change for the Close Vote queue.

Thoughts?

(Also, apologies if this is a dupe... was unable to find something hitting this potential strategy.)

Comment: One potential problem: If the robo-reviewer was the last review needed before changes went live, activity may be generated based on the published changes. A rollback would invalidate that activity in a manner that may cause confusion.

Comment: I suppose then, the question is what sort of confusion is caused (because I think in most queues cases the one review is all that is needed?), and is that worse than reviews being handled inaccurately?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins - That would only be an issue with suggested edits or reviews where a user flagged a post. I imagine those could be excluded from this, and only reviews with actions of "No Action Needed", upvotes, or downvotes be put back into review. Those are the only reviews that I'm seeing spam and non-answers slip through on.

Comment: @Brad Good point. I was thinking primarily of the suggested edit queue when I commented.