# Identify who reviewed a First Post

Tags: discussion, review

When a "first post" which is clearly terrible gets past the reviewers for whatever reason, is there any way for me to look at who reviewed it?

It would be nice to see who's passing these terrible first posts on, so that if there ends up being a pattern (some particular user or users regularly approving awful posts) something could be done about it, perhaps flagging the post for a moderator's attention or somesuch.

Comment: 10K users (and diamond moderators) can see the [review history](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/history). Below 10K you'll see only your own reviews there.

Comment: Nice idea. Also, this matches the public reviewing details one can see when suggested edits get approved.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering about that (given it shows my name).  Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Moderators currently have this ability, and we can use it to follow up on poor reviewers. If someone flags something as spam, and it clearly made it through review, I'm now looking into the review history of those who let it past. I've banned a number of people from review over the last few weeks as a result.

I'm not sure how much of a benefit exposing this to non-moderators would be, because normal users can't really do anything about a problematic reviewer. Moderators can message and ban from review, so we'd probably be the ones who'd have to act on this anyway.

I think a better long-term solution would be to [require more reviewers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188457/please-require-more-reviewers-on-first-posts) on the posts in the First Posts and Late Answers queues.

Comment: Thanks, Brad.  The only thing I was thinking about was that someone could do what I just did in a recent review suspension question - look at past history (like you say) and if it's a long history, flag with that comment.  (Alternately we could have some sort of voting for review quality, but perhaps that overcomplicates).  I definitely agree (and agreed with a vote a while back) with having more reviewers for First Posts.

Answer (score 4):

Mods get to see this for each post:

[image]

Which leads to:

[image]

I don't know if that warrants flagging for moderator attention, but if you ask nicely maybe a mod can check out who reviewed that post (this menu makes it easy to do that without browsing the entire history), and send that user a friendly message if needed.

At least if there was a strong suspicion that bogus reviews let a post stay on the site for too long, I would investigate that if it was flagged.

Comment: Lovely description of "link". :-)