# Why don't more of us get shown late answer reviews?

Tags: discussion, review

I've developed a habit of checking the history of the Late Answers review queue on stackoverflow. Sadly, I very frequently find things to do sweeping up after the supposed reviewers.

Consider as an example https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/3734334.

Now, if I read this correctly, this was shown to just one person, who apparently found nothing amiss with it.

Why?

Comment: Related: [Please require more reviewers on First Posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188457/please-require-more-reviewers-on-first-posts) - Mostly the same argument applies between First Posts and Late Answers, maybe even Low Quality Posts.