# Flagging VLQ after opening the post in Low Quality queue but prior to recommending deletion

Tags: bug, review, flags, low-quality-posts

<sup>Tagging as [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) as recommended by Shog [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181165/can-flags-send-a-post-into-the-low-quality-posts-review-queue/190639?noredirect=1#comment654642_190639)</sup>

Currently, flagging post as very low quality is designed to work [as specified here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190639/165773):

> If more than one VLQ flag accumulates on the post before the review has ended, a number of "Looks Good" responses equivalent to the number of flags is required to dequeue it...
>
> - Review items completed by deletion or closing result in a "helpful" status for the flag
> - Review items completed by "Looks Good" responses result in a "disputed" status for the flag

As a result, reviewer working in the LQ queue can do as follows:

1. Open the queue item
2. Open the reviewed post in a separate browser tab
3. Flag VLQ outside of the queue
4. Vote "Recommend Deletion" from the queue

Above opens a way to low-risk increase for the count of helpful flags.

Should something be done about this?

- Testing for above using [this review item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3313178) went as follows: after submitting Recommend Deletion and getting Looks Good from next reviewer, flag has been resolved as [painless "disputed"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95277/165773) and post has been taken off review queue.

---

<sub>Side note. If this is confirmed as a bug, a fix that naturally comes to mind would be to block review completion if flag is discovered at the moment of submitting "Recommend Deletion". Per my recollection, this would be similar to how things work in CV queue - voting to close from outside of the queue while item is still opened blocks "Close" action (reviewer can only Skip and maybe Leave Open).</sub>

Comment: Rather than blocking reviewing if they have flagged, why not just consider it an equivalent action, in effect, it shouldn't matter whether you flag or "recommend deletion", doing either action (or both) always results in the same outcome, much like with closing.

Comment: @Servy per [current design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181165/can-flags-send-a-post-into-the-low-quality-posts-review-queue/190639?noredirect=1#comment654618_190639 "discussed here"), actions are not exactly the same: "2 flags... raise the bar higher than 1 flag + 5 deletion votes from 1K+ users"

Comment: Philosophically, flagging here is *asking* for review, while "recommend delete" is *performing* the review. No, this isn't entirely consistent between queues, but then again closing is not the same as deletion either.

Comment: @Shog9 regarding _closing_, I recently discovered somewhat... similar difference between flagging for review and performing it. It is [discussed in this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207179/do-flags-to-close-expire-like-votes-to-close): votes to close expire while flags don't. If it really makes sense to keep it that way, I would very much appreciate having an explanation added there.

Comment: **update** - as of now, this is only for answers. Since 2014-12-06 [Very Low Quality flags are not available for questions under close and triage review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244736)

Comment: Currently, if you've flagged an answer as NAA or VLQ, you can't review the task, but I haven't tested for the case where you load it before you flag.