# 500 helpful flags hack

Tags: discussion, review, badges, etiquette

Once you're over 2K&3K(*depending on the review queues eligible to you*) your chances of earning the [Marshal badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1298/marshal) are lower because you're not flagging as much any more.

There's a funny and very minor workaround (*I named it a hack*) which allows you to get a helpful flag almost everytime you're [reviewing a low quality queue.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3456239) - except audits.

Once you realize that an answer you're reviewing is not a proper answer you can go into the question's page and flag the answer for moderators attention -> then go back to your review page and for example recommend deletion.

This way you're almost always guaranteed a helpful flag while still helping with moderation.

I could consider this a bug because it's a way of cheating the system but on the other hand you're not doing nothing terribly bad (*in terms of gaining some unfair advantage over others*).

Is there anything we should do about it or is this going to be considered status-by-design?

Comment: Be right back, I have some reviewing to do :)

Comment: *Meh*. When you're at 10k, you get given access to the flag queue, which lets you pile on flags to already flagged posts. I guess it's a similar thing.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to get flags without cheating or gaming the system.

Comment: @Matt - It's particularly amusing to watch the number of people farming flags this way spike during a moderator election. Like it isn't obvious what you're doing.

Comment: So much work for one badge?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Gold. "They are rarely awarded." ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're using the VLQ flag for this, [you're exploiting a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204694/flagging-vlq-after-opening-the-post-in-low-quality-queue-but-prior-to-recommendi).

If you're using a flag that doesn't apply, it's kinda dishonest.

If you're using "other", deletion won't actually clear it, so you're just creating more work for the moderators.

But if there's a good reason to flag *and* review, go right ahead and do that. (For instance: spam should always be spam-flagged, regardless of what else you do to it).

Comment: Also, very valid points. Animuson doesnt consider this a bug, do you?

Comment: Per my answer, whether or not it's a bug depends on which flag you're using (VLQ flagging in the LQ queue isn't productive). See my retag @mehow.

Answer (score 9):

This is not a bug, a cheat, or a hack. If you really want to go to the post and flag it as well, **go for it**. Because frankly, sometimes you'll get that moron that robo-reviews the post and then it falls through the cracks, and your flag actually becomes quite helpful.

In the end, it's *only* a helpful flag count and a badge. No one really cares.

Comment: Valid point, but still a way to cheat to get the Marshal badge

Comment: @mehow Call it a "just in case" flag.