# Disputed flags and triage

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts, disputed-flags, triage

Is the disputed flag handled any differently in the new triage review queue. I marked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321580/javascript-variables-use-in-html?noredirect=1) as very low quality, after choosing unsalvageable and this was disputed. From what I have read, if a question is edited, this puts the flag in dispute, but this question was not edited. I have no complaint, I just want to understand what is going on, as the triage queue seems like a really good initiative, so I want to help as positively as I can.

Comment: *Eventually* the VLQ flag will have a strong tie in with Triage.  Pretty sure it's just not all done yet, as it's still in beta.  Triage [marked the question as should be improved](http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6400223) which indicates the flag was helpful (if that flag even pushed the question into triage, not sure if even that is done yet).  I'm pretty sure VLQ flags for questions are still going to Low Quality Posts, not Triage, although that will (probably) eventually change.

Comment: OK. There is obviously some subjectivity between should be improved and very low quality, so that is very reasonable. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that the Triage action had nothing to do with how your flag was resolved, even though it will end up working that way *eventually*.

Comment: @Servy A "Should Be Improved" outcome marks the flag as disputed. Very Low Quality flags are only for content that can't be salvaged and should be deleted *immediately*. The only thing in Triage that corresponds to that is the "Unsalvageable" outcome. PS, while the flag did not push it into Triage, the Triage review item *did* clear the flags.

Comment: @animuson [Shog's comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage/278382#comment124353_278382) seems to indicate otherwise.  He indicated that the VLQ flag is basically going to be re-worked for questions to mean, "this should go back to triage because it's not okay" rather than meaning "this should be deleted post haste".  I'd of course expect its wording to change if that's how it ends up being treated.

Comment: @Servy I'm just looking at the post timeline, and the dismissal time for the two VLQ flags by Community exactly matches the completion time of that review item.

Comment: But this question doesn't look VLQ. Shouldn't you have flagged it as too broad?

Comment: I think davidism's answer in the original [triage post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage/278382#comment124353_278382) encapsulates the possible confusion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer here is that when a question is triaged as anything *other* than Unsalvageable, any pending Spam, Offensive, Very Low Quality or Close flags will be marked Disputed. This is done to prevent the queue from potentially sending questions in three different directions at once (mod flag queue, close review queue, and whatever the intended destination was).

Note that close *votes* are not affected; if you're trusted to vote, your vote can only be removed via [the normal aging mechanisms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away).

#### Additional complexity in your scenario

This answer got a bit weirder when I realized that you'd flagged the question as *very low quality*. See, that wasn't supposed to be an option here - eventually, VLQ flags are gonna send questions *into* Triage, so having that as an option there doesn't really make a lot of sense. That was in the original design, but... I kinda overlooked it when testing.

When I mentioned this to Geoff, he noted that it'd be possible to make the flag unavailable *on the question page itself* if the question was currently being triaged, making this all a bit more consistent and side-stepping a few even weirder scenarios...

#### Changes to VLQ flag availability

So as of a few minutes ago, Very Low Quality won't be an option from within Triage review **or from anywhere else while a question is being triaged**. We're also taking this opportunity to be a bit proactive with another change that'll be necessary soon: **Very Low Quality won't be available for questions that are currently undergoing Close review either.**

This moves VLQ one step closer to my intended purpose: catching awful questions that slipped through the cracks somehow. We'll see how that works out in practice...

Comment: that way, users with 15+ rep will be able to find out if question is (was) in close review, correct? I mean they can open flag dialog and, if it lacks VLQ option, this would indicate that question is (was) under review. By the way, will VLQ flags continue to stay disabled if question ages away from the queue? or if close votes age away?

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I guess my choosing the wrong option from triage had some beneficial side effects at least.

Comment: No restrictions on posts that aren't currently in a queue, @gnat. Apart from post score.

Comment: I see, thanks. Need more time to chew this, but on a first glance, looks like a right move. Forcing flaggers to use (and learn about!) close flags instead of VLQ while question is under review feels quite promising. Just in time learning about the system, I like it

Answer (score 5):

Marking a question as VLQ is there to push it into the Triage queue (now).  It's there to say that some sort of action is needed in that queue.

It doesn't make any sense to use that flag *from* the Triage queue.  You're flagging an item in that queue as needing to to into the queue you're flagging it from.

It shouldn't even be an available option from the "unsalvageable" menu, as it has no sensible workflow from that position.

If you think that the post is unsalvageable, then from the Triage queue you should be voting/flagging it for closure, or flagging as spam/offensive/some custom flag.

Comment: Ok, point taken. Very low quality was an option presented, I thought it was, it didn't occur to me that that would put it back in the triage queue, hence my original question. I was operating from the triage queue, not from flagging questions on the front page.