# What causes a recommend closure flag to be marked disputed, versus helpful or declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, off-topic, on-hold, disputed-flags

I know that this type of question was asked many time, but I didn't find answers related to my specific questions anywhere. At [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95277/203604) it is explained about disputed flags of types NAA, VLQ, offensive and spam, by there is no mention about off-topic flags. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244736/203604) I found explanation that after triage review flags may get disputed, but it says that close votes are not affected.

So here is my questions:

1. In which cases exactly off-topic flag gets disputed?
2. Also I have disputed flags in my profile near the questions that are actually `[on hold]`, why my flag not appears helpful?
3. Recently I marked [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29720274/failed-to-open-the-x11-display-virtualbox-linux) as off-topic, and now my flag is disputed. Is that mean that flag was inappropriate and question should remain in the developers SO?
4. Does flag counts as helpful if it describes the reason to close not very accurate? For example if I marked question as off-topic, but it was put on hold as too broad

Comment: Which sub-category did you choose in off-topic?

Comment: @rene I set it blatantly off-topic as not related to programming

Comment: I see, but I close voted that question with *Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.* which I think is a better match. I couldn't find the question in the review history so maybe it was disputed by a mod for the same reason

Comment: @rene thank your for the response, and it lead me to a new question: does flag counts as helpful if it describes the reason to close not very accurate? As you say in my case there was another option which is better than mine. I added that to my question too

Comment: This first needs a mod to check on those flags before I speculate further off-course...

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is talking about behavior of the Triage queue, which exists only on Stack Overflow, making it specific to one site.

Comment: Don't do that, @pppery. It helps no one. The fact that this behavior is covered in the official FAQ makes it answerable here; could've just closed as a duplicate if you felt it needed to be closed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a feature which is a part of the new Triage review queue. When reviewers determine that the question Looks Ok and requires no further action, the system automatically dismisses all pending non-custom flags on the post as **disputed** - which includes recommend closure flags. [This is exactly what happened in your case.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7739845)

Your flag gets marked as **helpful** if the question gets closed *or* if a user with full vote-to-close privileges casts a close vote for the same reason as you while your flag is still pending.

Your flag gets marked as **declined** if reviewers in the Close Votes review queue determine that the question should be left open while your flag is still pending.

It should be noted that recommend closure flags **can only be automatically dismissed by the system** via one of the events described above. It is not possible for a moderator to manually dismiss them with a reason of their choosing. The outcome is entirely based on what the community does with the post.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, could you also describe a bit more about remain part of my question please? Namely about disputed flags that refers to `[on hold]` question. Does that mean that during review post marked as OK, but later someone re-flagged it when my flag is already gone? And if my flag's reason is not the same for closing reason, that flag stay pending? Thank you

Comment: It's just a matter of order of events. Reviewers completed Triage and disputed your flags before anyone had a chance to cast the same close vote or close the question to mark your flag as helpful.

Comment: If I read your answer right, then even the duplicate closeflags are dismissed if the reviewers think it Looks OK... I'd say this is a bug or rather illogical behavior. A question can look good and be a duplicate.

Comment: @pizza as I understood, reviewers shouldn't press "looks ok" button unless they are sure that this is high quality, unique question and belongs to that SE site

Comment: @Azat [According to Shog9](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290536/3717023) this is not so; Triage reviewers should not spend time hunting for duplicate targets if they don't immediately recognize the question as a duplicate.

Comment: @pizza I used to skip questions that I'm not sure, I think it is better than accidentally apply duplicate or low quality question in the area of development where I am not qualified enough