# Reopen votes queue guidance contains outdated and/or inaccurate information

Tags: feature-request, bug, review, user-interface, declined-flags

Go to any site [`/review/reopen`](/review/reopen) then click *Learn more about the Reopen votes queue.*

> Closed questions that have received at least one reopen vote, as well as posts whose bodies have been edited within 70 days of closure, will appear in this queue.
>
> You can vote to **Reopen**, **Edit**, or **Leave closed**.
>
> Here are some tips on how to be most helpful in this queue:
>
> - Most posts require 5 votes to reopen them.
> - If enough people vote to reopen a question, recommend closure flags will be declined.
> - Consider using filters to find posts relevant to your interests and subject-matter expertise.
> - **Skip** the task if you aren't sure which action to take.
>
> [Read more](/help/review-reopen) about this queue in our help center.

- The line about declining recommended closure flags if enough people vote to reopen a question is confusing and most likely an error. There is no way for a recommended closure flag to be on a closed question in the first place. They are all automatically marked as helpful when a question is closed and cannot be raised on a question that is already closed. Furthermore there is no way to vote to reopen a non-closed question.

  Close flags are only declined when 3 people or 1 moderator vote to **Leave open** from the [**close** votes](/review/close) queue ([Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253836/1377755)). Perhaps that line belongs in the **close vote** queue guidance (Which currently does not mention declining close flags if the post is left open by 3 people) rather than the **reopen vote** queue guidance.
- The line about having been edited within 70 days of closure is outdated. Posts now enter the review queue if an editor marks the edit as a significant edit that should reconsider the question for reopening as described here: [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/1377755)

  The guidance should be updated to reflect that change.