# Why is the option very low quality sometimes hidden in the flag menu?

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts

Why is the option **very low quality**  sometimes hidden in the flag menu?

About a moment ago, I saw a post of very low quality on Stack Overflow, and I wanted to flag it as **very low quality** but this option was not in the flag menu.

Why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The low quality flag option will come up for zero or negatively scored posts - that's the first indication that a post is indeed low quality (or suffers from other issues).

I can only assume that the post had no downvotes at the time (or enough upvotes that the score was positive), and as such, the option didn't come up.

Why flag before voting? Voting is the first and most important thing to do.

Comment: I flag before voting if I feel my flag should translate into a close.

Comment: @Pureferret but there's no VLQ close reason, just flag.

Comment: for the sake of completeness, VLQ flags are also [not available for questions under close and triage review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244736/165773) - no matter what's their score

Comment: @ShadowWizard Just my general flag logic.

Answer (score 8):

As of June 2016, another reason for the missing VLQ flag option is that the post (question or answer) is [older than seven days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326635/4751173). If a post sticks around for 7 days or more, chances are very high that it's not **very** low quality:

> but the truth is that very few VLQ flags ever get raised on posts over 7 days old... Heck, 87% of all VLQ flags are raised on questions less than one day old. The vast, vast majority of the worst cruft gets cleaned up quickly...

The Very Low Quality flag option is also [unavailable on questions which are already in the Close Votes review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244736/295232); since the 'negative' outcome of a Low Quality Posts review on a question is to close it, it's pointless to review it in two queues.