# Do not hide VLQ flag option from users who already flagged and may wish to retract

Tags: feature-request, flags, low-quality-posts, retracted-flags

System hides an option to flag Very Low Quality in few cases, namely when post is:

- [in Triage or Close review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244736/165773)
- [older than 7 days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326635/839601)
- [of positive score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258896/165773)

Because of that users who already flagged it when none of above conditions applied miss an option to [retract their flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87500/165773).

Suggest<sup>1</sup> to show this flag option to such users so that they could retract a flag.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Frankly I won't mind if this gets [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) because I doubt that it is important. This is posted mainly to document how system behaves and to provide reference for those who may wonder why they can't retract flag in some cases.</sub>

Comment: `I won't mind if this gets status-declined` Did you mean: ***status-deferred***

Comment: @dorukayhan I really don't mind, declined or deferred, whatever. When drafting this feature request I was trying to figure compelling reasons to push strongly for it to be implemented and couldn't figure one (even though I am active flagger and even though I sometimes cast VLQ flags I later reconsider and would want to retract - this just happens too infrequently to worry)

Comment: cross-site duplicate at MSO: [Unable to retract VLQ flag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333569/839601)

Answer (score 5):

Before this feature gets implemented (or if it gets [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)), you can use [a userscript I wrote](https://stackapps.com/q/7033/38449), which allows you to retract flags directly from the "Flagged Posts for [User]" page in the user profile. This is how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The script mentioned in [the other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284301/295232) is no longer available. For the few times this happens to me, I didn't bother writing a new one, but running a simple jQuery command in the browser console suffices:

```js
$.post("https://meta.stackexchange.com/flags/posts/283357/retract/PostLowQuality", {
  fkey: $("input[name=fkey]").val()
})
```

You need to replace the domain name and the question ID accordingly. Note that the flag type is called `PostLowQuality`, not `VeryLowQuality`.