# Low quality review records say "Looks Good" instead of "Looks OK"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, user-interface, low-quality-posts

Button in LQ queue has been recently [renamed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232342/165773) from <kbd>Looks Good</kbd> to <kbd>Looks OK</kbd>.

But review records still say "Looks Good", as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5205347):

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqhP6.png]

It would be nice to have a consistent wording, "Looks OK" in both cases.

---

<sub>To those worried that my testing could have dropped bad post from review, I [countered it with flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204691/165773) (and added downvote, because I just couldn't resist).</sub>

Comment: @VotetoClose that's primarily because I knew that I am able to "neutralize" my Looks Good. And because I rarely use Looks Good in this queue, I tend to either recommend deletion or [Skip](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232140/165773 "'Skip is what lets me do reviews instead of frying my brain...'")

Comment: @gnat Impossible not to misread as "neutralize my Good Looks".

Comment: _"neutralize my Good Looks" –  This is much healthier_, agreed with @This :)

Comment: MSO: ["Looks Good" instead of "Looks OK" still remaining](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/259879/839601)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I decided that your request for this change *Looks OK* and so I changed the wording. It'll be live in the next prod build (> rev `2014.7.9.2357`).