# Can flags send a post into the Low Quality Posts review queue?

Tags: support, review, flags, low-quality-posts

I'm trying to clear the last few TODOs in [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing), so it can eventually go into the FAQ. The section on the Low Quality Posts queue currently says:

> Questions appear in the low quality post queue both by algorithm and by flags from users. [TODO remove this todo if you know this information is correct :) ]

I couldn't find any meta post stating that flags can take a post into that queue. [New Feature: Community Review Tasks - Now in Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta) says just that *this task targets posts that we've algorithmically determined to be low quality*.

Should we remove the mention to flags, or does anyone know a post to back that information up?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of July 2013, Very Low Quality flags automatically add the flagged post to the Low Quality review queue. [As of April 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue), Not An Answer flags do the same.

Each review task requires a minimum number of "Looks OK" reviews (2 on SO, 1 everywhere else) to be dequeued; this number increases by one for each pending flag on the post (edits, closing and deletion dequeue the task in the normal fashion).

Once reviewed, further flags do not re-add the post to the queue. At this point, a moderator will need to intervene. These flags will continue to appear in the moderator queue for this reason.

These changes replace the previous handling of these flags by 10K users. Details can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue/228861#228861).

Comment: So does that means if one person flags the post, one "Looks Good" response is given for the review, and then 10 other people flag it afterwards, would it just be in the moderator pile?

Comment: Correct, @Qantas. The previous flag (and resolution) *will* appear to the moderator reviewing it though.

Comment: _number of "Looks Good" responses equivalent to the number of flags_ -- it would be helpful to add an explanation for why "Recommend Deletion" votes from the queue don't follow this approach. It is not obvious why 2 flags (potentially from low rep users) raise the bar higher than 1 flag + 5 deletion votes from 1K+ users (I can ask this in a separate question if you prefer a dedicated post to clarify this). To avoid misunderstanding, I don't challenge this decision, merely wonder about the reasons for it

Comment: ...I also wonder if [hacks](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12077839#12077839) like flagging VLQ _prior_ to recommending deletion from the queue have been considered?

Comment: You're missing the most obvious question, @gnat: why does it only take one reviewer to kick a LQ post out of the queue under normal circumstances? Post a separate question, please. (And regarding the hack: you could probably consider this a bug, since AFAIK it requires you to load the review item before flagging the post and keep it open until you've both flagged and submitted your review - if you flag it first, it should become ineligible)

Comment: thanks, will post a new question... oh wait, it's already posted: [A single “looks good” should not mean the post is “good”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160067/a-single-looks-good-should-not-mean-the-post-is-good) - is that it? FWIW, keeping review item open while doing stuff on the post in a separate tab / window is [just the way I typically work in queues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773 "as mentioned eg here") :)

Comment: Hmm... Closer to my question than yours, but I've [tried to address both](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160067/a-single-looks-good-should-not-mean-the-post-is-good/204691#204691), @gnat.

Comment: I just posted a question about the "hack": [Flagging VLQ after opening the post in Low Quality queue but prior to recommending deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204694/165773) (took a while to test it, sorry for delay)

Comment: Wow, I never knew this. So does that mean the number of people who VLQ/NaA-flagged a post is more or less public knowledge?