# How to proceed with a post that was incorrectly removed from the low quality review queue?

Tags: support, review, low-quality-posts

Consider the following situation: A post was in the low quality review queue, because it was rather a comment to the question and not an answer. The first reviewer made some minor edit which did not change the quality of the post (marking one word as inline code, which is counter-productive in this situation, but not the topic of this question...)

How to proceed from there? I already flagged the post as "not an answer" two days ago and voted to delete, but the post did not reappear in the low quality review queue (I am aware that it will not reappear in my own review queue, but I had a look at the history and while many users did reviews and reviews of several posts were completed, no one got this post again, so I presume that it did not enter the queue again)

How to proceed from here? What else can I do to get this post into the review queue again?

Comment: Posts go to VLQ queue only once. They are send to the mod queue at each subsequent time.

Comment: @MEE Oh, interesting information. So the answer is "just do nothing and wait for the mods to decide"?

Comment: If your goal is to have the answer deleted, custom flag it and explain why. Otherwise, just downvote, possibly leave comment explaining why, and move on to the next low quality answer. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to proceed from here? What else can I do to get this post into the review queue again?

You did what you could, now you can only wait. [The post won't appear in the low quality queue again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291263/369802), so now it's in the moderator queue and up to moderators on the site to handle your flag.

If it is declined, you could flag the post for moderator attention and provide more detail on why you think it should be deleted, or raise an issue on the site meta.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer! That was really fast. I'll have to wait a bit before I'm allowed to accept one...

Answer (score 2):

> I already flagged the post as "not an answer" two days ago

That means it will be put in the ♦ moderator flag queue, and they will deal with it. Since this is a relatively rare situation, it's fine that they have to handle it this time while the community should technically be able to deal with it. There is no way to put it into the Low Quality Posts review queue again.

An alternative would be to gather two other 20k users in e.g. chat, and have them vote to delete as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer! That was really fast! The advice from both answers sounds equally good, so I just flipped a coin to decide which one to accept and the side with the bird won.