# What is an invalid flag?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderator-tools, 10k-tools, invalid-flags

There is this answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95277/234193)  to [What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag).

[image] from: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754332/jquery-slide-with-fade-when-move

This above post has not been edited so I assume the first part of the answer I'm quoting from means, the post received an invalid flag.

I am not sure what @Shog is meaning.

> A disputed flag is a flag that was issued on a post that then received an "invalid flag" flag from a 10K+ user. Both the original flag and the flag used to mark it as invalid will be listed as "disputed" in the respective user's flagging summary. Once a flag has been disputed, its state will not be changed by any additional action on the post.

- **A disputed flag is a flag that was issued on a post that then received an "invalid flag" flag from a 10K+ user.**
  Is the invalid flag one that is issued on the flag or the post?
- Why would **Both the original flag and the flag used to mark it as invalid will be listed as "disputed" in the respective user's flagging summary.**

What is an invalid flag, for those of us without the privilege?

Comment: It means that it wasn't a valid flag. In other words it wasn't an inappropriate flag, there was no evidence to support it.

Comment: FWIW, you actually should have access to the tools I referenced [on CogSci](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=flags) - there are no active flags as I type this, but if there were and you opted to flag one of them, you'd see the option to dispute highlighted in Sha's answer.

Comment: @Shog9 is one "disagree" flag enough to dispute even three "not an answer" flags? Isn't it too much power for non moderators?

Comment: @Shog9 I have never seen an active flag on Coggy, and will have ht priv on [pets.se] soon I think.. also what is FWIW

Comment: @Sha: there's very little "power" in play here; a moderator still has to make the call to dismiss the flag, even if there were 100 "disputed" flags countering it. [Contrast with "Looks Good" in review's Low Quality](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181165/can-flags-send-a-post-into-the-low-quality-posts-review-queue/190639#190639), which only falls back on the moderators if a post is flagged on multiple, separate occasions.

Comment: FWIW -> For What It's Worth (which is to say, very little - you'd have to get lucky to see a pending flag on either of those sites, since they don't get many flags and the moderators are pretty active).

Comment: @Shog9 yep gotcha and I did wonder if I had access to them, but had never seen them.. much like sighting unicorns, handling flags on beta sites for non-mods hey.. :)

Comment: Pretty much par for the course on beta sites - everyone who knows about the site runs out of questions to ask. Now's the time to let your friends know about it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What was the "invalid flag" flag? What was the "10k flag queue"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291260/what-was-the-invalid-flag-flag-what-was-the-10k-flag-queue)

Comment: @RobertColumbia actually that is a duplicate of my question - posted 4 years later. This was downvoted. as I was extremely unpopular at the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

10K users can access [this screen](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged):

> [image]

When clicking the marked button, we get:

> [image]

That's what Shog meant. :)

Note that even 10K users doing this still have to wait until moderator handle the original flag, until then it will still be active like any other flag:

> [image]

When the flag is handled, the status of *both* flags will be updated identically, based on how it was handled. Dismissed flags will both be marked as "disputed", while helpful flags will be marked as "helpful".

[image: disputed and dismissed == 'dismissed'] <-- flags dismissed without action

[image: disputed and helpful == 'helpful'] <-- flags marked helpful

Comment: So that means the person does not agree with the flag. and they just both sit there like that forever??

Comment: @YvetteColomb this means the person does not agree with the flag and choosing that option then clicking "Flag Answer" cause the original flag to get disputed and vanish from the queue.

Comment: ahhh and for the 10k + user, what does their flags look like?

Comment: @YvetteColomb exactly like <10K user flags, turns out we also have to wait until moderator handle the original flag. If he also agree the flag was invalid, it will cause the flag to get "disputed". (otherwise probably declined, though never checked it)

Comment: and then is can be declined or helpful.. and either way, the original disputed flag, stays disputed forever? Why did @shog say **Both the original flag and the flag used to mark it as invalid will be listed as "disputed" in the respective user's flagging summary.** because yours is not showing as disputed savvy??