# Why am I being notified just now of comments that were posted six years ago?

Tags: support, comments, notifications, linked-accounts

I've recently got notifications from two comments from [six years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204041/what-is-an-invalid-flag#comment651186_204044):

> [image: Notifications from very old comments received within minutes ago]
>
> [image: The comments that resulted in those notifications, which were posted in November 2013]

Some history:

1. It was posted by an account that I deleted years ago, and the post was later reattributed to my current account.
2. I edited the question some minutes before receiving the notifications.

Comment: We're just going to replay history on you. Expect these déjà vu-s for the next 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: @rene I'm getting PSTD - this was before the MSE - MSO split... oh those were the days :'(

Comment: Heh, I too have an account here (pre-split) that I deleted in November 2013. How did you get that post reattributed to your current account?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog after long discussion with the community team and then deciding to proceed. In parts it is traumatic being reminded how hated I was on the site. My [posts were routinely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204041/what-is-an-invalid-flag) downvoted, regardless of quality, but based on author. This doesn't mean my bad posts didn't warrant being downvoted, it meant my good posts were downvoted as well.

Comment: At least if they're not prompt they're thorough. Bringing new meaning to 6-8 weeks ...

Comment: @YvetteColomb Perhaps reframing "hated" as "misunderstood" might be helpful to you.  You've come a long way since that point.  Be proud of that.

Comment: Related: [Do users get notifications when @ was edited in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197393/187824)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I do apologise.

The question was brought to my attention and while investigating it I spotted that there were a number of obsolete comments on the answer which I deleted.

I then noticed that the other comments replied using your old name which I thought might not be a good idea so I edited them to use your current name. It was only after I'd done it that it occurred to me that they might raise a notification.

I'll think twice before I do it again.

Comment: that's fine! and good to know, as I cannot see the edits, so it gives us a frame of reference to deal with. I appreciate you taking care of the comments and helping out.

Comment: I was going to file a feature request about this, but then I realized that this is an extremely rare edge case (the edits wouldn't have resulted in a re-notification if the post hadn't been reattributed and the account had just been renamed).