# Low quality review doesn't get booted after one "looks good"?

Tags: bug, review, low-quality-posts

I've recently noticed that items in the Low Quality Review Queue aren't getting kicked out of the queue after one "looks good review"

Compare from a month ago:

[image: historical]

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/44689 (not the same one as the previous, however showed same sequence of items)

To something that was done today (though hasn't been yet):

[image: today]
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/47273

Note the multiple looks good *and* further reviews needed.

I want to point out that  both reviews start out with one recommend deletion and then have one followup look good.  The  historical one completed the review when the "Looks Good" was selected.

The modern one (now completed) was not completed even after *multiple* Looks Good (I don't know if it had left the queue when the third one was chosen).

Is correct? or a bug?

Comment: Perhaps it considers flag weights.

Comment: @TravisJ Flag weight doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @MichaelT can you link to the reviews in question for moar context?

Comment: @AnnaLear - Doesn't exist in the user's profile, doesn't exist internally in the system, or both?

Comment: @TravisJ Both. It was taken out some months ago.

Comment: @AnnaLear I've added the links.  The link from animuson suggests changes in flagging had an effect on the queue.  I can't see the flags on the post, it could very well play into the equation also with winterfest increasing site participation and flagging (thus needing more looks good to dequeue?).

Comment: @MichaelT The first review had no flags on it at all and the second had 4 VLQ flags. Not sure off the top of my head how many reviews would've been required to handle it without ChrisF's binding delete vote.

Comment: @AnnaLear thus the difference in dequeueing.  I'll chalk it up to "difference in participation from winterfest" -- it would be most interesting to do a report on "flags cast" (for example) for different time periods seeing how the hats influenced various behaviors.  You want to status-by-design this one then?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on the number of flags. If there is only one very low quality flag on the post, then it only takes one Looks Good decision to kick it out. If there are two, it takes two, three takes three, and so on. Likely that post had more than two VLQ flags on it, which kept it in review past the normal actions.

[Straight from the Shog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181165/can-flags-send-a-post-into-the-low-quality-posts-review-queue/190639#190639):

> If more than one VLQ flag accumulates on the post before the review has ended, a number of "Looks Good" responses equivalent to the number of flags is required to dequeue it. ...
>
> Once reviewed, further VLQ flags do not re-add the post to the queue. ...

Comment: That appears to be something from July.  The functionality appears to have changed between mid November and mid December.  Though, it *could* be because of flags (winterfest, people flagging for hats increasing that site participation?).