# 2016: a year in closing

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions, statistics, reopened-questions

A moderator asked me for data on the percentage of questions closed across all sites. This doesn't strike me as information that needs to be restricted to moderators, so for your idle enjoyment I present:

### Questions asked, closed and reopened for all sites in 2016

```
Site Name                                 QuestionsAsked Closed  PctClosed DuplicatesClosed DuplicatesReopened OTClosed OTReopened UnclearClosed UnclearReopened TooBroadClosed TooBroadReopened OpinionBasedClosed OpinionBasedReopened 
-------------------------------------------------------- ------- --------- ---------------- ------------------ -------- ---------- ------------- --------------- -------------- ---------------- ------------------ -------------------- 
Stack Overflow                               3201442      359737 11.24 %    129860             6292              99174     1500      50871          1138           66482            857            13350                160              
Super User                                     71032       10141 14.28 %      1971               71               4823       65       1683            33            1283             15              381                  9              
Server Fault                                   39209        9951 25.38 %      1021               28               7284      114        873            26             606             14              167                  3              
Stack Apps                                       278          97 34.89 %        21                0                 68        0          5             2               2              0                1                  0              
Cooking                                         2952         644 21.82 %       267               13                177       16         85             6              58              2               57                  4              
Home Improvement                                8998        1043 11.59 %       131                4                569       16        240            15              65              4               38                  0              
Game Developers                                 9889        2409 24.36 %       235               10               1324       32        229            22             405             14              216                  6              
Gaming                                         17856        4723 26.45 %      1717               49               1551       80        963            65             279             20              213                 20              
GIS                                            23091        7020 30.40 %      1133              112               2227      219       1809           281            1691            283              160                 18              
Mathematics                                   219959       32778 14.90 %      6866              205              19302      622       5663           228             655             32              292                 16              
Photography                                     3306         921 27.86 %       377                4                331        4        109             2              54              0               50                  2              
Statistical Analysis                           38578        8651 22.42 %      1183               45               4299      170       2503           332             581             27               85                  5              
Web Apps                                        5605        2263 40.37 %       290                4               1360       11        471            20             114              2               28                  0              
Webmasters                                      5852        2205 37.68 %       405               25                972       46        274            42             392             39              162                 18              
Apple                                          20048        3180 15.86 %       979               41                873       35        977           132             150             27              201                 16              
Theoretical Computer Science                    1680         560 33.33 %         7                0                512        3         32             0               6              0                3                  0              
English Language and Usage                     24178       13068 54.05 %      1949               55               8134      193       1552            58             378             22             1055                 22              
Personal Finance and Money                      5246        1197 22.82 %       160                6                718       15        158             3              76              0               85                  1              
Role-playing Games                              5127        1605 31.30 %       244               34                344       25        356           166             345             84              316                 63              
TeX - LaTeX                                    27881        5883 21.10 %      2438               99               1390       17       1868            42             109              6               78                  6              
Ubuntu                                         78381       16483 21.03 %      6545              110               5348      116       3318           129             715             17              557                  6              
Unix and Linux                                 35571        7233 20.33 %      1842               66               1743       43       2412            79             861             18              375                  8              
WordPress                                      19769        5475 27.69 %       280               10               4211       28        478            11             446              8               60                  1              
Bicycles                                        2299         502 21.84 %       158                1                190        6         83             2              40              1               31                  0              
Programmers                                    15030        6919 46.03 %       253                5               4109       35       1036            27            1037             19              484                 19              
Android Enthusiasts                            15497        3989 25.74 %       714               13               2207       27        882            64             111              1               75                  0              
Board and Card Games                            1535         310 20.20 %       126                2                 64        4         46             9              34              2               40                  8              
Physics                                        34377       11570 33.66 %      2243               42               5770       48       2847            50             500             18              210                  1              
Homebrew                                         556          14  2.52 %         7                0                  5        0          0             0               1              0                1                  0              
IT Security                                    14546        4477 30.78 %       783                8               2198       27        642            27             630             12              224                  5              
Writers                                         1310         411 31.37 %        40                0                262        9         46             2              39              4               24                  1              
Electronics and Robotics                       28314        7842 27.70 %       665                9               3129       76       2337            77            1437             26              274                  7              
Graphic Design                                  7586        2286 30.13 %       461                9               1113       34        295            16             333             14               84                  3              
Database Administrators                        16675        3396 20.37 %       463               29               1143       33       1218           112             463             23              109                  7              
Science Fiction & Fantasy                      10705        2529 23.62 %      1385              103                428       61        140            29             248             49              328                 50              
Code Review                                    16396        5158 31.46 %        51                6               4561      389        499           111              24              1               23                  0              
Code Golf                                       3114        1352 43.42 %       296               60                513       34        422           154             114             14                7                  2              
Quantitative Finance                            3120         448 14.36 %        28                0                281        8         85             2              39              2               15                  0              
Project Management                               846         213 25.18 %         5                0                104        0         28             2              40              0               36                  1              
Skeptics                                        1670         748 44.79 %       102                7                388       56        157            61              24              6               77                 13              
Drupal Answers                                 20417        3393 16.62 %       530               27               1043       45        774            57             924             32              122                  6              
Fitness and Nutrition                           1270         561 44.17 %       107                1                273        4         23             0              57              3              101                  1              
Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair            4894         616 12.59 %       131                4                145       12        128             8             157              2               55                  4                 
Parenting                                        996         299 30.02 %        38                1                154        4         63             9              23              0               21                  1              
SharePoint                                     17049         955  5.60 %       221               11                303       23        234            54             138             17               59                  6              
Musical Practice and Performance                3121         882 28.26 %       110                7                438        8        122             8             108              3              104                  4              
Software Quality Assurance and Testing          2215         725 32.73 %        60                0                142        0        242             1             166              1              115                  1                   
Jewish Life and Learning                        4095        1146 27.99 %       413               27                374       30        239            42              74             12               46                  3              
Astronomy                                       1869         448 23.97 %       114                1                148        9        121             7              34              2               31                  1              
German Language and Usage                       2088         557 26.68 %       113                2                310       22         77             9              35              1               22                  3              
Japanese Language and Usage                     3503         602 17.19 %       162                5                371       18         38             2              18              2               13                  2              
Gardening and Landscaping                       2121         204  9.62 %        55                0                 54        8         58             5              31              0                6                  0              
Philosophy                                      2697         943 34.96 %        55                2                421       26        242            16             119             10              106                  3              
Personal Productivity                            382         174 45.55 %        26                0                 75        0         23             1              34              0               16                  1              
Travel                                          8018        3379 42.14 %      1286               55                966       91        573            70             245             18              309                 37              
Cryptography                                    4656        1454 31.23 %       259               24                859       44        202            28             103             11               31                  7              
Signal Processing                               3890         827 21.26 %        78                1                279       18        317            72             137             14               16                  2              
French Language and Usage                       1859         227 12.21 %        73                3                113        5         19             1              14              0                8                  1              
Christianity                                    2324        1755 75.52 %       139                5                443       26        265             6             284             19              624                 28              
Bitcoin                                         2766         564 20.39 %       250               12                147        3        109             7              30              1               28                  2              
Linguistics                                     1397         374 26.77 %        22                1                211        9         75             0              42              0               24                  0              
Biblical Hermeneutics                           1268         415 32.73 %        76                1                217       25         66             5              20              2               36                  3              
Economics                                       2551         572 22.42 %        26                0                375        2        102             1              51              1               18                  1              
History                                         1977         717 36.27 %        37                0                331       13        136            11              99              7              114                  1              
LEGO®                                            456          87 19.08 %        30                1                 27        1         21             1               7              0                2                  0              
Spanish Language and Usage                      1141         151 13.23 %        37                0                 79        3         11             1              11              0               13                  0              
Computational Science                           1725         342 19.83 %        18                1                214        1         73             3              28              0                9                  1              
Movies                                          7328        2506 34.20 %       235                6               1927       67         96             7             102             12              146                 15              
Chinese Language and Usage                       966         179 18.53 %        18                0                124        4         11             1              18              2                8                  0              
Biology                                         5687        1919 33.74 %       153                0                744       13        506             6             297              1              219                  2              
Poker                                            290          79 27.24 %        46                0                 11        0          7             0               9              1                6                  1              
Mathematica                                    13642        4526 33.18 %      1072               29               2877       69        478            30              84              6               15                  2              
Cognitive Sciences                              1345         521 38.74 %        22                0                201        5        115             0             117              2               66                  1              
The Great Outdoors                               891         142 15.94 %        25                2                 61       15         11             4              30              6               15                  5              
Martial Arts                                     271          62 22.88 %        15                0                 17        0          5             0              16              1                9                  0              
Sports                                          1004         316 31.47 %        40                2                111        8         30             4              49              3               86                  4              
Academia                                        7402        2952 39.88 %       531               24               1784       57        378            30             178             10               81                 10              
Computer Science                                7972        2444 30.66 %       373               19                950       14        836            43             186              8               99                  0              
The Workplace                                   6262        3039 48.53 %       541                4               1749       53        298            16             201              8              250                  9              
Windows Phone                                    788         143 18.15 %        65                0                 49        3         19             2               1              0                9                  0              
Chemistry                                      10428        3805 36.49 %       484               18               2225       83        694            34             344             14               58                  2              
Chess                                            814         107 13.14 %        39                1                 21        0         17             0              16              0               14                  1              
Raspberry Pi                                    8218        1515 18.44 %       372               27                523       21        298            62             268             17               54                  4              
Russian Language and Usage                       633          93 14.69 %        10                0                 63        8         10             2               9              2                1                  0              
Islam                                           2210         424 19.19 %       101                0                100        0        118             2              35              0               70                  0              
Salesforce                                     23051        3387 14.69 %       503               19               1616       75        722            40             468             15               78                  2              
Patents                                         1121         436 38.89 %        79                0                316        5         35             3               5              1                1                  0              
User Experience                                 4699        1328 28.26 %       113                1                544       10        106             8             270              7              295                  9              
Genealogy and Family History                     467          97 20.77 %        39                2                 15        0         26             6              15              4                2                  0              
Robotics                                        1173         476 40.58 %        26                0                159       15        121            13              67              2              103                  3              
ExpressionEngine                                1380          23  1.67 %         2                0                 13        1          5             0               3              0                0                  0              
Politics                                        1747         554 31.71 %        63                3                105        6        107             9              88              3              191                 17              
Audio-Video Production                          1415         146 10.32 %        17                0                 80        0         15             1              25              0                9                  0              
Anime and Manga                                 3371        3109 92.23 %       121                4               2739       31        100            15              59              8               90                  5              
Magento                                        27444        2966 10.81 %       735               14               1336       17        453            23             315              7              127                  0              
English Language Learners                      13102        2709 20.68 %       625               26               1594      128        210            23             151              9              129                 13              
Sustainable Living                               260          44 16.92 %         8                0                 14        2          9             1               9              0                4                  0              
Tridion                                         1176          23  1.96 %        11                1                  5        1          3             0               4              0                0                  0              
Reverse Engineering                             1364         338 24.78 %        30                0                149        1        114             2              39              1                6                  0               
Arduino                                         5759         802 13.93 %        92                1                247        9        280             3             157              3               26                  0              
Network Engineering                             5373        2241 41.71 %        88                1               1933       22         53             7             134              3               33                  3               
Open Data                                       1268          75  5.91 %        27                2                 28        1         14             1               5              0                1                  0              
Freelancing                                      433         118 27.25 %         8                0                 53        0          5             0              29              2               23                  0              
Blender                                        12187        1504 12.34 %       871               24                261        9        224            21             107              6               41                  2              
MathOverflow                                   16748        4162 24.85 %        78                4               3431       77        535            30              74              3               44                  5              
Space Exploration                               1972         451 22.87 %       116               11                113       10         77            12              90              8               55                  8              
Sound Design                                    1060         207 19.53 %        16                0                154        4          8             1              14              0               15                  2              
Tor                                             1523         517 33.95 %       216                2                 63        0        195             4              30              1               13                  0              
Pets                                             986         127 12.88 %        64                1                 38        1          7             2              10              0                8                  0              
Amateur Radio                                    484          85 17.56 %         7                1                 53        5          8             2              12              3                5                  0              
Italian Language                                 532          36  6.77 %         6                1                 23        3          4             0               1              0                2                  0              
Stack Overflow em Português                    32171        6816 21.19 %      1168               46               1840       73       2557           128             970             27              281                  9              
Aviation                                        3227         872 27.02 %       286               30                225       34        154            35             151             28               56                  8              
Ebooks                                           248          46 18.55 %         1                0                 36        0          5             0               3              0                1                  0              
Beer                                             192          31 16.15 %         3                0                 11        0          5             0               7              1                5                  1              
Software Recommendations                        4785         778 16.26 %        45                0                345       21        266            49             102             18               20                  0                    
Expatriates                                     1167         171 14.65 %        37                1                 44        0         43             4              26              0               21                  0              
Mathematics Educators                            440          84 19.09 %         3                0                 62        0          9             1               8              1                2                  0                 
Earth Science                                    956         180 18.83 %        23                0                 70        4         57             4              24              1                6                  0              
Joomla                                          1721         222 12.90 %        35                0                 67        0         32             3              81              2                7                  0              
Data Science                                    3248         572 17.61 %        12                0                198        1        176            17             129              3               57                  0              
Puzzling                                        4869         852 17.50 %       203               10                286       32        114            17             237             29               12                  0              
Craft CMS                                       2523         130  5.15 %        45                0                 69        2          2             1              14              0                0                  0              
Buddhism                                         936          69  7.37 %        22                2                 24        4          8             4               5              3               10                  2              
Hinduism                                        2203         508 23.06 %       260               11                126       17         45             5              26              3               51                  9              
Moderators                                        90          17 18.89 %         1                0                 10        0          2             0               4              0                0                  0              
Startups                                        1008         192 19.05 %        14                0                 85        0         22             0              55              0               16                  0              
Worldbuilding                                   5849        1793 30.65 %       164                5                525       46        214            16             571             51              319                 24              
スタック・オーバーフロー                          5076         206  4.06 %        33                3                 51        5         65             7              39              4               18                  0              
Emacs                                           4202         164  3.90 %        92                0                 20        2         22             2              18              1               12                  0              
History of Science and Mathematics               552          58 10.51 %        16                1                 29        1          9             0               2              0                2                  0                              
Lifehacks                                        804         349 43.41 %        31                2                297        2         13             1               7              0                1                  0              
Engineering                                     2710         911 33.62 %        35                4                244       11        338            25             266              8               28                  3              
Coffee                                           256          30 11.72 %        12                0                  6        0          4             0               5              0                3                  0              
Vi and Vim                                      2038         186  9.13 %        84                7                 54        2         17             4              22              2                9                  1              
Music Fans                                       787         129 16.39 %         5                0                 52        0         13             0              23              0               36                  0              
Woodworking                                      683          87 12.74 %        20                1                 27        4         12             2              19              4                9                  0              
CiviCRM                                         3101          67  2.16 %        39                0                  8        0         15             1               4              1                1                  0              
Health                                          2418         578 23.90 %        20                0                436       12         40             1              49              2               33                  1              
Stack Overflow на русском                      63634        9137 14.36 %      1283               35               2800      107       2030           108            1393             61             1631                 32              
Русский язык                                    1988         203 10.21 %        13                0                140        4         27             1              11              0               12                  0              
Mythology                                        361          37 10.25 %         1                0                  9        0         14             4              10              3                3                  1              
Law                                             3752         463 12.34 %        51                1                209       13        106            11              58              3               39                  2              
Open Source                                      691         155 22.43 %        26                0                 86        9         16             2              15              3               12                  3              
elementary OS                                   2450         518 21.14 %       210                4                241        4         45             0              11              0               11                  1              
Portuguese Language                              470          31  6.60 %        11                1                 11        1          4             1               4              0                1                  0               
Computer Graphics                                791         153 19.34 %         3                1                 90        5         39             3              19              0                2                  0              
Hardware Recommendations                        1676         961 57.34 %         7                1                783       48         36             8              90             10               45                  3                    
Stack Overflow en español                      16154        3229 19.99 %       225               13                618      101       1124           184             892            114              370                 33              
Documentation Beta                               757          31  4.10 %        24                0                  4        0          3             1               0              0                0                  0              
3D Printing                                      767         113 14.73 %         6                0                 40        1         15             4              31              2               21                  6              
Ethereum                                        4309         648 15.04 %       360               34                 85        8         78            15              65              9               60                 10              
Latin Language                                   854          28  3.28 %         7                1                  4        0          5             2              10              4                2                  0              
Language Learning                                478         152 31.80 %        11                1                 39        7         17             7              40             14               45                 22              
Retrocomputing                                   509          51 10.02 %         4                0                 20        0          6             3              17              2                4                  2              
Arts & Crafts                                    535          75 14.02 %         3                0                 40        3          6             0              18              4                8                  2              
Korean Language                                  407          15  3.69 %         3                0                  6        2          1             1               4              2                1                  1              
Monero                                          1065         116 10.89 %        42                2                 11        1          8             0              25              5               30                  2              
Artificial Intelligence                          581         148 25.47 %         6                0                 88        9         13             1              26              2               15                  2                   
Esperanto Language                               749          26  3.47 %        10                1                  5        0          1             0               6              3                4                  0              
Sitecore                                        1273         101  7.93 %        17                2                 49        2          9             0              18              2                8                  2              
Internet of Things                               149          37 24.83 %         1                0                 10        1          7             3              16              3                3                  2
```

Caveats:

- this counts questions asked in 2016 and questions closed in 2016 - it does NOT ensure that the questions closed were also asked in 2016 (so big cleanup efforts will skew the %). See answer [for stats on questions asked *and* closed in 2016.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289797/2016-a-year-in-closing/289830#289830).
- if a question was closed twice, it'll be counted twice
- if a question was reopened twice, it'll be counted twice

Comment: By what (if any) characteristic was that table sorted?

Comment: No big surprise that on Martial Arts .. stuff _stays_ closed.

Comment: Looks like site id (i.e. the order the sites were created), @feet

Comment: For anyone interested in making use of this data, [here it is in CSV format](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0xRBj17XkNmcHR0TzFDWTFXOEk/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Programmers? Sounds like an interesting site, what is it about?

Comment: It's like a support group of some sort, @yannis. Never go there.

Comment: With 46.03% close rate, I'm not going anywhere near it @Shog9.

Comment: Why are the names of some sites truncated? "Code Golf" should be "Programming Puzzles and Code Golf" and "Science Fiction" should be "Science Fiction and Fantasy". (it's not name length, history of science and math and spanish SO are both long)

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ Fantasy never gets enough love :'(

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ Our internal database shortens some of the names.

Comment: @bluefeet ah, okay

Comment: I think ideally we could learn reopen reasons - that is, was the question fixed, or was the close incorrect to begin with - then we might have a better measure of how good we are. Then if we want to focus on optimization we can seek to minimize incorrect closures, increase closure rate of poor questions, or increase the percentage fixed and reopened - based on the needs of the site and community, of course.

Comment: Heh... still "Electronics and Robotics".

Comment: Those damn robots just refused to leave.

Comment: Do these numbers include deleted posts? Would limiting it to questions also _opened_ in 2016 be very hard numbers to run? Because that would tell us a lot more about Christianity which has still been cleaning up 2011-2012 questions prior to our scope changes.

Comment: Also, what did the world do to poor *Anime and Manga*? 92% question closure? And I thought we were harsh on *Christianity* with our 75%!

Comment: Anime & Manga did a rather large [cleanup of identification-requests](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2825/please-blacklist-the-identification-request-tag-and-lock-all-question-with-the) this past year, @Caleb. Phases [1](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2812/identification-request-cleanup-phase-1-deprecation), [2](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2824/identification-request-cleanup-phase-2-blacklisting), [3](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3839/identification-request-cleanup-phase-3-final-delete-lock)

Comment: [Here you go](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289797/2016-a-year-in-closing/289830#289830), @Caleb.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Any chance of posting a CSV for Shog9's additional stats in http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289830/215590 ?

Comment: @PolyGeo Link's under the answer.

Answer (score 16):

A few folks have requested (or expressed dismay and confusion at the absence of) data on questions that were both asked *and* closed in 2016. So... Here it is:

```
Site Name                              QuestionsAsked   Closed PctClosed DuplicatesClosed DuplicatesReopened OTClosed OTReopened UnclearClosed UnclearReopened TooBroadClosed TooBroadReopened OpinionBasedClosed OpinionBasedReopened 
-------------------------------------- -------------- -------- --------- ---------------- ------------------ -------- ---------- ------------- --------------- -------------- ---------------- ------------------ -------------------- 
Stack Overflow                              3,201,442  342,405    10.70%          123,428              6,167   92,357      1,432        50,015           1,130         64,336              822             12,269                  132 
Super User                                     71,032    9,308    13.10%            1,755                 64    4,313         64         1,630              32          1,241               15                369                    9 
Server Fault                                   39,209    9,463    24.13%              977                 28    6,897        113           850              26            588               14                151                    3 
Stack Apps                                        278       92    33.09%               16                  0       68          0             5               2              2                0                  1                    0 
Cooking                                         2,952      584    19.78%              255                 13      164         16            80               5             41                2                 44                    4 
Home Improvement                                8,998      994    11.05%              123                  4      552         16           219              15             64                4                 36                    0 
Game Developers                                 9,889    2,237    22.62%              222                 10    1,231         31           222              22            361               13                201                    6 
Gaming                                         17,856    4,523    25.33%            1,624                 49    1,480         77           938              65            271               20                210                   20 
GIS                                            23,091    5,479    23.73%              975                108    1,589        215         1,483             279          1,301              273                131                   18 
Mathematics                                   219,959   31,060    14.12%            6,243                181   18,394        607         5,535             228            621               31                267                   15 
Photography                                     3,306      872    26.38%              365                  4      305          4           100               2             52                0                 50                    2 
Statistical Analysis                           38,578    8,353    21.65%            1,101                 43    4,188        168         2,413             331            569               27                 82                    5 
Web Apps                                        5,605    1,886    33.65%              233                  4    1,109         11           436              20             85                2                 23                    0 
Webmasters                                      5,852    2,166    37.01%              398                 24      948         46           272              42            388               39                160                   18 
Apple                                          20,048    2,995    14.94%              861                 39      834         34           958             132            143               27                199                   15 
Theoretical Computer Science                    1,680      554    32.98%                7                  0      506          3            32               0              6                0                  3                    0 
English Language and Usage                     24,178   12,542    51.87%            1,843                 53    7,822        190         1,509              58            362               22              1,006                   22 
Personal Finance and Money                      5,246    1,101    20.99%              156                  6      642         13           150               3             73                0                 80                    1 
Role-playing Games                              5,127    1,384    26.99%              238                 34      185         23           353             165            306               84                302                   63 
TeX - LaTeX                                    27,881    4,501    16.14%            2,167                 95    1,065         15         1,128              39             74                6                 67                    6 
Ubuntu                                         78,381   14,902    19.01%            5,941                102    4,571        111         3,195             127            665               17                530                    6 
Unix and Linux                                 35,571    6,736    18.94%            1,742                 66    1,573         41         2,236              79            836               18                349                    8 
WordPress                                      19,769    5,024    25.41%              262                 10    3,854         27           444              11            411                7                 53                    1 
Bicycles                                        2,299      480    20.88%              155                  1      180          6            79               2             40                1                 26                    0 
Programmers                                    15,030    6,598    43.90%              247                  5    3,979         34         1,020              27            933               19                419                   19 
Android Enthusiasts                            15,497    3,815    24.62%              645                 13    2,149         27           847              63            102                1                 72                    0 
Board and Card Games                            1,535      297    19.35%              119                  2       63          4            44               9             32                2                 39                    8 
Physics                                        34,377   11,347    33.01%            2,165                 41    5,696         47         2,798              49            486               18                202                    1 
Homebrew                                          556       12     2.16%                6                  0        5          0             0               0              1                0                  0                    0 
IT Security                                    14,546    4,400    30.25%              750                  8    2,168         25           637              27            624               12                221                    5 
Writers                                         1,310      396    30.23%               38                  0      254          9            44               2             38                3                 22                    1 
Electronics and Robotics                       28,314    7,575    26.75%              649                  9    3,040         75         2,246              77          1,378               26                262                    7 
Graphic Design                                  7,586    2,197    28.96%              432                  9    1,067         34           287              15            328               14                 83                    3 
Database Administrators                        16,675    3,246    19.47%              437                 29    1,066         33         1,185             112            450               23                108                    7 
Science Fiction                                10,705    2,182    20.38%            1,126                 95      391         60           135              29            224               47                306                   49 
Area 51 Discussions                             1,353      193    14.26%               35                  2      151          2             7               1              0                0                  0                    0 
Code Review                                    16,396    5,040    30.74%               48                  6    4,474        388           472             103             23                1                 23                    0 
Code Golf                                       3,114    1,158    37.19%              282                 59      417         28           385             152             68               11                  6                    2 
Quantitative Finance                            3,120      444    14.23%               28                  0      279          8            85               2             37                2                 15                    0 
Project Management                                846      197    23.29%                3                  0       99          0            28               2             38                0                 29                    1 
Skeptics                                        1,670      733    43.89%               97                  7      380         56           156              60             24                6                 76                   13 
Drupal Answers                                 20,417    2,705    13.25%              421                 26      773         39           654              57            764               32                 93                    6 
Fitness and Nutrition                           1,270      536    42.20%               99                  1      261          4            22               0             56                3                 98                    1 
Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair            4,894      542    11.07%              122                  4      134         12           116               8            118                2                 52                    4 
Parenting                                         996      289    29.02%               35                  1      152          4            61               9             21                0                 20                    1 
SharePoint                                     17,049      929     5.45%              210                 11      295         23           232              54            135               17                 57                    6 
Musical Practice and Performance                3,121      856    27.43%              108                  7      425          8           118               8            104                3                101                    4 
Software Quality Assurance and Testing          2,215      640    28.89%               53                  0      111          0           218               1            149                1                109                    1 
Jewish Life and Learning                        4,095    1,046    25.54%              397                 26      308         27           234              42             65               12                 42                    2 
Astronomy                                       1,869      425    22.74%              108                  1      143          9           114               7             31                2                 29                    1 
German Language and Usage                       2,088      545    26.10%              112                  2      303         22            75               9             33                1                 22                    3 
Japanese Language and Usage                     3,503      579    16.53%              154                  5      357         17            37               2             18                2                 13                    2 
Gardening and Landscaping                       2,121      191     9.01%               51                  0       51          8            57               5             26                0                  6                    0 
Philosophy                                      2,697      757    28.07%               51                  2      368         24           177              14             63                7                 98                    3 
Personal Productivity                             382      166    43.46%               24                  0       72          0            22               1             34                0                 14                    1 
Travel                                          8,018    3,234    40.33%            1,212                 55      942         89           557              69            233               18                290                   37 
Cryptography                                    4,656    1,399    30.05%              241                 21      830         43           199              28             99               10                 30                    7 
Signal Processing                               3,890      800    20.57%               76                  1      268         18           306              72            135               14                 15                    2 
French Language and Usage                       1,859      223    12.00%               70                  3      113          5            18               1             14                0                  8                    1 
Christianity                                    2,324    1,329    57.19%              132                  5      378         26           252               6            200               16                367                   25 
Bitcoin                                         2,766      516    18.66%              235                 12      126          3           103               6             25                0                 27                    2 
Linguistics                                     1,397      356    25.48%               21                  1      202          9            71               0             39                0                 23                    0 
Biblical Hermeneutics                           1,268      403    31.78%               74                  1      212         24            64               4             20                2                 33                    2 
Economics                                       2,551      567    22.23%               25                  0      373          2           100               1             51                1                 18                    1 
History                                         1,977      704    35.61%               36                  0      323         13           135              11             99                7                111                    1 
LEGO®                                             456       78    17.11%               28                  1       27          1            15               0              6                0                  2                    0 
Spanish Language and Usage                      1,141      142    12.45%               34                  0       74          3            11               1             10                0                 13                    0 
Computational Science                           1,725      332    19.25%               18                  1      206          1            71               3             28                0                  9                    1 
Movies                                          7,328    2,296    31.33%              227                  6    1,736         67            93               7             97               12                143                   15 
Chinese Language and Usage                        966      165    17.08%               15                  0      120          4            11               1             15                1                  4                    0 
Biology                                         5,687    1,874    32.95%              150                  0      736         13           492               6            289                1                207                    2 
Poker                                             290       78    26.90%               46                  0       10          0             7               0              9                1                  6                    1 
Mathematica                                    13,642    4,124    30.23%              981                 27    2,615         68           442              30             72                6                 14                    1 
Cognitive Sciences                              1,345      465    34.57%               20                  0      184          5           108               0             94                2                 59                    0 
The Great Outdoors                                891      137    15.38%               25                  2       61         15             8               4             28                6                 15                    5 
Martial Arts                                      271       61    22.51%               14                  0       17          0             5               0             16                1                  9                    0 
Sports                                          1,004      293    29.18%               40                  2       97          8            29               4             45                3                 82                    4 
Academia                                        7,402    2,882    38.94%              511                 24    1,754         56           361              29            175               10                 81                   10 
Computer Science                                7,972    2,394    30.03%              365                 19      938         14           812              43            181                8                 98                    0 
The Workplace                                   6,262    3,001    47.92%              525                  4    1,732         52           296              16            199                8                249                    9 
Windows Phone                                     788      138    17.51%               61                  0       48          3            19               2              1                0                  9                    0 
Chemistry                                      10,428    3,695    35.43%              461                 18    2,180         83           671              34            327               14                 56                    1 
Chess                                             814       98    12.04%               35                  1       20          0            16               0             15                0                 12                    1 
Raspberry Pi                                    8,218    1,478    17.98%              350                 27      516         21           295              62            264               17                 53                    3 
Russian Language and Usage                        633       90    14.22%                9                  0       63          8             9               2              8                2                  1                    0 
Islam                                           2,210      396    17.92%               94                  0       93          0           113               2             35                0                 61                    0 
Salesforce                                     23,051    3,267    14.17%              491                 19    1,520         75           713              40            466               15                 77                    2 
Patents                                         1,121      430    38.36%               76                  0      313          5            35               3              5                1                  1                    0 
User Experience                                 4,700    1,289    27.43%              107                  1      536         10           102               8            263                7                281                    8 
Genealogy and Family History                      467       85    18.20%               34                  2       15          0            22               6             12                4                  2                    0 
Robotics                                        1,173      431    36.74%               26                  0      149         15           107              12             63                2                 86                    3 
ExpressionEngine                                1,380       22     1.59%                1                  0       13          1             5               0              3                0                  0                    0 
Politics                                        1,747      536    30.68%               61                  3       99          6           102               9             86                3                188                   17 
Audio-Video Production                          1,415      139     9.82%               16                  0       76          0            15               1             23                0                  9                    0 
Anime and Manga                                 3,371    1,511    44.82%              116                  4    1,154         31            99              15             56                8                 86                    5 
Magento                                        27,444    2,480     9.04%              670                 14    1,014         17           411              23            271                7                114                    0 
English Language Learners                      13,102    2,594    19.80%              566                 26    1,549        125           207              23            147                9                125                   13 
Sustainable Living                                260       38    14.62%                3                  0       13          2             9               1              9                0                  4                    0 
Tridion                                         1,176       23     1.96%               11                  1        5          1             3               0              4                0                  0                    0 
Reverse Engineering                             1,364      334    24.49%               30                  0      147          1           113               2             38                1                  6                    0 
Arduino                                         5,759      733    12.73%               83                  1      236          9           243               3            146                3                 25                    0 
Network Engineering                             5,373    2,220    41.32%               87                  1    1,913         22            53               7            134                3                 33                    3 
Open Data                                       1,268       70     5.52%               24                  2       28          1            13               1              4                0                  1                    0 
Freelancing                                       433      116    26.79%                8                  0       52          0             5               0             28                2                 23                    0 
Blender                                        12,187    1,468    12.05%              848                 24      258          9           217              21            105                6                 40                    2 
MathOverflow                                   16,748    4,094    24.44%               74                  4    3,390         77           517              29             73                3                 40                    5 
Space Exploration                               1,972      438    22.21%              112                 11      111         10            75              12             86                8                 54                    7 
Sound Design                                    1,060      191    18.02%               15                  0      145          4             7               1             14                0                 10                    1 
Tor                                             1,523      480    31.52%              197                  1       58          0           184               3             28                1                 13                    0 
Pets                                              986      121    12.27%               61                  1       38          1             7               2              8                0                  7                    0 
Amateur Radio                                     484       85    17.56%                7                  1       53          5             8               2             12                3                  5                    0 
Italian Language                                  532       36     6.77%                6                  1       23          3             4               0              1                0                  2                    0 
Stack Overflow em Português                    32,171    6,389    19.86%            1,128                 45    1,683         73         2,389             128            917               27                272                    8 
Aviation                                        3,227      857    26.56%              283                 29      221         34           151              35            148               28                 54                    8 
Ebooks                                            248       44    17.74%                1                  0       35          0             5               0              2                0                  1                    0 
Beer                                              192       29    15.10%                2                  0       10          0             5               0              7                1                  5                    1 
Software Recommendations                        4,785      766    16.01%               44                  0      342         21           262              49             98               18                 20                    0 
Expatriates                                     1,167      154    13.20%               35                  1       43          0            38               4             23                0                 15                    0 
Mathematics Educators                             440       83    18.86%                3                  0       62          0             8               0              8                1                  2                    0 
Earth Science                                     956      174    18.20%               23                  0       70          4            54               4             21                1                  6                    0 
Joomla                                          1,721      184    10.69%               33                  0       55          0            31               3             58                2                  7                    0 
Data Science                                    3,248      545    16.78%               12                  0      187          1           169              17            123                3                 54                    0 
Puzzling                                        4,869      823    16.90%              195                 10      277         32           109              17            230               29                 12                    0 
Craft CMS                                       2,523      127     5.03%               44                  0       67          2             2               1             14                0                  0                    0 
Buddhism                                          936       68     7.26%               22                  2       24          4             8               4              4                3                 10                    2 
Hinduism                                        2,203      460    20.88%              227                 10      121         17            41               4             24                3                 47                    8 
Moderators                                         90       17    18.89%                1                  0       10          0             2               0              4                0                  0                    0 
Startups                                        1,008      187    18.55%               13                  0       81          0            22               0             55                0                 16                    0 
Worldbuilding                                   5,849    1,767    30.21%              162                  5      514         45           212              16            563               51                316                   23 
スタック・オーバーフロー                                 5,076      203     4.00%               33                  3       51          5            64               7             38                4                 17                    0 
Emacs                                           4,202      158     3.76%               88                  0       20          2            21               2             18                1                 11                    0 
History of Science and Mathematics                552       57    10.33%               15                  1       29          1             9               0              2                0                  2                    0 
Lifehacks                                         804      343    42.66%               31                  2      291          2            13               1              7                0                  1                    0 
Engineering                                     2,710      901    33.25%               34                  4      242         11           334              25            264                8                 27                    3 
Coffee                                            256       29    11.33%               11                  0        6          0             4               0              5                0                  3                    0 
Vi and Vim                                      2,038      171     8.39%               79                  6       47          1            15               4             21                2                  9                    1 
Music Fans                                        787      111    14.10%                5                  0       47          0             9               0             17                0                 33                    0 
Woodworking                                       683       86    12.59%               20                  1       27          4            11               1             19                4                  9                    0 
CiviCRM                                         3,101       65     2.10%               38                  0        8          0            14               1              4                1                  1                    0 
Health                                          2,418      559    23.12%               16                  0      426         12            40               1             45                2                 32                    1 
Stack Overflow на русском                      63,634    8,402    13.20%            1,192                 34    2,571        106         1,940             108          1,307               59              1,392                   26 
Русский язык                                    1,988      178     8.95%                9                  0      130          4            22               1              8                0                  9                    0 
Mythology                                         361       37    10.25%                1                  0        9          0            14               4             10                3                  3                    1 
Law                                             3,752      457    12.18%               51                  1      206         12           105              11             57                3                 38                    2 
Open Source                                       691      153    22.14%               26                  0       86          9            16               2             13                3                 12                    3 
elementary OS                                   2,450      459    18.73%              185                  3      213          4            41               0              9                0                 11                    1 
Portuguese Language                               470       31     6.60%               11                  1       11          1             4               1              4                0                  1                    0 
Computer Graphics                                 791      148    18.71%                3                  1       86          5            38               3             19                0                  2                    0 
Hardware Recommendations                        1,676      955    56.98%                7                  1      779         48            36               8             90               10                 43                    3 
Stack Overflow en español                      16,154    3,225    19.96%              225                 13      617        101         1,121             183            892              114                370                   33 
Documentation Beta                                757       28     3.70%               21                  0        4          0             3               1              0                0                  0                    0 
3D Printing                                       767      113    14.73%                6                  0       40          1            15               4             31                2                 21                    6 
Ethereum                                        4,309      648    15.04%              360                 34       85          8            78              15             65                9                 60                   10 
Latin Language                                    854       28     3.28%                7                  1        4          0             5               2             10                4                  2                    0 
Language Learning                                 478      152    31.80%               11                  1       39          7            17               7             40               14                 45                   22 
Retrocomputing                                    509       51    10.02%                4                  0       20          0             6               3             17                2                  4                    2 
Arts & Crafts                                     535       75    14.02%                3                  0       40          3             6               0             18                4                  8                    2 
Korean Language                                   407       15     3.69%                3                  0        6          2             1               1              4                2                  1                    1 
Monero                                          1,065      116    10.89%               42                  2       11          1             8               0             25                5                 30                    2 
Artificial Intelligence                           581      148    25.47%                6                  0       88          9            13               1             26                2                 15                    2 
Esperanto Language                                749       26     3.47%               10                  1        5          0             1               0              6                3                  4                    0 
Sitecore                                        1,273      101     7.93%               17                  2       49          2             9               0             18                2                  8                    2 
Internet of Things                                149       37    24.83%                1                  0       10          1             7               3             16                3                  3                    2
```

Caveats:

- if a question was closed twice, it'll still be counted twice
- if a question was reopened twice, it'll still be counted twice
- This ignores questions asked in 2016 and closed in 2017.
- This can be misleading for sites that *didn't* go through big organized cleanups in the same way that the query above is misleading for sites that did.
- I added commas to the numbers, so it looks really classy in that "bank statement" way - but it's not a bank statement, I don't remember anything about RPG, and no one's making bank closing questions.

Comment: is there a way to show how much of OTClosed were (successfully) migrated? I've heard somewhere that ELU migrates a lot to ELL, wonder if this explains their rather high close rate

Comment: Those can be gleaned for the last 90 days from various 10K tools on EL&U, @gnat. For the entire year, there were about 570 migrations in total... The bulk of OT questions - 5240 in all - fall under the reason, *"Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic."*

Comment: thanks! (I asked because I don't have access to 10K tools at EL&U) Seems safe to generally say that migrations don't make substantial impact on closing stats, even at sites having established successful migration path like ELU -> ELL

Comment: [Here's the CSV for these stats.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0xRBj17XkNmMDVyU2lZLUdOZlk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @gnat Most bad off-topic ELU questions are also off-topic at ELL.

Comment: I see @curiousdannii - stats here suggest that ELU is overwhelmed with bad questions, just like many other sites. Quite a pity that SE management doesn't do anything to help in closing these. One can even argue that they do the opposite by [advertising close-worthy questions in HNQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237391/165773)

Answer (score 11):

If a question gets no answers, it does not matter much if it's closed or not. I took a look at all questions created in 2016 (including deleted), separating the category of "closed or has no answers" (C or NA below). This appears to be an accurate measure of the futility of asking questions on a given site. [Source: SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/615901/questions-from-2016-that-are-either-closed-or-unanswered-with-deleted).

```
   Site               Questions    C or NA     % C or NA   
Hardwarerecs             1682        1144            68
StackApps                 278         185          66.5
Softwarerecs             4798        2856          59.5
Christianity             2330        1366          58.6
Cogsci                   1349         768          56.9
Patents                  1124         635          56.5
Stats                   38634       21662          56.1
English                 24227       13535          55.9
Health                   2423        1321          54.5
Anime                    3384        1842          54.4
Chemistry               10448        5621          53.8
Biology                  5691        3057          53.7
Tor                      1525         818          53.6
Android                 15529        8116          52.3
Networkengineerin        5385        2813          52.2
Ubuntu                  78556       40678          51.8
Programmers             15060        7574          50.3
Hinduism                 2207        1100          49.8
WebApps                  5621        2799          49.8
Cstheory                 1689         840          49.7
Mathoverflow            16777        8288          49.4
ServerFault             39287       18861            48
Skeptics                 1673         803            48
Economics                2554        1216          47.6
Engineering              2713        1288          47.5
Robotics                 1174         553          47.1
Scicomp                  1727         811            47
Productivity              382         179          46.9
Physics                 34431       16085          46.7
Workplace                6270        2920          46.6
Webmasters               5863        2683          45.8
History                  1979         897          45.3
Opendata                 1271         568          44.7
Fitness                  1275         569          44.6
Elementaryos             2457        1076          43.8
Mathematica             13661        5948          43.5
Cs                       7988        3461          43.3
Raspberrypi              8248        3569          43.3
Sqa                      2218         956          43.1
Reverseengineerin        1368         589          43.1
SuperUser               71222       30427          42.7
GameDev                  9912        4213          42.5
Ebooks                    248         105          42.3
Linguistics              1403         594          42.3
Lifehacks                 806         340          42.2
Judaism                  4105        1728          42.1
Expatriates              1169         490          41.9
Academia                 7417        3053          41.2
Wordpress               19808        8129            41
Apple                   20086        8195          40.8
Crypto                   4663        1895          40.6
Graphicdesign            7605        3079          40.5
Datascience              3252        1315          40.4
Gis                     23120        9329          40.4
Windowsphone              788         315            40
Dsp                      3896        1546          39.7
Security                14574        5704          39.1
Islam                    2214         866          39.1
Philosophy               2706        1045          38.6
Codereview              16438        6299          38.3
Magento                 27483       10461          38.1
Hermeneutics             1270         482            38
Movies                   7348        2788          37.9
Travel                   8034        3037          37.8
Quant                    3129        1178          37.6
Expressionengine         1383         519          37.5
Politics                 1750         656          37.5
Unix                    35656       13351          37.4
Blender                 12211        4565          37.4
Br.StackOverflow        32211       11710          36.4
Electronics             28382       10221            36
Avp                      1420         498          35.1
Sound                    1060         371            35
Earthscience              958         330          34.4
Musicfans                 787         271          34.4
Sports                   1005         342            34
Math                   220365       73761          33.5
Ru.StackOverflow        63678       21305          33.5
Bitcoin                  2771         926          33.4
Dba                     16702        5569          33.3
Gaming                  17892        5921          33.1
Salesforce              23088        7462          32.3
Sharepoint              17073        5487          32.1
Photography              3313        1062          32.1
StackOverflow         3207203     1012752          31.6
Writers                  1314         414          31.5
Ux                       4709        1459            31
Codegolf                 3121         964          30.9
Drupal                  20447        6284          30.7
Tex                     27921        8572          30.7
Computergraphics          791         241          30.5
Law                      3757        1136          30.2
Ai                        581         175          30.1
Music                    3125         936            30
Astronomy                1872         560          29.9
Emacs                    4208        1250          29.7
Space                    1980         570          28.8
Matheducators             440         126          28.6
Es.StackOverflow        16159        4608          28.5
Hsm                       552         156          28.3
Poker                     292          82          28.1
Genealogy                 467         131          28.1
Joomla                   1727         484            28
Parenting                 997         279            28
Worldbuilding            5853        1633          27.9
Money                    5255        1463          27.8
Freelancing               433         120          27.7
Startups                 1009         277          27.5
Pm                        847         232          27.4
Scifi                   10739        2934          27.3
Pets                      987         264          26.7
Arduino                  5769        1537          26.6
Bicycles                 2301         603          26.2
Aviation                 3233         834          25.8
Languagelearning          478         123          25.7
Civicrm                  3105         791          25.5
Cooking                  2961         740            25
Ja.StackOverflow         5088        1265          24.9
German                   2092         514          24.6
Diy                      9024        2149          23.8
Ethereum                 4309         987          22.9
Martialarts               272          62          22.8
Garage                   4902        1113          22.7
Ell                     13138        2943          22.4
Bricks                    459         100          21.8
Opensource                693         150          21.6
Iot                       149          32          21.5
Sustainability            260          55          21.2
Mythology                 362          75          20.7
Rpg                      5131        1049          20.4
Boardgames               1543         314          20.3
Vi                       2043         409            20
Moderators                 90          18            20
Ham                       485          96          19.8
Coffee                    258          45          17.4
Craftcms                 2529         436          17.2
Tridion                  1179         201            17
Chinese                   968         165            17
Beer                      192          32          16.7
Japanese                 3507         562            16
Puzzling                 4876         759          15.6
Crafts                    535          82          15.3
Gardening                2123         322          15.2
Chess                     818         122          14.9
3dprinting                767         114          14.9
Retrocomputing            509          73          14.3
Outdoors                  893         125            14
Monero                   1065         144          13.5
Spanish                  1145         152          13.3
Woodworking               683          89            13
Russian                   634          78          12.3
French                   1864         225          12.1
Portuguese                476          55          11.6
Sitecore                 1273         140            11
Rus                      1990         203          10.2
Latin                     854          77             9
Italian                   533          40           7.5
Buddhism                  940          59           6.3
Esperanto                 749          22           2.9
Homebrew                  556          14           2.5
Korean                    407          10           2.5
```

Comment: I think trying to use raw numbers to measure something abstract such as "futility" is itself futile. This ranking just doesn't jive at all with my experiences across many of these sites. First it doesn't factor in the nature of the questions themselves: some sites require more effort to ask good questions that others but will often pay much higher dividends to those that do put in some effort in asking.

Comment: Others are prone to over-broad questions that often get split up and posted separately with different scopes. Other sites insist on editing the initial attempts. How helpful the community is in this process will mean more than these numbers in whether going there to ask a question is "futile" or not.

Answer (score 9):

3 interesting findings for me:

- The first is reassuring: when sorted by percentage closed, the sites I moderate range from 8th to 141st on the list. This reassures me as I'm obviously not biasing sites towards over- or under-closure. I'd have been concerned if all mine were in a cluster...
- We have very few reopens on these sites, indicating we are getting things right, mostly

and

- Despite some sites changing names, the underlying database obviously keeps the original name, which was interesting when searching for my sites.

Comment: I would think very few reopens is a *bad* sign rather than a good one: it means your users aren't motivated to improve their questions after having them put on hold.

Comment: @randal'thor and/or that users have a poorer-than-average (across sites) concept of what will be an on-topic question when they ask. It might not be that they're not motivated to improve, but rather that the question isn't salvageable from the get-go.

Comment: Oh, don't get me wrong - if we had a million closures it would concern me, but having a reasonably low level of closures, and most staying closed implies mods and users with close privs are getting that right

Comment: Reopening stuff is **hard** - you need to get enough people to care enough to cast VTRO, even if the question wasn't closed correctly. Double extra hard if it is binding-closed by a moderator - very few people are willing to cross a moderator, in my experience.

Comment: @DVK - Even moderators get it wrong. I've kept it open to Mechanics users, if they think something I put the close hammer on is wrong, I'll re-open in a heartbeat. I may be a mod, but I'm not infallible. Note I haven't reopened anything yet, but I do put it out there as such ;-)

Comment: As @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 says, I do get challenged on occasion, and have reopened some. Don't think anyone is scared of me, thankfully - if they think I've done wrong they'll tell me why

Comment: Friendly reminder that [there's a 10k tool that breaks down closed questions both by those edited after being closed, and those edited before being reopened.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257449/new-10k-tool-question-close-statistics). If you're trying to suss out why things do / do not get reopened over a large population of questions, those are pretty useful. @rand

Answer (score 5):

These stats were useful for helping to improve an [answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4182/115) to a Meta GIS SE question about [Too many questions On Hold and Closed?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4181/too-many-questions-on-hold-and-closed)

For GIS I think the ranking at 43rd (of 162 sites) highest percentage of closed questions may be higher than otherwise expected due to a cleanup effort for [Improving on 17,500 unanswered questions?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4117/improving-on-17-500-unanswered-questions)  GIS started to become alarmed about the number when it was 15,000 and got serious about addressing it when it had blown out to over 18,000 at the end of 2015.

When [Shog9's stats on questions that were both asked and closed in 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289830/215590) were examined, GIS was 63rd out of 163 sites placing it much closer to being an average site in this respect.