# 2017: a year in closing

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions, statistics, reopened-questions

Last year [I posted some numbers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289797/2016-a-year-in-closing) on how many questions were closed on various sites around the network in the preceding year. This ended up being kinda handy to refer back to, so I'm gonna do it again:

### Questions asked, closed and reopened for all sites in 2017

```
                Site                   Asked   AskedAndClosed PctAskedAndClosed AllClosed DuplicatesClosed DuplicatesReopened OTClosed OTReopened UnclearClosed UnclearReopened TooBroadClosed TooBroadReopened OpinionBasedClosed OpinionBasedReopened
------------------------------------ --------- -------------- ----------------- --------- ---------------- ------------------ -------- ---------- ------------- --------------- -------------- ---------------- ------------------ --------------------
Stack Overflow                       3,157,603        341,165           10.8  %   360,489          139,647              5,417   93,931      1,532        47,332           1,109         67,366              848             12,213                   92
Super User                              59,152         10,427           17.63 %    11,317            2,126                 67    4,783        105         1,959              70          2,002               52                447                   15
Server Fault                            33,913          7,176           21.16 %     7,378              725                 20    5,488         99           606              32            457                7                102                    4
Stack Apps                                 405            137           33.83 %       140               19                  0      102          0             9               0             10                0                  0                    0
Seasoned Advice                          2,633            481           18.27 %       497              201                  8      112          4            87               3             39                1                 58                    1
Home Improvement                         8,740          1,059           12.12 %     1,126              106                  1      536         10           325               5             74                0                 85                    1
Game Development                         8,083          1,381           17.09 %     1,702              196                  4      785         14           207              12            348                4                166                    1
Arqade                                  10,368          2,314           22.32 %     2,454              672                 11      983         37           485              24            171               11                143                    8
GIS                                     22,300          5,938           26.63 %     7,253            1,271                110    2,058        234         1,802             329          1,905              341                217                   17
Mathematics                            230,498         33,461           14.52 %    34,890            7,545                186   21,095        467         5,447             161            550               15                253                    5
Photography                              3,128            832           26.6  %       881              373                 11      317          9           117              10             40                2                 34                    3
Cross Validated                         40,671          9,481           23.31 %    10,349            1,463                 55    5,045        222         3,059             398            689               38                 93                    7
Web Applications                         5,421          1,670           30.81 %     2,289              307                  3    1,430         10           380              16            119                1                 53                    1
Webmasters                               4,870          2,195           45.07 %     2,246              509                 26      871         35           363              86            333               30                170                   13
Ask Different                           20,401          2,551           12.5  %     2,758              972                 49      667         52           777             113            206               40                136                   14
Theoretical Computer Science             1,661            422           25.41 %       432                4                  0      368          3            51               1              9                0                  0                    0
English Language & Usage                23,300         12,773           54.82 %    13,224            2,018                 46    8,269        178         1,539              50            336               13              1,062                   29
Money                                    5,139          1,168           22.73 %     1,273              220                 11      652         17           179               7            105                0                117                    1
RPG                                      6,321          1,822           28.82 %     1,956              399                 59      264         23           523             258            401              120                369                   85
TeX - LaTeX                             27,545          5,104           18.53 %     6,685            2,964                134    1,370         29         1,993              36            269               14                 89                    3
Ask Ubuntu                              68,563         16,252           23.7  %    18,960            8,284                169    5,458        124         4,123             239            635               37                460                   14
Unix & Linux                            34,926          6,693           19.16 %     7,056            1,686                 52    1,525         26         2,583             115          1,008               18                254                    4
WordPress Development                   21,181          4,700           22.19 %     4,890              197                  2    3,813         19           368               8            449                7                 63                    1
Bicycles                                 1,993            344           17.26 %       369              101                  0      149          3            72               0             30                1                 17                    0
Software Engineering                     9,672          3,575           36.96 %     3,709              206                  2    2,106         14           469               8            595                5                333                    7
Android Enthusiasts                     11,330          2,556           22.56 %     2,605              403                  5    1,703         20           407              26             38                1                 54                    2
Board & Card Games                       1,368            261           19.08 %       294              134                  9       60          2            36               9             33                1                 31                    2
Physics                                 36,143         11,508           31.84 %    11,812            2,389                 38    6,076         55         2,621              78            509               26                217                    3
Homebrewing                                436             14            3.21 %        16                3                  0       11          0             1               0              0                0                  1                    0
Information Security                    12,363          4,449           35.99 %     4,573              795                 21    2,236         26           585              15            751                4                206                    1
Writers                                  1,657            381           22.99 %       394               41                  1      263          8            34               3             32                3                 24                    1
Electrical Engineering                  28,452          7,434           26.13 %     7,607              550                  9    3,175         50         2,448              61          1,205               17                229                    4
Graphic Design                          10,374          1,664           16.04 %     1,727              317                  7      624         16           342              25            369               17                 75                    3
DBA                                     14,648          3,095           21.13 %     3,343              367                 23      998         27         1,154              88            663               14                161                    3
Science Fiction & Fantasy                9,900          2,190           22.12 %     2,390            1,243                 70      456         57           146              28            232               45                313                   55
Area 51 Discussions                        810            185           22.84 %       185               33                  0      144          2             6               1              2                0                  0                    0
Code Review                             15,419          5,034           32.65 %     5,093               53                  6    4,448        317           532              93             46                6                 14                    3
Code Golf                                3,293          1,301           39.51 %     1,398              328                 85      510         37           498             179             58               10                  4                    0
Quantitative Finance                     3,204            614           19.16 %       621               49                  1      392          1           109               2             52                1                 19                    0
Project Management                         806            155           19.23 %       170                4                  0       99          3            14               0             31                3                 22                    0
Skeptics                                 1,642            644           39.22 %       657               62                  2      328         41           169              55             19                5                 79                   12
Drupal Answers                          16,023          2,295           14.32 %     2,649              337                 22      787         19           714              43            714               24                 97                    6
Physical Fitness                         1,152            420           36.46 %       435              101                  0      216          2            21               0             23                0                 74                    1
Motor Vehicles                           4,074            459           11.27 %       481               90                  3      163          7           104               8             76                4                 48                    3
Parenting                                  952            290           30.46 %       301               46                  0      154         12            50               5             25                4                 26                    2
SharePoint                              14,430            782            5.42 %       798              159                  8      241          9           231              43            107               12                 60                    4
Music                                    3,479            915           26.3  %       949              124                  0      459          5           132               8            103                2                131                    3
Software Quality Assurance & Testing     2,468            710           28.77 %       850               52                  2      272         14           296              16            154               15                 76                    8
Mi Yodeya                                4,013            961           23.95 %     1,072              372                 17      361         36           211              26             82               14                 46                    2
Astronomy                                2,453            406           16.55 %       431              106                  1      122          2           134               2             46                2                 23                    0
German Language                          2,217            482           21.74 %       494               82                  6      313         24            51               4             28                2                 20                    0
Japanese Language                        4,217            798           18.92 %       816              273                  6      441          8            56               7             30                0                 16                    0
Gardening & Landscaping                  1,932             95            4.92 %       114               29                  2       33          5            37               4             13                0                  2                    0
Philosophy                               2,518            672           26.69 %       687               67                  1      333         14           161               5             68                4                 58                    2
Personal Productivity                      365            139           38.08 %       147               27                  0       72          1            14               2             20                0                 14                    1
Travel                                   8,633          3,841           44.49 %     4,027            1,419                 62    1,083         71           736              91            276               37                513                   44
Cryptography                             4,947          1,431           28.93 %     1,497              181                 15    1,004         77           167              19            109               15                 36                    5
Literature                               1,718            207           12.05 %       207                3                  0       77         20            32               9             58               12                 37                    8
Signal Processing                        4,469            830           18.57 %       846               82                  3      280         12           322              38            145               10                 17                    1
French Language                          1,571            169           10.76 %       173               69                  2       77          4            10               0              8                0                  9                    0
Christianity                             2,120          1,009           47.59 %     1,146               99                  5      347         16           181               5            145                5                374                   18
Bitcoin                                  7,450          1,875           25.17 %     1,933              982                 16      411         12           286              16            147                7                107                    1
Linguistics                              1,407            390           27.72 %       406               22                  0      244          8            66               0             49                1                 25                    1
Biblical Hermeneutics                    1,279            337           26.35 %       358               72                  2      173         14            47               4             17                3                 49                    8
Economics                                2,537            670           26.41 %       707               53                  0      442         10           137               0             49                2                 26                    0
History                                  2,496            776           31.09 %       797               42                  3      372         18           133               4            115                7                135                    6
Bricks                                     470             63           13.4  %        66               24                  1       14          2            17               2              8                2                  3                    0
Spanish Language                         1,407            152           10.8  %       160               49                  3       91         13            11               0              6                0                  3                    0
Computational Science                    1,482            349           23.55 %       377               19                  1      244          0            82               1             24                0                  8                    0
Movies & TV                              7,915          2,940           37.14 %     3,249              246                  9    2,429         62           215              18            139               16                220                   15
Chinese Language                         1,421            159           11.19 %       161               14                  0      118          0            18               0              4                0                  7                    0
Biology                                  6,444          1,787           27.73 %     1,833              161                  7      832         23           402               7            269                2                169                    4
Poker                                      294             75           25.51 %        81               47                  0       11          0             6               0              8                0                  9                    0
Mathematica                             12,357          3,352           27.13 %     3,574            1,013                 30    2,158         61           351              23             45                2                  7                    1
Psychology & Neuroscience                1,271            635           49.96 %       744               44                  1      289         18           192              15            136                4                 83                    4
The Great Outdoors                         772            131           16.97 %       138               29                  2       54          6            23               4             19                5                 13                    3
Martial Arts                               274             61           22.26 %        62               13                  0       19          0             9               0              8                0                 13                    1
Sports                                     960            247           25.73 %       263               46                  2       89          3            28               4             50                7                 50                    9
Academia                                 6,750          2,550           37.78 %     2,582              420                  8    1,526         37           327              15            169                3                140                    7
Computer Science                         8,985          2,209           24.59 %     2,230              346                  7      949         15           710              32            133                3                 92                    2
The Workplace                            7,349          3,457           47.04 %     3,499              712                 15    1,831        112           433              28            182                8                341                   30
Windows Phone                              369             51           13.82 %        53               24                  1       19          1             7               0              1                0                  2                    0
Chemistry                               11,592          5,179           44.68 %     5,351              614                 22    2,792         81         1,135              46            724               21                 86                    7
Chess                                      882            137           15.53 %       145               52                  0       38          2            26               2             15                0                 14                    0
Raspberry Pi                             8,181          1,643           20.08 %     1,684              295                 18      460         21           489              50            379                9                 61                    0
Russian Language                           521            136           26.1  %       141               11                  1      100         14            19               8             11                1                  0                    0
Islam                                    3,101            981           31.63 %     1,234              335                  0      329          1           297              14            119                4                154                    2
Salesforce                              23,544          3,262           13.85 %     3,384              791                 29    1,555         33           592              14            355                5                 91                    3
Ask Patents                              1,016            381           37.5  %       385               36                  0      310          9            36               3              2                0                  1                    0
UX                                       4,109          1,115           27.14 %     1,155              123                  0      488          7            87               3            190                1                267                    4
Genealogy & Family History                 500             84           16.8  %        93               39                  9       23          4            14               1             15                3                  2                    0
Robotics                                 1,308            381           29.13 %       393               19                  0      113          5           109               8             33                1                119                    7
ExpressionEngine® Answers                  770             14            1.82 %        14                1                  0        8          0             4               1              0                0                  1                    0
Politics                                 3,219          1,239           38.49 %     1,298              147                 18      448         65           169              24            155               26                379                   56
Video Production                         1,450            135            9.31 %       142               19                  0       74          1            24               0             13                0                 12                    2
Anime & Manga                            2,261            762           33.7  %       780               96                  0      520          8            61               5             32                2                 71                    4
Magento                                 26,758          2,103            7.86 %     2,407              599                 10      854          6           407              17            406                6                141                    0
English Language Learners               14,878          2,620           17.61 %     2,679              510                 22    1,758        122           175              10            139                8                 97                    6
Sustainable Living                         183             28           15.3  %        30                5                  1       10          0             7               0              6                0                  2                    0
Tridion                                    874             16            1.83 %        21               13                  0        2          0             4               0              2                0                  0                    0
Reverse Engineering                      1,423            260           18.27 %       292               27                  1      114          3            85               2             55                0                 11                    0
Arduino                                  6,122          1,528           24.96 %     1,704              110                  2      495          8           645              12            434                4                 20                    0
Network Engineering                      5,008          2,600           51.92 %     2,998               97                  1    2,471         35            55              13            326               19                 49                    4
Open Data                                  909             65            7.15 %        68               23                  2       31          2            10               1              4                0                  0                    0
Freelancing                                375             77           20.53 %        80                3                  0       31          0             6               0             25                0                 15                    0
Blender                                 14,162          2,289           16.16 %     2,365            1,270                 24      441         14           441              35            140               10                 73                    2
MathOverflow                            16,603          3,398           20.47 %     3,465               72                  2    2,888         60           432              20             39                3                 34                    5
Space Exploration                        1,810            328           18.12 %       332               89                  2       88          3            49               2             62                6                 44                    2
Sound Design                               845            200           23.67 %       222               20                  0      157          9            18               2             13                0                 14                    0
Tor                                      1,496            437           29.21 %       488              227                  1       57          0           177               2             21                2                  6                    0
Pets                                     1,166            160           13.72 %       164               99                  6       37          2            16               0              5                0                  7                    0
Amateur Radio                              516             74           14.34 %        81                6                  1       41          4             9               2             15                0                 10                    3
Italian Language                           430             44           10.23 %        46                7                  1       25          0             8               0              3                0                  3                    0
Stack Overflow em Português             44,945          8,844           19.68 %     9,130            1,904                 45    2,534        147         3,218             104          1,189               26                285                   12
Aviation                                 3,788            938           24.76 %       949              351                 28      229         22           154              24            127               22                 88                    8
Ebooks                                     309             45           14.56 %        50                4                  0       37          0             7               0              0                0                  2                    0
Beer, Wine & Spirits                       223             24           10.76 %        24                2                  0        8          0             7               3              6                1                  1                    0
Software Recommendations                 3,970            413           10.4  %       422               12                  0      267         13            93              17             39                0                 11                    2
CS50                                     2,762             80            2.9  %       104               59                  0       15          0            26               0              3                0                  1                    0
Expatriates                              1,401            341           24.34 %       526               49                  3       81          2           157               5            154                9                 85                    2
Mathematics Educators                      411             97           23.6  %        97                4                  0       69          1             8               1             12                0                  4                    0
Earth Science                            1,153            181           15.7  %       191               26                  1       74          2            52               4             33                2                  6                    0
Joomla                                   1,095             78            7.12 %        88               20                  0       29          1            14               2             23                2                  2                    0
Data Science                             5,077            944           18.59 %       978               28                  0      267          3           347              14            263                6                 73                    0
Puzzling                                 3,200            469           14.66 %       479              118                  2      184          3            60               7            101                6                 16                    0
Craft CMS                                2,467             87            3.53 %        89               31                  0       49          1             5               1              4                0                  0                    0
Buddhism                                 1,194            114            9.55 %       115               39                  4       39          5            18               5              6                2                 13                    2
Hinduism                                 2,727            662           24.28 %       744              388                 27      189         35            43              10             33                9                 91                   20
Community Building                          69             13           18.84 %        14                2                  0        9          0             2               0              0                0                  1                    0
Startups                                   801            107           13.36 %       111                5                  0       64          0            14               0             25                0                  3                    0
Worldbuilding                            5,927          2,438           41.13 %     2,493              234                 13      633         47           347              34            784               61                495                   29
スタック・オーバーフロー                   4,874            256            5.25 %       261               14                  1      104         13            72              10             49                2                 22                    2
Emacs                                    4,104            145            3.53 %       155               68                  2       24          0            38               4             15                1                 10                    0
History of Science and Mathematics         575             55            9.57 %        57               19                  0       19          0             9               0              4                0                  6                    0
Lifehacks                                  496            222           44.76 %       229               20                  0      197          4             9               3              2                0                  1                    0
Engineering                              2,875            745           25.91 %       757               22                  1      190          3           319              11            205                4                 21                    0
Coffee                                     184             15            8.15 %        15                3                  0        5          0             2               0              1                0                  4                    0
Vi and Vim                               1,778            184           10.35 %       191               96                  4       65          2            18               3              9                0                  3                    1
Music Fans                                 743             77           10.36 %       104                6                  0       50          0            17               0             14                0                 17                    0
Woodworking                                560             61           10.89 %        64               18                  0       22          2             8               1             10                1                  6                    2
CiviCRM                                  2,510             43            1.71 %        44               27                  0       12          0             5               0              0                0                  0                    0
Health                                   2,380            481           20.21 %       508               16                  0      409          4            27               2             28                0                 28                    1
Stack Overflow на русском               79,398          9,073           11.43 %     9,561            2,117                 58    3,447        188         1,774              86          1,263               51                960                   28
Русский язык                             2,331            195            8.37 %       243               61                  6      119         15            32               6             14                2                 17                    2
Mythology & Folklore                       370             38           10.27 %        40                8                  1       13          2             4               1             12                0                  3                    0
Law                                      3,816            729           19.1  %       741               45                  2      449         22           135              11             95                8                 17                    1
Open Source                                674            111           16.47 %       112               26                  0       61          2            13               0              9                0                  3                    0
elementary OS                            2,133            200            9.38 %       252               94                  1      113          0            29               0             13                0                  3                    0
Portuguese Language                        312             19            6.09 %        19                2                  0       13          0             2               0              1                0                  1                    0
Computer Graphics                          841            142           16.88 %       145                8                  0       85          3            27               3             19                0                  6                    0
Hardware Recommendations                 1,311            582           44.39 %       589                4                  0      483          5            16               3             60                2                 26                    1
Stack Overflow en español               41,465          9,262           22.34 %     9,568              659                 21    1,857        157         3,228             202          2,737              143              1,087                   50
3D Printing                                705             93           13.19 %        97                1                  0       29          0            25               2             22                0                 20                    0
Ethereum                                10,066          1,324           13.15 %     1,351              666                 12      350          5           134               9            113                1                 88                    3
Latin Language                             989             28            2.83 %        30               12                  0        6          1             8               2              4                0                  0                    0
Language Learning                          284             67           23.59 %        69                6                  0       38          1             4               0             14                4                  7                    1
Retrocomputing                             640             80           12.5  %        80                6                  0       36          5             6               4             26                7                  6                    2
Arts & Crafts                              401             83           20.7  %        83                6                  1       51          1             8               0             11                0                  7                    0
Korean Language                            330             13            3.94 %        13                4                  0        1          0             4               3              4                2                  0                    0
Monero                                   1,275            114            8.94 %       115               60                  0       14          0            13               0             16                0                 12                    0
Artificial Intelligence                  1,047            147           14.04 %       149                3                  0      105          1            14               2             23                0                  4                    1
Esperanto Language                         289             13            4.5  %        13                8                  2        1          0             1               0              1                0                  2                    0
Sitecore                                 2,347            328           13.98 %       341               54                  5      198         14            29               3             52                3                  8                    0
Internet of Things                         718            216           30.08 %       216               11                  0       90          3            48               3             57                7                 10                    1
Vegetarianism                              408             97           23.77 %        97                7                  3       24          4             7               1             40                5                 19                    4
Ukrainian Language                         634             49            7.73 %        49                6                  0       14          1            14               6              9                3                  6                    1
DevOps                                   1,079            151           13.99 %       151               12                  1       34          3            53               6             34                7                 18                    5
Bioinformatics                             810             67            8.27 %        67                6                  1       23          3             9               0             24                6                  5                    3
Computer Science Educators                 505             83           16.44 %        83                2                  0       40          7             4               4             29               10                  8                    3
Interpersonal Skills                     1,533            600           39.14 %       600               29                  6      189         25           103              17            214               46                 65                   13
Augur                                      253             36           14.23 %        36                2                  0       13          0             2               0             16                1                  3                    0
```

Notes:

- this counts questions asked in 2017 and questions closed in 2017 - the AskedAndClosed and PctAskedAndClosed columns reflect questions that were *both* asked and closed in 2017, while the remaining columns total up all questions closed in 2017 - even those asked in prior years.
- reopen numbers also include questions asked in years prior - but limit themselves to questions that were closed in 2017 and then also reopened in 2017.
- if a question was closed twice, it'll be counted twice
- if a question was reopened twice, it'll be counted twice

### Alternate formats

- Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-mlLjpMW9hzZRbiqRY5lMGsAIMIML5qzn81vn2XshEM/edit?usp=sharing
- CSV: https://gist.github.com/Shog9/d11c370aafe2ff0f9dc2d51e9b2228b7

Comment: This is a great indication that SE needs table formatting.

Comment: What's the sorting order?

Comment: Sorted by the credit score of the 17th user to earn 10 points after joining on a Thursday.

Comment: The Japanese SO name is 2 characters shorter on Mobile

Comment: @iDebug that's a problem with half-width and full-width character on CJK languages (ASCII is half-width, Japanese kana is full-width)... in fact, the desktop version is also not perfectly aligned, just *almost* aligned. Anyway, the site sorting order looks like a default result from API.

Comment: I think I know the sorting. It's site ID. i.e. SO's ID is 1, and SU's ID is 2, etc.

Comment: Is there anywhere this data can be viewed in a nicer format? I'd kind of like to be able to sort by ascending/descending in each column.

Comment: Added CSV and Google Sheet @rand

Comment: And the winner is Network Engineering, with over half of questions asked being closed.

Comment: @ExUmbris English Language & Usage beats out Network Engineering, at 54.82% closed (compared to Network Engineering's 51.92%)

Comment: How did I miss that? Oh well...

Comment: Wait, where's the deletion one?