# Statistics about closures/deletions with a binding vote by a ♦ moderator

Tags: support, closed-questions, deleted-answers, moderators

I would like to know if it is possible to see a count of question closures and answer deletions that occurred by the normal queue vote process (where some number of community members all voted until the number was met and the action happened) and then another count of the same actions where the normal queue action was pre-empted by the vote of a ♦ moderator?

The counts of the first should go back at least one election cycle prior to the current, and then the count of the second would be maybe done twice, once for the previous cycle, and once for the current.

Comment: As a note, mods have often asked for the ability to cast non-immediate close votes and been refused that request. We are expected to know whether something is within scope or not and if we're unsure, wait to vote... but there's nothing about a close vote for mods that's binding... the userbase, if they disagree, can still reopen those questions, so if the moderator is doing something the community doesn't agree with, the questions won't *stay* closed.

Comment: I think the question is of broader interest to the network, so I wouldn't VTC as being about a single site. The back story may relate to a specific site, but that doesn't make the question single-site...

Comment: Your question will be better received if it doesn't include a jab at a moderator. It's sort of irrelevant why you're asking the question if you just want the data... Attempting to lodge a complaint in the form of a request for support seems somewhat duplicitous. If you have a concern about a mod, fill out the contact form and talk to the CMs... or take it to the per-site meta... but this question would be much better off without most of the body.

Comment: Fixed and please accept my apology. I do not want this question to be about issue with mods, but about a request for information.

Comment: Sure :) I'm guessing that this is something that may be possible in SEDE but I've no clue how to query for it. Perhaps someone will be able to write a query for you. They can be changed to any site, so you can use them on whichever site you like even if it's written for a different site entirely :) It probably won't be based on election cycle dates and it won't include deleted posts but at the least it would include the ones currently available to view on the site.

Comment: for closure and deletion you could use this [sede query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/796278?date=2015-04-22&UserId=100297). Not sure if that fits your needs. I picked on Martijn Pieters here, SO Mod, because he showed up in my first 100 results, and his overall awesomeness.

Comment: @rene that's an interesting query, thanks for it. I'll have to play with it for a bit.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would knowing the number of questions closed by a moderator tell you? Are you saying there’s something inherently wrong with moderators closing questions?

Comment: Related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306197/2017-a-year-in-closing

Comment: @Cai Have you looked at the revision history of the question? As my earlier comment notes, the (now removed) content isn't really doing much of value to the question but there's no reason to not help someone compile data. Purely as a datapoint, I find it interesting, so... eh. I don't think the motivations are necessary.

Comment: @Catija that’s why I asked. I do think it’s an interesting metric, I’m just wondering what’s being inferred from it

Comment: @Cai I won't go into the why here or now. I should not have done so in the beginning.

Answer (score 5):

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/796269/question-close-statistics?DateFrom=2017-12-01&DateTill=2017-12-31) is a SEDE query which might help in analyzing how many questions are closed by a ♦ moderator and how many are not. Last December, 45 questions on Meta Stack Exchange were closed and in only 4 cases a ♦ moderator cast a binding vote. You can change the parameters to choose the date interval you need, and there's also an option to switch sites.

I've excluded duplicate questions; those can be closed single-handedly by gold tag badge holders and by the author of the question. Questions which are deleted (e.g. by [Roomba](/help/roomba)) aren't included, but there's no reason to assume this shifts the statistics in one direction or another.

For reference, here is the complete query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
    AS 'Questions closed',
  SUM(CASE WHEN Text LIKE '%{%{%{%{%{%{%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
    AS 'Questions closed by less than 5 users'
  FROM PostHistory
  WHERE PostHistoryTypeId = 10 -- Post Closed
    AND CreationDate BETWEEN ##DateFrom:string## AND ##DateTill:string##
    AND Comment != '101' -- not Duplicate, those can be closed by gold tag badge holders
```

Note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning.

As for deleted answers, SEDE won't be of much help because only very limited information is stored about deleted posts.

Comment: To me, the amusing thing here is that the *actual* number is far higher, it's just that, here on MSE, many of the mod hammer closes are also deleted, so they don't show up. :D But, on most sites, this won't be the case... the questions, unless downvoted and roombaed, will probably still be around, even if closed.

Comment: PostHistoryTypeid =12 (delete) returned lots of rows for Martijn so it looks like Posthistory isn't sanitized for that.

Comment: If it is dupe hammerd the text will contain {"GoldTagBadge"

Comment: ... but I only see (on Meta Stack Exchange) posts which have been subsequently undeleted.

Comment: Ah, didn't investigate further. That would make sense

Comment: ... and by the OP themselves {"BindingApprovalByOP" or something like that.

Comment: This gave me what I was looking for. I'm going to let the question remain unanswered for a couple days, though.