# 2018: a year in closing

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions, statistics, reopened-questions

Continuing [my sometimes-annual practice of posting these numbers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306197/2017-a-year-in-closing), here is the information on how many questions were closed on various sites around the network in 2018:

```
                Site                   Asked   AskedAndClosed PctAskedAndClosed AllClosed DuplicatesClosed DuplicatesReopened OTClosed OTReopened UnclearClosed UnclearReopened TooBroadClosed TooBroadReopened OpinionBasedClosed OpinionBasedReopened
------------------------------------ --------- -------------- ----------------- --------- ---------------- ------------------ -------- ---------- ------------- --------------- -------------- ---------------- ------------------ --------------------
Stack Overflow                       2,888,870        331,039           11.46 %   353,949          143,339              5,865   89,254      1,375        43,185           1,089         65,420              846             12,751                  104
Super User                              53,131         11,036           20.77 %    11,680            1,502                 61    4,852        140         2,080             116          2,796              112                450                   11
Server Fault                            28,918          6,096           21.08 %     6,351              649                 17    4,567         96           638              37            400               11                 97                    4
Stack Apps                                 282             75           26.60 %        91               16                  0       72          4             3               0              0                0                  0                    0
Seasoned Advice                          2,725            604           22.17 %       630              303                  6      141          4            83               4             49                3                 54                    4
Home Improvement                         8,804          1,107           12.57 %     1,177              111                  2      657          7           232               2            110                1                 67                    0
Game Development                         6,412            887           13.83 %       985              153                  8      483         26            72               9            185               11                 92                    3
Arqade                                   7,133          1,807           25.33 %     1,967              610                  7      722         20           370               8            164                7                101                    3
GIS                                     21,525          5,158           23.96 %     6,098            1,041                 66    1,917        148         1,452             195          1,491              228                197                   12
Mathematics                            216,187         35,774           16.55 %    38,368            7,044                190   25,403        651         4,966             139            663               24                292                    8
Photography                              2,664            784           29.43 %       862              330                 14      292          8           147               5             50                0                 43                    1
Cross Validated                         38,040          9,414           24.75 %    11,095            1,634                 49    4,844        193         3,699             442            850               51                 68                    4
Web Applications                         5,067          1,395           27.53 %     1,510              261                  2      819          4           293               1            103                1                 34                    0
Webmasters                               4,392          1,868           42.53 %     1,938              478                 21      746         41           329              62            269               28                116                   13
Ask Different                           16,000          2,505           15.66 %     2,668              957                 46      705         49           657             115            225               36                124                    8
Theoretical Computer Science             1,400            299           21.36 %       303                6                  0      262          6            29               0              5                0                  1                    0
English Language & Usage                22,415         10,431           46.54 %    10,761            1,658                 38    6,728        158         1,279              49            281                4                815                   29
Money                                    5,011          1,171           23.37 %     1,297              189                  3      625         19           219               3            131                1                133                    1
RPG                                      7,504          2,278           30.36 %     2,442              577                135      313         48           708             361            388              134                456                  119
TeX - LaTeX                             26,890          4,341           16.14 %     5,348            2,176                101    1,209         19         1,665              32            229                6                 69                    1
Ask Ubuntu                              62,399         13,902           22.28 %    15,321            7,758                148    4,166         92         2,579             127            493               16                325                    5
Unix & Linux                            33,828          7,819           23.11 %     8,192            2,386                106    1,634         34         2,530             109          1,256               38                386                   10
WordPress Development                   18,535          4,391           23.69 %     4,524              169                  1    3,679         23           241               4            366                4                 69                    1
Bicycles                                 1,917            248           12.94 %       266               86                  0      108          3            41               0             13                0                 18                    1
Software Engineering                     8,896          2,668           29.99 %     2,728              165                  3    1,618         10           285               2            444                7                216                    3
Android Enthusiasts                      8,138          1,917           23.56 %     1,973              324                  6    1,290         29           294              23             35                0                 30                    2
Board & Card Games                       1,408            276           19.60 %       314              144                  8       44          4            44              12             47                5                 35                    8
Physics                                 35,231         11,800           33.49 %    12,298            2,618                 33    6,465         63         2,390              55            551               34                274                    9
Homebrewing                                448             12            2.68 %        12                4                  0        6          0             1               0              1                0                  0                    0
Information Security                    10,916          3,763           34.47 %     3,867              696                  6    1,939         25           494              14            604                7                134                    2
Writing                                  1,818            527           28.99 %       549               79                  7      353         18            40               8             40                1                 37                    6
Electrical Engineering                  28,360          6,792           23.95 %     6,992              581                  8    2,817         50         2,126              48          1,266               13                202                    2
Graphic Design                           6,850          1,553           22.67 %     1,607              325                  9      584         19           305              17            311               12                 82                    3
DBA                                     14,822          3,028           20.43 %     3,339              341                 19    1,075         21         1,215              65            576               23                132                    4
Science Fiction & Fantasy                8,002          1,771           22.13 %     1,966              894                 53      434         67           174              33            189               49                275                   51
Area 51 Discussions                        456             97           21.27 %       100               33                  2       61          2             4               1              2                0                  0                    0
Code Review                             13,191          4,589           34.79 %     4,796               29                  2    4,453        255           277              34             23                3                 14                    1
Code Golf                                1,830            730           39.89 %       768              148                 36      349         30           252              91             19                3                  0                    0
Quantitative Finance                     3,240            553           17.07 %       560               62                  0      324          4            82               4             65                1                 27                    0
Project Management                         740            167           22.57 %       179                2                  0       71          1            36               0             30                0                 40                    0
Skeptics                                 1,172            447           38.14 %       454               27                  0      257         13           121              34             10                4                 39                   11
Drupal Answers                          11,970          2,166           18.10 %     2,503              320                 12      686         26           653              22            757               16                 87                    3
Physical Fitness                         1,098            319           29.05 %       336               47                  1      216          6            21               3             36                1                 16                    1
Motor Vehicles                           4,455            362            8.13 %       377               88                  2      143          7            63               3             52                2                 31                    0
Parenting                                  716            291           40.64 %       315               26                  1      130          7            81              11             39                3                 39                    5
SharePoint                              10,759            667            6.20 %       681              106                  8      201          4           246              30             95               12                 33                    2
Music                                    3,688            948           25.70 %     1,034              182                  5      524          8           102               7             97                4                129                    2
Software Quality Assurance & Testing     2,130            377           17.70 %       388               43                  2      118          1           131               7             61                1                 35                    2
Mi Yodeya                                4,046            926           22.89 %       978              382                 15      340         50           171              46             53               13                 32                    5
Astronomy                                2,290            371           16.20 %       383              113                  1      108          8           100               7             28                2                 34                    1
German Language                          1,798            457           25.42 %       468               87                 10      269         37            59               6             34                4                 19                    3
Japanese Language                        3,666            756           20.62 %       772              285                 11      413         11            44               3             14                1                 16                    0
Gardening & Landscaping                  2,138            109            5.10 %       125               22                  0       45          3            29               0             22                2                  7                    0
Philosophy                               3,021            565           18.70 %       572               42                  0      267          4           108               2             53                1                102                    3
Travel                                   8,750          3,762           42.99 %     3,856            1,540                 27    1,151         53           661              29            229               17                275                    7
Cryptography                             4,919          1,099           22.34 %     1,133              186                  9      735         32           116              19             72                7                 24                    4
Literature                               1,012            135           13.34 %       138                9                  0       63          5            24               4             32                2                 10                    1
Signal Processing                        4,543            926           20.38 %       947              100                  2      269          4           359              14            202                2                 17                    0
French Language                          1,537            119            7.74 %       120               40                  2       56          1            13               2             10                1                  1                    0
Christianity                             1,807            723           40.01 %       769               99                 10      314         16           107               3             66                2                183                    9
Bitcoin                                  6,909          1,491           21.58 %     1,589              463                  6      468          3           350               5            186                3                122                    1
Linguistics                              1,517            388           25.58 %       399               20                  0      272          4            56               1             35                1                 16                    0
Biblical Hermeneutics                    1,460            303           20.75 %       320               48                  0      189          6            48               0             11                0                 24                    1
Economics                                2,891            532           18.40 %       545               24                  0      353          0           102               0             43                0                 23                    0
History                                  2,467            680           27.56 %       692               37                  1      340         17           118              10            120                7                 77                    4
Bricks                                     466             38            8.15 %        39               14                  0        4          0            10               0              9                2                  2                    0
Spanish Language                         1,068            107           10.02 %       129               51                  2       56          6             6               1             12                0                  4                    0
Computational Science                    1,321            273           20.67 %       337               23                  0      224          1            73               0             15                0                  2                    0
Movies & TV                              3,851          1,340           34.80 %     5,813              192                  4    5,201         22           148              18             96                9                176                   14
Chinese Language                         1,285             98            7.63 %       103               23                  0       64          1             9               1              6                0                  1                    0
Biology                                  5,395          1,392           25.80 %     1,470              133                  6      737         11           291               5            159                1                150                    0
Poker                                      235             65           27.66 %        68               41                  0        9          0             8               1              5                0                  5                    0
Mathematica                             11,084          2,619           23.63 %     2,790              677                 21    1,797         45           256              12             51                2                  9                    0
Psychology & Neuroscience                1,457            568           38.98 %       601               43                  2      377         15            67               4             62                4                 52                    3
The Great Outdoors                         867            108           12.46 %       111               25                  2       39         10            14               6             27               12                  6                    0
Martial Arts                               213             56           26.29 %        59               14                  0       16          2             9               0              8                0                 12                    0
Sports                                     965            314           32.54 %       373               51                  1      197          4            25               1             60                3                 40                    4
Academia                                 6,591          2,371           35.97 %     2,455              435                  7    1,559         65           210              12            117               11                134                   14
Computer Science                         8,554          1,749           20.45 %     1,775              339                 11      792         11           478              20            110                6                 56                    1
The Workplace                            5,487          2,839           51.74 %     2,868              513                 35    1,344        114           302              26            288               27                421                   40
Windows Phone                              134             17           12.69 %        18                6                  0        6          0             5               0              0                0                  1                    0
Chemistry                                9,981          5,148           51.58 %     5,309              644                 11    2,740         60         1,062              26            769               21                 94                    0
Chess                                      872            199           22.82 %       203               67                  0       39          1            30               1             20                0                 47                    1
Raspberry Pi                             6,563          1,423           21.68 %     1,473              178                 12      457         11           511              51            290               13                 37                    0
Russian Language                           789            117           14.83 %       123               21                  0       78         16            10               4             12                1                  2                    0
Islam                                    3,164            924           29.20 %     1,108              360                  1      325          2           246               6             75                1                102                    0
Salesforce                              20,426          3,184           15.59 %     3,304              583                 11    1,218         24           895              17            537                4                 71                    1
Ask Patents                                557            107           19.21 %       107               20                  1       73          1            12               0              0                0                  2                    0
UX                                       3,083            842           27.31 %       875               69                  1      335          6           107               3            150                2                214                    1
Genealogy & Family History                 512             98           19.14 %       103               34                  0       31          1            18               6             13                3                  7                    1
Robotics                                 1,107            307           27.73 %       330               19                  1       86          4            79               6             40                2                106                    3
ExpressionEngine® Answers                  453              8            1.77 %         9                0                  0        7          0             2               0              0                0                  0                    0
Politics                                 2,560            865           33.79 %       894               99                 12      425         71           127              20            104               12                139                   26
Video Production                         1,309            103            7.87 %       110               15                  0       58          2            14               0             18                0                  5                    0
Anime & Manga                            2,121            645           30.41 %       656              101                  4      395          9            52              10             36                8                 72                    2
Magento                                 23,229          1,557            6.70 %     1,823              405                  6      601         11           412              18            290               10                115                    3
English Language Learners               14,573          2,394           16.43 %     2,442              372                  5    1,668        144           162              12            141                4                 99                    7
Sustainable Living                         235             28           11.91 %        32                7                  0       14          0             4               0              4                0                  3                    0
Tridion                                    600              4            0.67 %         4                2                  0        2          0             0               0              0                0                  0                    0
Reverse Engineering                      1,666            340           20.41 %       350               44                  2      140          5            82               7             74                1                 10                    0
Arduino                                  5,458          1,925           35.27 %     1,999              144                  2      578         10           781              26            477                3                 19                    0
Network Engineering                      4,810          2,676           55.63 %     2,921              111                  2    2,156         31            74               6            516               27                 64                    2
Open Data                                  800             45            5.63 %        49               19                  1       19          1            10               0              1                0                  0                    0
Freelancing                                236             53           22.46 %        53                1                  0       21          0             3               0             24                1                  4                    0
Blender                                 15,253          2,258           14.80 %     2,340            1,171                 16      442          3           477              16            171                4                 79                    3
MathOverflow                            16,305          3,080           18.89 %     3,112               86                  1    2,595         35           355              11             52                4                 24                    4
Space Exploration                        3,124            497           15.91 %       507              154                 10      147         11            85              20             60                9                 61                   13
Sound Design                               787            204           25.92 %       218               13                  0      153          5            22               1             12                1                 18                    0
Tor                                      1,034            100            9.67 %       114               37                  0       25          0            30               0             19                0                  3                    0
Pets                                     1,161            293           25.24 %       334              239                  9       39          3            37               3             12                0                  7                    0
Amateur Radio                              699            101           14.45 %       104               10                  1       47         11            28               9             12                4                  7                    4
Italian Language                           542             26            4.80 %        28               10                  0       12          1             4               1              2                0                  0                    0
Stack Overflow em Português             45,406          9,679           21.32 %     9,964            1,904                 75    3,281        119         3,427             112          1,151               16                201                    2
Aviation                                 3,958          1,081           27.31 %     1,098              364                 13      236         14           217              24            176               26                105                   15
Ebooks                                     231             20            8.66 %        20                0                  0       17          0             2               1              0                0                  1                    0
Beer, Wine & Spirits                       151             22           14.57 %        25                3                  0       10          1             4               0              3                0                  5                    0
Software Recommendations                 3,512            421           11.99 %       430                8                  0      287         17            87              21             38                2                 10                    1
CS50                                     1,449             36            2.48 %        40                5                  0       16          0            12               0              5                0                  2                    0
Expatriates                              1,332            141           10.59 %       146               40                  0       35          0            25               0             28                0                 18                    0
Mathematics Educators                      466            116           24.89 %       119                2                  0       82          1            18               0              9                0                  8                    0
Earth Science                            1,358            281           20.69 %       294               29                  1       96          6           145               5             22                0                  2                    0
Joomla                                     817             80            9.79 %        96               12                  0       37          2            20               2             24                1                  3                    0
Data Science                             8,799          1,448           16.46 %     1,484               28                  0      480          2           343               8            523                2                110                    1
Puzzling                                 5,204            740           14.22 %       747              168                  4      322         21            80               6            164               15                 13                    0
Craft CMS                                2,322             92            3.96 %        93               27                  1       59          0             3               0              3                0                  1                    0
Buddhism                                 1,193            127           10.65 %       131               53                  4       32          0            21               3             10                5                 15                    5
Hinduism                                 3,021            744           24.63 %       824              433                 25      162         21            54               8             61               12                114                   18
Community Building                          54             13           24.07 %        13                0                  0        8          1             2               0              3                0                  0                    0
Worldbuilding                            6,161          2,483           40.30 %     2,511              287                 27      643         58           295              36            669               72                617                   54
スタック・オーバーフロー                             5,261            246            4.68 %       250               22                  1      109         23            78               4             30                2                 11                    2
Emacs                                    3,444            110            3.19 %       118               70                  0       17          2            17               2              8                0                  6                    0
History of Science and Mathematics         537             48            8.94 %        48               12                  0       23          0             6               0              2                0                  5                    0
Lifehacks                                  517            162           31.33 %       164               14                  0      143          4             4               0              1                0                  2                    0
Engineering                              2,830            557           19.68 %       579               23                  0      173          6           235               9            132                4                 16                    0
Coffee                                     216             15            6.94 %        16                4                  0        3          0             1               0              3                0                  5                    0
Vi and Vim                               1,789            151            8.44 %       165               92                  7       39          3            14               4             11                1                  9                    0
Music Fans                                 717             75           10.46 %        90                7                  1       48          0            11               0             12                0                 12                    0
Woodworking                                513             27            5.26 %        29                5                  0       14          1             4               1              5                0                  1                    0
CiviCRM                                  2,161             15            0.69 %        18               14                  0        2          0             2               0              0                0                  0                    0
Medical Sciences                         2,121            998           47.05 %     1,174               29                  2      900         22            77               2             92                0                 76                    3
Stack Overflow на русском               87,030          9,214           10.59 %     9,583            2,106                 71    3,409        139         2,160              75          1,014               19                894                   10
Русский язык                             2,541            194            7.63 %       213               42                  1      127         10            21               4             11                0                 12                    2
Mythology & Folklore                       420             35            8.33 %        38                6                  0       14          0             7               1              9                0                  2                    0
Law                                      4,549            776           17.06 %       782              124                  6      389         14           143              13            104                8                 22                    0
Open Source                                660            107           16.21 %       108               36                  0       51          1            11               0              6                0                  4                    0
elementary OS                            1,741             68            3.91 %        97               56                  0       25          0            12               0              1                0                  3                    0
Portuguese Language                        248             22            8.87 %        23                6                  0       14          3             0               0              3                0                  0                    0
Computer Graphics                          765             77           10.07 %        79                3                  0       45          0            20               1              5                0                  6                    0
Hardware Recommendations                 1,108            471           42.51 %       483                1                  0      406         11            18               1             39                1                 19                    1
Stack Overflow en español               50,399          7,926           15.73 %     8,258              719                 21    2,380        108         1,975              72          1,842               43              1,342                   42
3D Printing                                899             97           10.79 %       103               14                  1       35          2            24               1             17                1                 13                    0
Ethereum                                14,163          1,937           13.68 %     2,005              747                  4      576          6           312               5            291                5                 79                    0
Latin Language                             776             19            2.45 %        19                9                  2        7          2             3               1              0                0                  0                    0
Language Learning                          316             96           30.38 %        96                7                  1       61          6             6               0             17                4                  5                    1
Retrocomputing                             850             88           10.35 %        91               12                  3       41          3             8               2             19                7                 11                    2
Arts & Crafts                              385             78           20.26 %        78                7                  0       49          2             7               0             11                0                  4                    0
Korean Language                            285              9            3.16 %        10                2                  1        4          1             1               0              3                1                  0                    0
Monero                                   1,263            207           16.39 %       215              168                  1       17          0            13               1             13                0                  4                    0
Artificial Intelligence                  2,059            176            8.55 %       179               11                  1      112          5            25               3             27                1                  4                    0
Esperanto Language                         153              7            4.58 %         8                2                  0        3          0             2               1              0                0                  1                    0
Sitecore                                 3,087            481           15.58 %       500              129                  4      220         25            40               2             98                6                 13                    0
Internet of Things                         612            165           26.96 %       173                4                  0       73          3            44               6             46                3                  6                    0
Veganism & Vegetarianism                   153             24           15.69 %        25                4                  0       10          1             2               1              6                1                  3                    0
Ukrainian Language                       1,091            102            9.35 %       102               44                  4       10          0            23               4             14                1                 11                    2
DevOps                                   1,377            122            8.86 %       129               11                  0       42          0            45               2             20                0                 11                    0
Bioinformatics                           1,104             53            4.80 %        57                3                  0       26          1            10               1             15                2                  3                    0
Computer Science Educators                 262             79           30.15 %        79                0                  0       67          5             5               0              5                0                  2                    1
Interpersonal Skills                     2,599          1,333           51.29 %     1,414               70                  7      620         82           223              40            248               45                253                   33
Augur                                      147             30           20.41 %        30                0                  0       10          0             6               1              7                0                  7                    0
```

Notes:

- this counts questions asked in 2018 and questions closed in 2018 - the AskedAndClosed and PctAskedAndClosed columns reflect questions that were *both* asked and closed in 2018, while the remaining columns total up all questions closed in 2018 - even those asked in prior years.
- reopen numbers also include questions asked in years prior - but limit themselves to questions that were closed in 2018 and then also reopened in 2018.
- if a question was closed twice, it'll be counted twice
- if a question was reopened twice, it'll be counted twice

### Alternate formats

- CSV: https://gist.github.com/Shog9/f75f5a759cd19556e617f0fe01810db2

Comment: Aww. no MSE? ;p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I think there may be separate post "2018: a year in feedback" for MSE! :p :)

Comment: Probably off-topic: I don't really understand the direction of the SE network and too-specialized sites. "Coffee" with 216 questions in a year? A whole site for IoT (aren't there enough technical sites already)? Martial Arts? It doesn't hurt that they exist - but are they *fun*? maybe some merges would benefit these communities?

Comment: @Kobi I'm surprised Martial Arts wasn't closed in proposal, for being completely covered at https://sports.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The data you posted on per-site metas included information on *who* did all that closing. I found it interesting enough to summarize here. In the table below, the sites are ordered by the percentage of closing done by diamond-less community.

```
+------+--------------------------------------+--------+-----------+-------------+
| Rank |                 Site                 |  Mods  | Community | % Community |
+------+--------------------------------------+--------+-----------+-------------+
|    1 | Chess                                | 1      | 202       | 99.51%      |
|    2 | TeX - LaTeX                          | 124    | 5,224     | 97.68%      |
|    3 | Mathematics                          | 1,954  | 36,414    | 94.91%      |
|    4 | Board & Card Games                   | 16     | 298       | 94.90%      |
|    5 | Ask Ubuntu                           | 808    | 14,513    | 94.73%      |
|    6 | MathOverflow                         | 166    | 2,946     | 94.67%      |
|    7 | Salesforce                           | 181    | 3,123     | 94.52%      |
|    8 | Stack Overflow                       | 22,180 | 331,769   | 93.73%      |
|    9 | Science Fiction & Fantasy            | 128    | 1,838     | 93.49%      |
|   10 | Mathematics Educators                | 8      | 111       | 93.28%      |
|   11 | Photography                          | 70     | 792       | 91.88%      |
|   12 | Stack Overflow - Russian             | 919    | 8,664     | 90.41%      |
|   13 | The Workplace                        | 278    | 2,590     | 90.31%      |
|   14 | Magento                              | 196    | 1,627     | 89.25%      |
|   15 | Aviation                             | 120    | 978       | 89.07%      |
|   16 | Biblical Hermeneutics                | 39     | 281       | 87.81%      |
|   17 | Chemistry                            | 648    | 4,661     | 87.79%      |
|   18 | Bicycles                             | 35     | 231       | 86.84%      |
|   19 | Unix & Linux                         | 1,129  | 7,063     | 86.22%      |
|   20 | Arqade                               | 273    | 1,694     | 86.12%      |
|   21 | Linguistics                          | 57     | 342       | 85.71%      |
|   22 | German Language                      | 69     | 399       | 85.26%      |
|   23 | DBA                                  | 518    | 2,821     | 84.49%      |
|   24 | Earth Science                        | 51     | 243       | 82.65%      |
|   25 | Programming Puzzles & Code Golf      | 136    | 632       | 82.29%      |
|   26 | Home Improvement                     | 216    | 961       | 81.65%      |
|   27 | Academia                             | 489    | 1,966     | 80.08%      |
|   28 | Theoretical Computer Science         | 64     | 239       | 78.88%      |
|   29 | Astronomy                            | 81     | 302       | 78.85%      |
|   30 | Ethereum                             | 444    | 1,561     | 77.86%      |
|   31 | 3D Printing                          | 23     | 80        | 77.67%      |
|   32 | Stack Overflow - Japanese            | 56     | 194       | 77.60%      |
|   33 | Writing                              | 123    | 426       | 77.60%      |
|   34 | History of Science and Mathematics   | 11     | 37        | 77.08%      |
|   35 | Worldbuilding                        | 579    | 1,932     | 76.94%      |
|   36 | Interpersonal Skills                 | 351    | 1,063     | 75.18%      |
|   37 | Arduino                              | 511    | 1,488     | 74.44%      |
|   38 | The Great Outdoors                   | 29     | 82        | 73.87%      |
|   39 | Space Exploration                    | 133    | 374       | 73.77%      |
|   40 | Woodworking                          | 8      | 21        | 72.41%      |
|   41 | Travel                               | 1,218  | 2,638     | 68.41%      |
|   42 | Graphic Design                       | 514    | 1,093     | 68.01%      |
|   43 | Politics                             | 297    | 597       | 66.78%      |
|   44 | Software Engineering                 | 963    | 1,765     | 64.70%      |
|   45 | Economics                            | 194    | 351       | 64.40%      |
|   46 | Role Playing Games                   | 880    | 1,562     | 63.96%      |
|   47 | Mathematica                          | 1,006  | 1,784     | 63.94%      |
|   48 | Puzzling                             | 274    | 473       | 63.32%      |
|   49 | Electrical Engineering               | 2,707  | 4,285     | 61.28%      |
|   50 | CiviCRM                              | 7      | 11        | 61.11%      |
|   51 | English Language & Usage             | 4,343  | 6,418     | 59.64%      |
|   52 | Philosophy                           | 232    | 340       | 59.44%      |
|   53 | Blender                              | 950    | 1,390     | 59.40%      |
|   54 | Homebrewing                          | 5      | 7         | 58.33%      |
|   55 | Reverse Engineering                  | 150    | 200       | 57.14%      |
|   56 | Physics                              | 5,303  | 6,995     | 56.88%      |
|   57 | Anime & Manga                        | 292    | 364       | 55.49%      |
|   58 | Code Review                          | 2,158  | 2,638     | 55.00%      |
|   59 | Sports                               | 168    | 205       | 54.96%      |
|   60 | Medical Sciences                     | 534    | 640       | 54.51%      |
|   61 | Engineering                          | 276    | 303       | 52.33%      |
|   62 | Literature                           | 67     | 71        | 51.45%      |
|   63 | Signal Processing                    | 469    | 478       | 50.48%      |
|   64 | Open Source                          | 54     | 54        | 50.00%      |
|   65 | Hinduism                             | 413    | 411       | 49.88%      |
|   66 | Stack Overflow - Portuguese          | 5027   | 4937      | 49.55%      |
|   67 | History                              | 351    | 341       | 49.28%      |
|   68 | Personal Finance & Money             | 658    | 639       | 49.27%      |
|   69 | Expatriates                          | 75     | 71        | 48.63%      |
|   70 | Software Quality Assurance & Testing | 211    | 177       | 45.62%      |
|   71 | Biology                              | 816    | 654       | 44.49%      |
|   72 | Portuguese Language                  | 13     | 10        | 43.48%      |
|   73 | Quantitative Finance                 | 322    | 238       | 42.50%      |
|   74 | English Language Learners            | 1,406  | 1,036     | 42.42%      |
|   75 | Language Learning                    | 95     | 75        | 44.12%      |
|   76 | Super User                           | 6,820  | 4,860     | 41.61%      |
|   77 | Stack Overflow - Spanish             | 4875   | 3383      | 40.97%      |
|   78 | Emacs                                | 71     | 47        | 39.83%      |
|   79 | Japanese Language                    | 467    | 305       | 39.51%      |
|   80 | Computational Science                | 206    | 131       | 38.87%      |
|   81 | User Experience                      | 542    | 333       | 38.06%      |
|   82 | Data Science                         | 930    | 554       | 37.33%      |
|   83 | Geographic Information Systems       | 3,843  | 2,255     | 36.98%      |
|   84 | Retrocomputing                       | 59     | 32        | 35.16%      |
|   85 | Information Security                 | 2,519  | 1,348     | 34.86%      |
|   86 | Mythology & Folklore                 | 25     | 13        | 34.21%      |
|   87 | elementary OS                        | 64     | 33        | 34.02%      |
|   88 | Martial Arts                         | 39     | 20        | 33.90%      |
|   89 | Computer Science                     | 1,180  | 595       | 33.52%      |
|   90 | Law                                  | 521    | 261       | 33.38%      |
|   91 | Sharepoint                           | 462    | 219       | 32.16%      |
|   92 | Bitcoin                              | 1,080  | 509       | 32.03%      |
|   93 | Coffee                               | 11     | 5         | 31.25%      |
|   94 | Spanish Language                     | 89     | 40        | 31.01%      |
|   95 | Iota                                 | 82     | 32        | 28.07%      |
|   96 | Christianity                         | 554    | 215       | 27.96%      |
|   97 | Mi Yodeya                            | 711    | 267       | 27.30%      |
|   98 | Lifehacks                            | 121    | 43        | 26.22%      |
|   99 | WordPress Development                | 3,349  | 1,175     | 25.97%      |
|  100 | Gardening & Landscaping              | 93     | 32        | 25.60%      |
|  101 | Tridion                              | 3      | 1         | 25.00%      |
|  102 | Bioinformatics                       | 43     | 14        | 24.56%      |
|  103 | Русский язык                         | 161    | 52        | 24.41%      |
|  104 | Veganism & Vegetarianism             | 19     | 6         | 24.00%      |
|  105 | Sitecore                             | 383    | 117       | 23.40%      |
|  106 | Sustainable Living                   | 25     | 7         | 21.88%      |
|  107 | Seasoned Advice                      | 497    | 133       | 21.11%      |
|  108 | Drupal Answers                       | 1,976  | 527       | 21.05%      |
|  109 | Cross Validated                      | 8,834  | 2,261     | 20.38%      |
|  110 | Skeptics                             | 366    | 88        | 19.38%      |
|  111 | DevOps                               | 104    | 25        | 19.38%      |
|  112 | Raspberry Pi                         | 1,190  | 283       | 19.21%      |
|  113 | Project Management                   | 145    | 34        | 18.99%      |
|  114 | Joomla                               | 78     | 18        | 18.75%      |
|  115 | Internet of Things                   | 141    | 32        | 18.50%      |
|  116 | Server Fault                         | 5,187  | 1,164     | 18.33%      |
|  117 | Vi and Vim                           | 135    | 30        | 18.18%      |
|  118 | Music                                | 847    | 187       | 18.09%      |
|  119 | Ask Different                        | 2,189  | 479       | 17.95%      |
|  120 | French Language                      | 99     | 21        | 17.50%      |
|  121 | Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair   | 312    | 65        | 17.24%      |
|  122 | Chinese Language                     | 87     | 16        | 15.53%      |
|  123 | Bricks                               | 34     | 5         | 12.82%      |
|  124 | Arts & Crafts                        | 68     | 10        | 12.82%      |
|  125 | Esperanto Language                   | 7      | 1         | 12.50%      |
|  126 | Physical Fitness                     | 294    | 42        | 12.50%      |
|  127 | Craft CMS                            | 82     | 11        | 11.83%      |
|  128 | Music Fans                           | 80     | 10        | 11.11%      |
|  129 | Web Applications                     | 1,350  | 160       | 10.60%      |
|  130 | Poker                                | 61     | 7         | 10.29%      |
|  131 | Parenting                            | 283    | 32        | 10.16%      |
|  132 | Islam                                | 996    | 112       | 10.11%      |
|  133 | Artificial Intelligence              | 161    | 18        | 10.06%      |
|  134 | Movies & TV                          | 5,306  | 507       | 8.72%       |
|  135 | Cryptography                         | 1,047  | 86        | 7.59%       |
|  136 | Pets                                 | 309    | 25        | 7.49%       |
|  137 | Monero                               | 199    | 16        | 7.44%       |
|  138 | Psychology & Neuroscience            | 558    | 43        | 7.15%       |
|  139 | Computer Graphics                    | 74     | 5         | 6.33%       |
|  140 | Computer Science Educators           | 74     | 5         | 6.33%       |
|  141 | Android Enthusiasts                  | 1,858  | 115       | 5.83%       |
|  142 | Beer, Wine & Spirits                 | 24     | 1         | 4.00%       |
|  143 | Game Development                     | 947    | 38        | 3.86%       |
|  144 | Italian Language                     | 27     | 1         | 3.57%       |
|  145 | Russian Language                     | 119    | 4         | 3.25%       |
|  146 | Ask Patents                          | 104    | 3         | 2.80%       |
|  147 | Buddhism                             | 128    | 3         | 2.29%       |
|  148 | Robotics                             | 323    | 7         | 2.12%       |
|  149 | Genealogy & Family History           | 101    | 2         | 1.94%       |
|  150 | Amateur Radio                        | 102    | 2         | 1.92%       |
|  151 | Freelancing                          | 52     | 1         | 1.89%       |
|  152 | Video Production                     | 108    | 2         | 1.82%       |
|  153 | Software Recommendations             | 425    | 5         | 1.16%       |
|  154 | Ukrainian Language                   | 101    | 1         | 0.98%       |
|  155 | Sound Design                         | 217    | 1         | 0.46%       |
|  156 | Hardware Recommendations             | 482    | 1         | 0.21%       |
|  157 | Webmasters                           | 1,935  | 3         | 0.15%       |
|  158 | Network Engineering                  | 2,917  | 4         | 0.14%       |
|  159 | ExpressionEngine                     | 9      | 0         | 0.00%       |
|  160 | Korean Language                      | 10     | 0         | 0.00%       |
|  161 | Community Building                   | 13     | 0         | 0.00%       |
|  162 | Windows Phone                        | 18     | 0         | 0.00%       |
|  163 | Latin Language                       | 19     | 0         | 0.00%       |
|  164 | Ebooks                               | 20     | 0         | 0.00%       |
|  165 | Augur                                | 30     | 0         | 0.00%       |
|  166 | Open Data                            | 49     | 0         | 0.00%       |
|  167 | Tor                                  | 114    | 0         | 0.00%       |
+------+--------------------------------------+--------+-----------+-------------+
```