# No "2018: A year in moderation" here?

Tags: discussion, meta, moderators, statistics

Shog9 has been posting posts titled "2018: a year in moderation" in all the child-metas (e.g., here's the [post on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378415/2422776)) with some interesting statistics on how many various moderation tasks are performed by diamond moderators as opposed to the community in that site.

Two sites seem to be exceptions, and didn't get such a post - Area 51's Discussion Zone (which kinda-sorta makes sense, since a lot of these moderation actions aren't available on the main Area 51), and this site (which is kinda-sorta it's own meta).

Any chance to get such a post for MSE? Even though we [only recently got a moderation team here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318630/223467), MSE has a very active, engaged community, and it would be interesting to see these stats.

**EDIT:**
According to @Martin's comment, there are actually three sites without this post - Area 51's Discussion Zone, MSE and Meta Mathoverflow.

Comment: Does somebody know whether there is indeed a plan to post this on all per-site-metas? If yes, this is still an ongoing process, right?

Comment: @Martin looks like [it's already done](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=2018%3A+a+year+in+moderation). On what meta site you think it's missing?

Comment: @Martin I noticed this on three different child metas (Stack Overflow, Super User and Open Source beta), so I just assumed (perhaps wrongly) it would be on all of them. Do you have another example of a meta site that doesn't have such a post?

Comment: Oh wait, there is this one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321318/2018-a-year-in-closing

Comment: @ShadowWizard I did not see anything [on MathOverflow Meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions). However, MO is a somewhat special case. (It's part of Stack Exchange network and also to some extent independent. But perhaps we should wait a bit to see - maybe it's going to be posted later.)

Comment: @Martin yeah, weird. Appears to be the only one then, but MathOverflow does appear in Shog's post I linked above with general stats of all sites. Try pinging him there, or start a new question on MathOverflow meta.

Comment: @ShadowWizard "2018: a year in closing" is an interesting, different topic - it's about closing stats throughout the network, not about all moderation actions in this site.

Comment: Since this discussion about per-site-metas where the post of this kind is missing is a digression from the topic of *this question* we can [continue it in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/1292/2019/1/1) if needed.

Comment: Another exception would be Quantum Computing Stack Exchange?