# 2019: a year in closing

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions, statistics, reopened-questions

Closing and reopening questions is a very small part of what goes on around this network... But it gets a lot of attention, and always has. Particularly over the past year, as we've [tested](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/655/results-added-testing-single-vote-closure-on-hardware-recs) some [pretty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390083/threshold-experiment-results-closing-editing-and-reopening-all-become-more-eff) [significant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow) changes, with successful releases on both [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391832/we-re-lowering-the-close-reopen-vote-threshold-from-5-to-3-for-good) and [the network as a whole](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide). We hope to continue evolving and refining this system in the new year, so it's worth keeping an eye on how we're all using this system.

So, for the [fourth year in a row](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321318/2018-a-year-in-closing), I present for your amusement, entertainment and education... **A grey table containing numbers** reflecting how many questions were closed on various sites around the network in 2019:

```
                Site                   Asked   AskedAndClosed PctAskedAndClosed AllClosed DuplicatesClosed DuplicatesReopened OTClosed OTReopened UnclearClosed UnclearReopened TooBroadClosed TooBroadReopened OpinionBasedClosed OpinionBasedReopened
------------------------------------ --------- -------------- ----------------- --------- ---------------- ------------------ -------- ---------- ------------- --------------- -------------- ---------------- ------------------ --------------------
Stack Overflow                       2,717,332        320,314           11.79 %   340,072          138,952              5,401   79,169      1,643        44,058           1,342         67,314            1,152             10,579                  150
Super User                              72,297         12,881           17.82 %    13,188            1,128                 43    6,972        106         2,133              79          2,629               72                326                    7
Server Fault                            26,750          5,127           19.17 %     5,368              509                 14    3,754         79           717              59            308                7                 80                    2
Stack Apps                                 223             75           33.63 %       126               19                  0      100          8             1               0              0                0                  0                    0
Seasoned Advice                          2,377            476           20.03 %       499              204                  5      133          5            71               3             52                3                 39                    2
Home Improvement                         9,539            627            6.57 %       696              110                  3      395          2            89               1             64                0                 38                    0
Game Development                         5,735            892           15.55 %       957              158                  4      462         23            98               7            169               10                 70                    3
Arqade                                   7,344          2,075           28.25 %     2,657            1,076                 16      710         23           526              32            260               12                 85                    4
GIS                                     20,679          5,180           25.05 %     6,002              793                 30    2,259        221         1,318             159          1,432              190                200                    7
Mathematics                            206,635         31,674           15.33 %    34,162            8,776                230   20,595        611         4,043             146            484               14                264                    6
Photography                              2,548            649           25.47 %       671              249                 13      262          2           102               4             36                2                 22                    1
Cross Validated                         34,871          8,651           24.81 %     9,591            1,534                 48    4,004        182         3,356             399            620               50                 77                    5
Web Applications                         5,746          1,238           21.55 %     1,368              218                  2      698          3           302              11            121                1                 29                    0
Webmasters                               3,790          1,424           37.57 %     1,448              320                 11      593         28           247              55            196               29                 92                    2
Ask Different                           14,028          2,294           16.35 %     2,458              884                 61      621         55           635             132            223               39                 95                   11
Theoretical Computer Science             1,289            253           19.63 %       258                7                  1      223          4            19               0              8                0                  1                    0
English Language & Usage                17,998          7,750           43.06 %     8,063            1,155                 19    5,165         82           966              34            202                6                575                    9
Money                                    5,106            955           18.70 %     1,014              241                 11      536         17           113              10             52                1                 72                    2
RPG                                      6,958          1,984           28.51 %     2,076              638                140      182         34           662             310            291              100                303                   81
TeX - LaTeX                             25,433          3,582           14.08 %     4,137            1,864                 91    1,090         27           969              25            156               13                 58                    2
Ask Ubuntu                              51,130          9,698           18.97 %    10,478            4,950                 89    3,379         65         1,693              69            249                6                207                    9
Unix & Linux                            30,934          4,817           15.57 %     5,077            1,540                 64      995         16         1,575              56            767               17                200                    7
WordPress Development                   17,085          3,143           18.40 %     3,287              126                  3    2,678          6           202               4            252                2                 29                    0
Bicycles                                 1,916            301           15.71 %       316              101                  1      125          5            55               2             18                1                 17                    0
Software Engineering                     8,937          4,327           48.42 %     4,482              150                  5    2,243         16           433              17          1,314               37                342                   18
Android Enthusiasts                      7,279          1,823           25.04 %     1,937              408                 11    1,187         44           252              21             60                3                 30                    1
Board & Card Games                       1,555            262           16.85 %       292              133                 12       45          1            44               6             33                3                 37                    4
Physics                                 33,186         10,181           30.68 %    10,534            2,066                 48    5,690         35         1,912              35            564               33                302                    1
Homebrewing                                265              7            2.64 %        10                5                  0        4          0             1               0              0                0                  0                    0
Information Security                     9,898          3,736           37.74 %     3,835              600                  8    2,099         27           516              13            484                9                136                    4
Writing                                  2,002            512           25.57 %       532               96                  3      298         22            43               2             55                3                 40                    4
Electrical Engineering                  25,688          5,932           23.09 %     6,177              551                  8    2,467         49         1,665              60          1,324               25                170                    2
Graphic Design                           5,966            896           15.02 %       929              225                  5      346          7           134               7            172                3                 52                    1
DBA                                     14,016          3,055           21.80 %     3,528              372                 14    1,263         10         1,215              36            554                4                124                    2
Science Fiction & Fantasy                7,331          1,690           23.05 %     1,873              844                 55      380         59           216              43            175               38                258                   48
Area 51 Discussions                        282             63           22.34 %        66               29                  1       34          1             3               0              0                0                  0                    0
Code Review                             10,976          3,178           28.95 %     3,290               21                  1    2,979        104           258              17             14                0                 18                    0
Code Golf                                1,265            512           40.47 %       535               93                 17      243         20           184              49             15                0                  0                    0
Quantitative Finance                     3,312            515           15.55 %       523               55                  0      261          5           112               2             64                3                 31                    0
Project Management                         788            211           26.78 %       234                6                  0      107          2            37               2             34                0                 50                    3
Skeptics                                   975            341           34.97 %       345               36                  1      202         10            72              24             12                3                 23                    3
Drupal Answers                           7,628          1,745           22.88 %     2,391              203                  5      557         11           605               8            934               10                 92                    3
Physical Fitness                           837            252           30.11 %       266               43                  2      190          9            11               3             12                0                 10                    1
Motor Vehicles                           3,979            337            8.47 %       349               61                  0      120          3            98               1             34                1                 36                    0
Parenting                                  531            193           36.35 %       203               17                  0       78          8            49               2             31                5                 28                    2
SharePoint                               8,594            522            6.07 %       556               44                  1      186          1           220              17             86                7                 20                    0
Music                                    3,933          1,015           25.81 %     1,103              201                  9      477          7           144               6            116                2                165                    2
Software Quality Assurance & Testing     1,896            389           20.52 %       416               48                  1      132          1           140               4             71                4                 25                    3
Mi Yodeya                                4,540            991           21.83 %     1,090              444                 15      356         39           185              46             65               16                 40                    4
Astronomy                                2,046            372           18.18 %       379              110                  2      135         11            88               2             26                1                 20                    0
German Language                          1,968            454           23.07 %       465               89                  4      261         28            64              13             35                1                 16                    2
Japanese Language                        3,392            705           20.78 %       713              251                 10      406          8            28               4              8                1                 20                    0
Gardening & Landscaping                  2,153             88            4.09 %        91               11                  0       39          2            25               3             13                3                  3                    1
Philosophy                               2,841            774           27.24 %       796               54                  2      371         11           179               4             79                2                113                    3
Travel                                   8,665          3,542           40.88 %     3,706            1,421                 38    1,040         81           729              57            184               12                332                   19
Cryptography                             4,438          1,289           29.04 %     1,382              259                  7      756         21           221              13            123                9                 23                    1
Literature                                 841            140           16.65 %       142               11                  0       77          6            15               3             23                3                 16                    0
Signal Processing                        4,095            594           14.51 %       601               49                  1      204          3           212               9            121                1                 15                    0
French Language                          1,731            183           10.57 %       185               70                  2       62          4            19               4             22                1                 12                    1
Christianity                             1,480            526           35.54 %       546               74                 12      264         12            76               4             42                0                 90                    5
Bitcoin                                  3,854            810           21.02 %     1,060              172                  4      698          2           107               2             50                1                 33                    0
Linguistics                              1,659            483           29.11 %       495               26                  2      342          9            69               1             36                2                 22                    0
Biblical Hermeneutics                    1,381            246           17.81 %       261               40                  0      152          5            37               2             10                1                 22                    1
Economics                                2,906            567           19.51 %       581               32                  0      362          0           122               0             49                0                 16                    0
History                                  2,228            684           30.70 %       691               20                  0      357         17           109              10            136                7                 69                    2
Bricks                                     482             36            7.47 %        38               17                  0        8          0             5               0              7                0                  1                    0
Spanish Language                         1,109            146           13.17 %       151               66                  2       60          6            15               0              7                0                  3                    0
Computational Science                    1,338            164           12.26 %       204               11                  0      107          2            74               0             12                0                  0                    0
Movies & TV                              3,371          1,033           30.64 %     1,054              181                  9      535         22           111              19             76               10                151                   14
Chinese Language                         1,238             79            6.38 %        83               17                  1       59          0             7               2              0                0                  0                    0
Biology                                  4,249          1,130           26.59 %     1,188              140                  3      629         16           212               3            100                1                107                    2
Poker                                      222             55           24.77 %        57               36                  0       11          0             8               1              2                0                  0                    0
Mathematica                             10,381          2,217           21.36 %     2,313              459                  9    1,595         33           216              10             36                3                  7                    3
Psychology & Neuroscience                1,367            448           32.77 %       459               34                  0      266         10            58               6             49                1                 52                    5
The Great Outdoors                         592             78           13.18 %        80               22                  2       31          3            11               1              9                4                  7                    0
Martial Arts                               229             33           14.41 %        38                9                  0       13          0             6               0              3                0                  7                    0
Sports                                     767            275           35.85 %       287               44                  1      150          0            29               0             31                0                 33                    0
Academia                                 6,244          2,292           36.71 %     2,354              343                  4    1,483         31           268               6            110                5                150                   10
Computer Science                         8,271          1,838           22.22 %     1,883              328                  6      835         13           555              25            114                4                 51                    1
The Workplace                            5,247          1,813           34.55 %     1,831              279                 27      827         66           244              18            268               20                213                   25
Windows Phone                               60             17           28.33 %        17                5                  0        9          0             2               0              0                0                  1                    0
Chemistry                                9,389          4,839           51.54 %     4,953              464                  7    2,666        136         1,167              71            568               25                 88                    3
Chess                                      894            171           19.13 %       205               56                  5       59          4            15               2             25                2                 50                    1
Raspberry Pi                             5,969            731           12.25 %       780              113                  1      267          4           248              34            122                4                 30                    1
Russian Language                           607            133           21.91 %       136               13                  1       89          8            22               7             11                2                  1                    0
Islam                                    2,340            610           26.07 %       695              220                  1      174          1           180               2             59                1                 62                    0
Salesforce                              21,931          3,798           17.32 %     3,879              880                 15    1,505         20           878              11            521                9                 95                    1
Ask Patents                                398             57           14.32 %        57                8                  0       44          2             5               0              0                0                  0                    0
UX                                       2,514            631           25.10 %       667               61                  0      272          2            79               1             85                1                170                    1
Genealogy & Family History                 484             86           17.77 %        96               50                  0       14          2            14               0             16                0                  2                    0
Robotics                                 1,067            180           16.87 %       192               14                  1       35          1            50              11             32                2                 61                    3
ExpressionEngine® Answers                  404              8            1.98 %         8                0                  0        6          0             2               0              0                0                  0                    0
Politics                                 3,362          1,096           32.60 %     1,138              140                 10      541        101           179              25            102                9                176                   34
Video Production                         1,388             60            4.32 %        64               10                  0       30          0             7               0             12                0                  5                    0
Anime & Manga                            1,697            496           29.23 %       504               78                  2      296          4            52               1             16                1                 62                    0
Magento                                 20,532            937            4.56 %       993              212                 10      311          6           268              13            159                7                 43                    3
English Language Learners               16,793          2,306           13.73 %     2,415              356                 10    1,561        108           203              17            166                8                129                    1
Sustainable Living                         236             32           13.56 %        35                6                  0       11          0             7               0              9                0                  2                    0
Tridion                                    434              1            0.23 %         1                1                  1        0          0             0               0              0                0                  0                    0
Reverse Engineering                      1,437            235           16.35 %       241               15                  1      109          1            70               0             37                0                 10                    0
Arduino                                  5,358          1,352           25.23 %     1,388              173                  0      460         12           450              15            287                1                 18                    0
Network Engineering                      4,620          2,885           62.45 %     3,169              178                  6    2,231         18            91               8            619               42                 50                    2
Open Data                                  730             72            9.86 %        80               30                  2       35          3            15               0              0                0                  0                    0
Freelancing                                214             65           30.37 %        65                7                  0       14          0             2               0             32                0                 10                    0
Blender                                 19,177          2,389           12.46 %     2,526            1,431                 51      448          8           388              25            130                6                129                    0
MathOverflow                            16,523          3,103           18.78 %     3,144               66                  4    2,710         21           287               3             57                0                 24                    1
Space Exploration                        2,909            375           12.89 %       383              124                  7      119         21            60               9             52                8                 28                    4
Sound Design                               630            148           23.49 %       167               11                  0      123          2            14               1              9                1                 10                    0
Tor                                        803             64            7.97 %        81               29                  0       13          0            37               0              2                0                  0                    0
Pets                                       947            201           21.22 %       209              140                  2       34          1            25               0              6                0                  4                    1
Amateur Radio                              995             98            9.85 %        99               15                  1       37          6            28               8             11                2                  8                    8
Italian Language                           512             25            4.88 %        25               11                  2       10          1             2               0              0                0                  2                    0
Stack Overflow em Português             42,298         15,973           37.76 %    16,620            1,583                 53    9,713        262         4,359             113            789               18                176                    2
Aviation                                 4,132          1,111           26.89 %     1,147              296                 14      332         32           224              43            179                9                116                    8
Ebooks                                     173             16            9.25 %        16                1                  0       13          0             1               0              0                0                  1                    0
Beer, Wine & Spirits                        88             16           18.18 %        17                2                  0        3          0             1               0              5                0                  6                    0
Software Recommendations                12,465          4,477           35.92 %     4,487               26                  3    3,712         49           493              75            233               24                 23                    0
CS50                                     1,119             35            3.13 %        41               18                  1        7          0            12               1              2                0                  2                    0
Expatriates                              1,214             94            7.74 %        99               22                  0       21          0            23               1             16                0                 17                    0
Mathematics Educators                      413            105           25.42 %       115                6                  0       70          1            19               0             12                1                  8                    0
Earth Science                            1,444            555           38.43 %       904               29                  3      773         12            60               1             29                0                 13                    0
Joomla                                     713             50            7.01 %        69               11                  0       22          2            14               0             20                2                  2                    0
Data Science                            11,298          1,503           13.30 %     1,525               54                  0      581          3           328              16            477                6                 85                    0
Puzzling                                 4,043            698           17.26 %       708              135                 12      433         43            74               7             55                4                 11                    0
Craft CMS                                1,762             22            1.25 %        22                6                  0       11          0             3               0              2                0                  0                    0
Buddhism                                 1,069            108           10.10 %       109               26                  4       33          2            30               7              3                1                 17                    0
Hinduism                                 2,735            573           20.95 %       590              273                 15      163          5            38               8             29                2                 87                   11
Community Building                          86             15           17.44 %        19                0                  0       13          0             2               0              3                0                  1                    0
Worldbuilding                            5,197          1,657           31.88 %     1,690              175                 16      500         20           244              27            485               52                286                   16
スタック・オーバーフロー                             4,993            168            3.36 %       170               18                  0       84         14            46               3             16                0                  6                    0
Emacs                                    3,380            180            5.33 %       205               95                  4       36          1            48               8             21                3                  5                    0
History of Science and Mathematics         508             57           11.22 %        57               14                  0       26          1             8               0              5                0                  4                    0
Lifehacks                                  458            139           30.35 %       145               17                  0      120          2             6               0              1                0                  1                    0
Engineering                              2,751            458           16.65 %       463               19                  0      129          3           162              17            132                5                 21                    0
Coffee                                     137              7            5.11 %         7                2                  0        2          0             2               0              0                0                  1                    0
Vi and Vim                               1,771            143            8.07 %       152               77                  1       43          1            22               1              8                0                  2                    0
Music Fans                                 663            117           17.65 %       176               13                  2      122          1            10               0             10                0                 21                    0
Woodworking                                430             34            7.91 %        35                8                  0       14          1             5               1              8                0                  0                    0
CiviCRM                                  2,064             22            1.07 %        23               18                  0        3          0             2               0              0                0                  0                    0
Medical Sciences                         1,612            823           51.05 %       924               19                  0      773         25            58               2             33                3                 41                    1
Stack Overflow на русском               78,086         12,057           15.44 %    12,479            1,798                 45    5,128        188         3,497              88          1,107               29                949                    7
Русский язык                             3,179            307            9.66 %       318               48                  1      143          6            68               7             25                3                 34                    1
Mythology & Folklore                       237             27           11.39 %        28                5                  0       11          0             3               0              7                0                  2                    0
Law                                      4,722            715           15.14 %       747              104                  3      418         19           113               7             89                5                 23                    2
Open Source                                676            103           15.24 %       103               32                  0       48          1            13               0              3                0                  7                    0
elementary OS                            1,575            124            7.87 %       343               93                  4      225         11            17               0              6                0                  2                    0
Portuguese Language                        236             16            6.78 %        16                4                  0        7          0             2               1              3                0                  0                    0
Computer Graphics                          597             37            6.20 %        37                0                  0       25          0            10               1              1                0                  1                    0
Hardware Recommendations                 1,708            848           49.65 %       863                5                  0      711          7            37               1             92                1                 18                    0
Stack Overflow en español               49,704          7,127           14.34 %     7,478              819                 13    2,585        101         1,508              42          1,462               28              1,104                   15
3D Printing                              1,078            118           10.95 %       121               35                  5       39          1            30               5              8                0                  9                    0
Ethereum                                 6,134            789           12.86 %       834              212                  1      217          1           232               3            137                0                 36                    1
Latin Language                             859             33            3.84 %        34                8                  0       15          0             7               0              3                0                  1                    0
Language Learning                          258             89           34.50 %        89                2                  0       63          1             7               3              9                1                  8                    2
Retrocomputing                             944            119           12.61 %       123               14                  2       52          9            20               6             25                3                 12                    1
Arts & Crafts                              357             95           26.61 %        98                5                  0       66          5            12               2             14                2                  1                    0
Korean Language                            240              8            3.33 %         8                1                  0        2          0             4               0              0                0                  1                    0
Monero                                     565             58           10.27 %        63               54                  0        5          0             2               0              1                0                  1                    0
Artificial Intelligence                  3,179            259            8.15 %       280               31                  0      161          4            46               5             35                1                  7                    0
Esperanto Language                         171              5            2.92 %         5                2                  0        1          0             0               0              0                0                  2                    1
Sitecore                                 3,394            621           18.30 %       647              151                  8      303         30            60               7            113                9                 20                    1
Internet of Things                         539            136           25.23 %       137                4                  0       45          0            28               1             51                0                  9                    1
Veganism & Vegetarianism                   110             28           25.45 %        28                6                  0       12          1             3               1              4                0                  3                    0
Ukrainian Language                         264             19            7.20 %        19                1                  0        7          0             5               1              6                2                  0                    0
DevOps                                   1,774            360           20.29 %       478               17                  1       54          3           294              16             77                6                 36                    5
Bioinformatics                           1,078             69            6.40 %        70                8                  1       23          0            11               0             22                1                  6                    0
Computer Science Educators                 239             82           34.31 %        83                3                  0       62          5             3               0             10                0                  5                    0
Interpersonal Skills                     1,178            592           50.25 %       640               15                  1      267         26           105              19            126               10                127                    7
Augur                                       43              1            2.33 %         1                0                  0        1          0             0               0              0                0                  0                    0
Iota                                        88              7            7.95 %         7                0                  0        1          0             3               0              3                0                  0                    0
Stellar                                    456             35            7.68 %        36               11                  0        9          2             7               0              7                1                  2                    0
Constructed Languages                       68             14           20.59 %        14                2                  0        4          1             1               1              4                0                  3                    0
Quantum Computing                        1,518            170           11.20 %       178               33                  2       34          4            65              12             29                5                 13                    3
EOS.IO                                     751             46            6.13 %        57               37                  0       11          0             5               0              2                0                  2                    0
Tezos                                      907             76            8.38 %        76               30                  1       12          0            12               1             19                0                  3                    0
Operations Research                        657             53            8.07 %        53                8                  1       19          5             6               2             14                6                  6                    4
```

Notes:

- this counts questions asked in 2019 and questions closed in 2019 - the AskedAndClosed and PctAskedAndClosed columns reflect questions that were *both* asked and closed in 2019, while the remaining columns total up all questions closed in 2019 - even those asked in prior years.
- reopen numbers also include questions asked in years prior - but limit themselves to questions that were closed in 2019 and then also reopened in 2019.
- if a question was closed twice, it'll be counted twice
- if a question was reopened twice, it'll be counted twice

### Alternate formats

- CSV: https://gist.github.com/Shog9/317b3b8dfa3e387b0503376200779fee

Comment: I'll admit, I was kinda hoping to see MSE in the table. Not just because it would surface the moderation impact of a high-intensity community situation but also would show how many people get lost and ask their question here instead of on some other site (intentionally or unintentionally). Or duplicate questions, etc. Basically, a very muddy way to grade the effectiveness of MSE as a site.

Comment: No matter how bad/contentious stuff gets - I think MUCH more gets closed/deleted here cause its blatantly OT than due to high intensity community situations.

Comment: I honestly kinda hate lumping MSE into stuff like this, @Troyen - it's not really comparable to *any* other site, and the closest sites to compare to are... Other meta sites, which I also don't post #s on. Might be worth doing separately at some point, but... Eh.

Comment: @Troyen Closures are more common on this site than on others, and it seems unfair to assess this site as its difference would come down to its nature rather than the way it's moderated. For instance, blatantly off-topic questions as you mentioned, as well as more lenient policies for duplicate closures, and other stuff.

Comment: I'm stunned how busy Mathmatics is - are they really the second-busiest site with only Stack Overglow having more questions asked ?

Comment: @Criggie: Stack Overglow is a brilliant site! Very illuminating ;)

Comment: @Sonic With all the debate over meta no longer being useful, it would be nice to see just how much of a problem the current setup is.  A glance at the homepage usually doesn't show much amiss, but I have stumbled across the errant question that gets quickly closed and deleted, so I know they exist.  When people say the close rate here is "high", what does that mean?  Higher than IPS's 50%?

Comment: @Troyen It means it's artificially high, and thus cannot really be compared with those of other sites. Its rate may be lower than that of IPS, let's say 30%, but to say that it has a similar rate to Linguistics or Movies & TV would be an inaccurate statement because of the meaning and nature behind those closures.

Comment: @Sonic My interest wasn't in comparing to other sites. My interest was in gauging the effectiveness and usefulness of Meta with respect to the company's decision to phase Meta out.  This just happened to be a post that provided all the closing stats around the network...but didn't include MSE.