# In 2019, which sites had the fewest/most moderator-handled flags per question?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation

I just ask out of curiosity...

**Question**: In 2019, which sites had the fewest/most moderator-handled flags per question?

*How to calculate this*: from Shog9's Chinese.SE [2019: a year in moderation](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1649/2019-a-year-in-moderation):

> ```
>                  Action                  Moderators Community¹
> ---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
> Question flags handled⁵                         100        117
> Comment flags handled                           141        210
> Answer flags handled                            291         20
> ```

There were 1120 questions created in 2019 ([`created:2019 is:question`](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2019%20is%3Aquestion)) ignoring deleted questions.  Thus:

```
Chinese.SE:  (100 + 141 + 291) / 1120 = 0.475
```

With similar manual calculations...

```
Math.SE:             (2498 + 7829 + 3394) /  165365 = 0.083
StackOverflow:  (45195 + 244261 + 265031) / 2097109 = 0.264
Meta.SE              (3452 + 7207 + 2616) /    3898 = 3.406
IPS.SE                 (295 + 2304 + 725) /     664 = 5.006
```

I'm hoping someone can figure out how to complete this list (without doing it manually for all N sites).

(I don't believe the data is available for per-site metas.)

Comment: Was there a table published with all the data?  I vaguely remember such a table.  If so, then it could go into a spreadsheet.

Comment: @aparente001 I only remember tables comparing various sites about closing, not about flags: [2019: a year in closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341507). In 2018 somebody also compiled how closing was divided between community and moderators in an answer to [2019: a year in closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341507)

Comment: @aparente001 literally the first column of the first table in the linked post has as description `asked`. I assume that indicates the amount of questions asked for each listed site in 2019. For SO that is about 2.7M questions, probably taking into account deleted questions as well.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming I haven't totally messed this up, I worked it out:

```
Site                   Qf   Af   Cf    #Qs  ratio
----
Tridion                 5   17    2    434  0.055
Mathematica            95  434  131  10381  0.064
Mathematics          2498 3394 7829 206635  0.066
Emacs                  22  198   27   3380  0.073
CiviCRM                17  155    3   2064  0.085

...

TheWorkplace          791  960 5769   5247  1.433
MathematicsEducators   72  113  442    413  1.518
Skeptics              329  657  871    975  1.905
WindowsPhone            9  130    1     60  2.333
InterpersonalSkills   295  725 2304   1178  2.822
```

I used the question count from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341507/2019-a-year-in-closing) which includes deleted questions, but the data is incomplete:

- Missing "2019: a year in moderation" data: Area51Discussions, Augur, CS50, OperationsResearch, StackApps, StackOverflowemPortuguês, StackOverflowenespañol, StackOverflowнарусском, Tezos, Русскийязык, スタック・オーバーフロー.
- I don't know how many deleted questions there were at meta.SE.

---

Here's a CSV of the data.  I'm not sure how to make this look nice (I'd appreciate some help).

```
site Qflags Aflags Clfags Qs ratio
Tridion 5 17 2 434 0.055
Mathematica 95 434 131 10381 0.064
Mathematics 2498 3394 7829 206635 0.066
Emacs 22 198 27 3380 0.073
CiviCRM 17 155 3 2064 0.085
ViandVim 15 115 38 1771 0.095
ComputationalScience 57 54 23 1338 0.1
CraftCMS 3 149 30 1762 0.103
Engineering 46 181 59 2751 0.104
SignalProcessing 65 309 55 4095 0.105
ExpressionEngine®Answers 4 38 5 404 0.116
Bioinformatics 33 72 22 1078 0.118
DataScience 284 991 107 11298 0.122
MathOverflow 735 801 540 16523 0.126
GameDevelopment 223 406 113 5735 0.129
QuantitativeFinance 58 322 51 3312 0.13
KoreanLanguage 3 28 2 240 0.138
JapaneseLanguage 131 267 109 3392 0.149
ComputerGraphics 24 60 6 597 0.151
QuantumComputing 85 112 34 1518 0.152
TheoreticalComputerScience 57 57 85 1289 0.154
Ethereum 79 816 84 6134 0.16
Sitecore 210 341 10 3394 0.165
ComputerScience 335 535 527 8271 0.169
CrossValidated 937 2827 2135 34871 0.169
EOSIO 29 98 1 751 0.17
Magento 305 2736 507 20532 0.173
Blender 358 2779 220 19177 0.175
Salesforce 331 3317 286 21931 0.179
EsperantoLanguage 3 21 9 171 0.193
GIS 452 3059 510 20679 0.194
TeX-LaTeX 248 1192 3483 25433 0.194
Physics 1225 3703 1745 33186 0.201
StackOverflow 45195 265031 244261 2717332 0.204
Cryptography 331 425 164 4438 0.207
Economics 309 228 75 2906 0.211
OpenSource 51 53 39 676 0.212
ServerFault 1253 3786 684 26750 0.214
Gardening&Landscaping 54 400 21 2153 0.221
ItalianLanguage 3 78 34 512 0.225
SoftwareRecommendations 2006 678 131 12465 0.226
Robotics 47 151 48 1067 0.231
VideoProduction 30 283 14 1388 0.236
EnglishLanguageLearners 360 2859 757 16793 0.237
Stellar 37 50 23 456 0.241
DevOps 162 197 82 1774 0.249
Monero 16 124 3 565 0.253
Unix&Linux 654 5095 2245 30934 0.258
WordPressDevelopment 1497 2594 374 17085 0.261
SharePoint 164 1993 91 8594 0.262
ReverseEngineering 83 205 95 1437 0.267
SoftwareEngineering 1554 390 469 8937 0.27
Arduino 158 1200 106 5358 0.273
RussianLanguage 49 98 26 607 0.285
Board&CardGames 68 187 192 1555 0.287
OpenData 46 138 31 730 0.295
CodeReview 481 1574 1349 10976 0.31
FrenchLanguage 45 365 126 1731 0.31
ElectricalEngineering 885 5650 1456 25688 0.311
Joomla 25 119 86 713 0.323
DrupalAnswers 648 1025 816 7628 0.326
elementaryOS 131 378 4 1575 0.326
AskUbuntu 1708 11917 3515 51130 0.335
InternetofThings 44 116 21 539 0.336
Webmasters 367 809 101 3790 0.337
AmateurRadio 127 167 42 995 0.338
Genealogy&FamilyHistory 39 118 10 484 0.345
RaspberryPi 220 1688 159 5969 0.346
DBA 251 2018 2699 14016 0.354
NetworkEngineering 232 383 1032 4620 0.356
SpaceExploration 116 495 430 2909 0.358
SuperUser 5216 18096 5002 72297 0.392
AskPatents 55 85 18 398 0.397
GraphicDesign 745 1417 217 5966 0.399
Linguistics 200 317 149 1659 0.401
UX 291 561 172 2514 0.407
Iota 15 21 0 88 0.409
Law 176 1266 549 4722 0.422
Buddhism 113 222 118 1069 0.424
ProjectManagement 81 223 33 788 0.428
Astronomy 125 503 250 2046 0.429
ChineseLanguage 100 291 141 1238 0.43
Poker 21 69 6 222 0.432
Ebooks 19 53 3 173 0.434
InformationSecurity 985 2647 685 9898 0.436
SoftwareQualityAssurance&Testing 182 573 94 1896 0.448
Woodworking 20 159 15 430 0.451
ComputerScienceEducators 46 52 10 239 0.452
Philosophy 244 688 352 2841 0.452
MiYodeya 243 378 1447 4540 0.456
Homebrewing 4 108 9 265 0.457
Biology 397 901 653 4249 0.459
HistoryofScienceandMathematics 31 141 66 508 0.469
Chemistry 436 2176 1851 9389 0.475
PhysicalFitness 140 220 38 837 0.476
HomeImprovement 280 3313 989 9539 0.48
SoundDesign 44 233 26 630 0.481
Puzzling 380 507 1073 4043 0.485
EnglishLanguage&Usage 937 5734 2110 17998 0.488
Movies&TV 375 674 611 3371 0.492
Psychology&Neuroscience 170 291 216 1367 0.495
ConstructedLanguages 11 22 1 68 0.5
Aviation 227 1182 688 4132 0.508
EarthScience 203 381 149 1444 0.508
AskDifferent 1361 5074 857 14028 0.52
Tor 59 349 16 803 0.528
AndroidEnthusiasts 733 2750 366 7279 0.529
UkrainianLanguage 6 103 32 264 0.534
Bricks 6 235 19 482 0.539
MotorVehicles 72 1953 120 3979 0.539
Worldbuilding 840 1197 845 5197 0.555
GermanLanguage 107 565 430 1968 0.56
Islam 222 955 135 2340 0.561
MedicalSciences 595 234 76 1612 0.561
Writing 260 366 497 2002 0.561
HardwareRecommendations 864 96 14 1708 0.57
Literature 86 207 186 841 0.57
SustainableLiving 11 80 48 236 0.589
ArtificialIntelligence 273 384 1223 3179 0.591
Expatriates 50 648 46 1214 0.613
Music 268 1493 658 3933 0.615
LatinLanguage 44 136 361 859 0.63
Arts&Crafts 54 156 18 357 0.639
Academia 806 1680 1553 6244 0.647
SpanishLanguage 55 472 204 1109 0.659
Bitcoin 658 1842 79 3854 0.669
LanguageLearning 48 31 102 258 0.702
Bicycles 102 1131 134 1916 0.713
ScienceFiction&Fantasy 508 1809 2922 7331 0.715
BeerWine&Spirits 8 46 9 88 0.716
Chess 61 273 313 894 0.724
BiblicalHermeneutics 76 658 273 1381 0.729
Pets 61 568 72 947 0.74
Hinduism 299 954 794 2735 0.748
Money 656 1593 1570 5106 0.748
SeasonedAdvice 193 1338 246 2377 0.748
Arqade 535 4179 912 7344 0.766
Freelancing 74 88 2 214 0.766
3DPrinting 147 335 377 1078 0.797
Sports 91 448 87 767 0.816
Veganism&Vegetarianism 11 51 28 110 0.818
History 231 805 809 2228 0.828
WebApplications 540 3871 355 5746 0.829
Photography 147 1364 664 2548 0.854
Retrocomputing 66 319 437 944 0.871
CodeGolf 214 458 455 1265 0.891
MartialArts 15 70 120 229 0.895
PortugueseLanguage 3 179 30 236 0.898
TheGreatOutdoors 73 314 147 592 0.902
Travel 818 5451 1628 8665 0.911
Mythology&Folklore 18 187 22 237 0.958
Anime&Manga 178 1377 231 1697 1.052
Parenting 82 387 94 531 1.06
Christianity 174 985 537 1480 1.146
MusicFans 90 413 262 663 1.154
RPG 396 1335 6312 6958 1.156
CommunityBuilding 72 16 13 86 1.174
Lifehacks 67 401 116 458 1.275
Coffee 12 159 9 137 1.314
Politics 656 999 2898 3362 1.354
TheWorkplace 791 960 5769 5247 1.433
MathematicsEducators 72 113 442 413 1.518
Skeptics 329 657 871 975 1.905
WindowsPhone 9 130 1 60 2.333
InterpersonalSkills 295 725 2304 1178 2.822
Meta.SE 3452 2616 7207 0
```

---

In anyone wants to reproduce this themselves...

I used the search [`title:"2019: a year in moderation"`](https://stackexchange.com/search?page=1&q=title%3A%222019%3A%20a%20year%20in%20moderation%22&pagesize=1000) (editing the URL to include all sites).  Saving the results as `temp.html`, the `grep` and `awk` command gives the 166 URLs:

```
grep ">2019: a year in moderation" temp.html | awk -F"\"" '{print $2}' | awk -F"\">https:" '{print $1}' > temp2.txt
```

From `temp2.txt`, I created a bash file and ran `wget` to download all 166 pages.  I used

```
grep 'performed on\|flags handled' * > temp3.txt
```

to extract the site names and relevant data.  I had to do some manual clean-up here.  Afterwards, I extracted the site names using:

```
grep "performed on" temp3.txt | awk -F"performed on " '{print $2}' | awk -F" over the" '{print $1}' > temp4.txt
```

From here I extracted the number of flags via, e.g.:

```
grep "Question flags handled" temp3.txt | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/,//' > temp5.txt
```

From here, I simply copy/pasted the numbers in a spreadsheet.

Comment: Info from [es.so] is in https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4523/83. From [ru.so] in https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9952/193685, from [pt.so] in https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8115/28073 and from [ja.so] in https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3182/19559.