# When not logged in, why is my search limited to 500 hits?

Tags: discussion, search

In answering [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342610/in-2019-which-sites-had-the-fewest-most-moderator-handled-flags-per-question/342632?noredirect=1#comment1147193_342632) I stumbled upon some peculiar behavior.

#### No account: 500 hits

[image]

#### Incognito mode: 500 hits

[image]

I'm not sure why this is...

**Question**: When not logged in, why is my search limited to 500 hits?

I'm not sure if this is a "bug" or a "feature".

Comment: Risk mitigation; anonymous users using search to scrape the site is a bigger problem than a user with an account that is doing the same, so anonymous users are rate limited on the number of search results returned for any given search.

Comment: (Note: I'm speculating, I don't have first-hand knowledge that it *is* a rate limit, but if it wasn't this would be a very peculiar bug indeed. It wasn't listed in the [rate limits FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899) nor can I find any other explicit confirmation).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Search is heavily rate-limited in various ways for anonymous users for performance reasons. Anonymous users get cut off after 500 results and are also limited to three tags when performing tag searches. I believe there were a couple other minor features that are disabled for anonymous users. The sorting options were also disabled at the time, but I don't know if they are still disabled for anonymous users.

They were implemented many years ago to mitigate a DDOS attack and then never removed.

Comment: I thought the restriction against searching multiple tags as a logged-out user was removed a while ago. In 2015-16 it didn't work, but sometime in 2017 it started working, and I just tested today and it works.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Looks like we increased the limit to three tags. After that, we cut off additional tags.