# Where should I ask a question about how the Internet works (financially)?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

My question is about an ISP forwarding **foreign** traffic.

So neither the source nor the destination is a customer of the ISP.

But the ISP owns a data cable which is part of the way from the source to the destination.

Will the ISP get money?

Answer (score 2):

The best place to ask this type of question is the network engineering Stack Exchange site, at https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, and they have "Operating, maintaining, purchasing or managing an enterprise / service provider network" as on-topic. Regarding the caveat, "under your direct control (if the network is not under your control you will not likely be able to provide the information required to answer your question)" I think that is stated there because of the part in parentheses. But for this particular question, I think it is an exception, and the information required to answer the question is provided with the question.

Comment: Also, the knowledge to answer this question would probably be more readily found in the network engineering community rather than economics community, as it is more related to technical details of how the Internet is engineered, from which the economic arrangements flow

Answer (score 2):

Such a question would be likely be off-topic for [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> #### Network Engineering Stack Exchange is for asking questions about professionally managed networks in a business environment.

Now this *is* a professionally managed network (hopefully), but it does not meet

> the following requirements
>
> - under your direct control (if the network is not under your control you will not likely be able to provide the information required to answer your question);
> - hardware that has a paid support option from the manufacturer (enterprise/provider class products, some small business class devices);

In defense of the other answer, I did find a well-received 'philosophical' question on their site: [Network Neutrality, how does it actually work, technically speaking?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7924/31801) so perhaps it *might* work.

I would think that it's more oriented towards understanding the business model of a certain company, and [Economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) would be a better candidate. But do check their Help Center before asking.

Comment: Thanks for the comment/question, and finding the question on network neutrality. I guess the question may be debatable, depending on who's reading it and their interpretation of things.

Comment: @auspicious99 sure. Perhaps it's time to update their Help Center article (the moderators there can do that). I can imagine they want to exclude a lot of consumer network questions, they have [one of the highest closing percentages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341507/2952320) of the network (pun intended).