# Which Stack Exchange website has the highest question close percentage?

Tags: discussion, voting, closed-questions, statistics

Which Stack Exchange website has the highest question close percentage?

I see on https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats that Medical Sciences Stack Exchange's question close percentage is 39.5% (probably lower than usual due to COVID-19-related leniency), and I wonder if any other Stack Exchange website is topping that.

The percentage I quote is computed over the last 90 days, which is the longest available span on the statistics page (looking at shorter spans, e.g. one day, increases the variance).

Answer (score 4):

I would imagine it's almost certainly the one you're asking this question on right now. Probably the majority of the questions we get are actually from the lost and there are many others that we close as duplicates. Since most of us are high rep users elsewhere we're actually pretty good at finding duplicates.

Anyway [this site's close percentage over 90 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days) is 55.56%

Comment: Thanks good point I hadn't considered Meta.SE.

Answer (score 4):

Re-ordering the table from [2019: a year in closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341507/178179) (thanks to [Rob](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/282094/rob) for pointing to it) on `PctAskedAndClosed` (shortened as `PctAskedAndC`):

```
Site                           Asked        AskedAndClos PctAskedAndC AllClosed    DuplicatesCl DuplicatesRe OTClosed     OTReopened   UnclearClo UnclearReopen TooBroadClosed  TooBroadReopen OpinionBasedClos OpinionBasedReopen  
Network Engineering            4620         2885         62.44588745  3169         178          6            2231         18           91         8             619             42             50               2                   
Chemistry                      9389         4839         51.53903504  4953         464          7            2666         136          1167       71            568             25             88               3                   
Medical Sciences               1612         823          51.05459057  924          19           0            773          25           58         2             33              3              41               1                   
Interpersonal Skills           1178         592          50.25466893  640          15           1            267          26           105        19            126             10             127              7                   
Hardware Recommendations       1708         848          49.64871194  863          5            0            711          7            37         1             92              1              18               0                   
Software Engineering           8937         4327         48.41669464  4482         150          5            2243         16           433        17            1314            37             342              18                  
English Language & Usage       17998        7750         43.06034004  8063         1155         19           5165         82           966        34            202             6              575              9                   
Travel                         8665         3542         40.87709175  3706         1421         38           1040         81           729        57            184             12             332              19                  
Code Golf                      1265         512          40.4743083   535          93           17           243          20           184        49            15              0              0                0                   
Earth Science                  1444         555          38.43490305  904          29           3            773          12           60         1             29              0              13               0                   
Stack Overflow em Português    42298        15973        37.7630148   16620        1583         53           9713         262          4359       113           789             18             176              2                   
Information Security           9898         3736         37.74499899  3835         600          8            2099         27           516        13            484             9              136              4                   
Webmasters                     3790         1424         37.57255937  1448         320          11           593          28           247        55            196             29             92               2                   
Academia                       6244         2292         36.70723895  2354         343          4            1483         31           268        6             110             5              150              10                  
Parenting                      531          193          36.34651601  203          17           0            78           8            49         2             31              5              28               2                   
Software Recommendations       12465        4477         35.91656639  4487         26           3            3712         49           493        75            233             24             23               0                   
Sports                         767          275          35.85397653  287          44           1            150          0            29         0             31              0              33               0                   
Christianity                   1480         526          35.54054054  546          74           12           264          12           76         4             42              0              90               5                   
Skeptics                       975          341          34.97435897  345          36           1            202          10           72         24            12              3              23               3                   
The Workplace                  5247         1813         34.55307795  1831         279          27           827          66           244        18            268             20             213              25                  
Language Learning              258          89           34.49612403  89           2            0            63           1            7          3             9               1              8                2                   
Computer Science Educators     239          82           34.30962343  83           3            0            62           5            3          0             10              0              5                0                   
Stack Apps                     223          75           33.632287    126          19           0            100          8            1          0             0               0              0                0                   
Psychology & Neuroscience      1367         448          32.77249451  459          34           0            266          10           58         6             49              1              52               5                   
Politics                       3362         1096         32.59964307  1138         140          10           541          101          179        25            102             9              176              34                  
Worldbuilding                  5197         1657         31.8837791   1690         175          16           500          20           244        27            485             52             286              16                  
History                        2228         684          30.70017953  691          20           0            357          17           109        10            136             7              69               2                   
Physics                        33186        10181        30.67859941  10534        2066         48           5690         35           1912       35            564             33             302              1                   
Movies & TV                    3371         1033         30.6437259   1054         181          9            535          22           111        19            76              10             151              14                  
Freelancing                    214          65           30.37383178  65           7            0            14           0            2          0             32              0              10               0                   
Lifehacks                      458          139          30.34934498  145          17           0            120          2            6          0             1               0              1                0                   
Physical Fitness               837          252          30.10752688  266          43           2            190          9            11         3             12              0              10               1                   
Anime & Manga                  1697         496          29.2280495   504          78           2            296          4            52         1             16              1              62               0                   
Linguistics                    1659         483          29.11392405  495          26           2            342          9            69         1             36              2              22               0                   
Cryptography                   4438         1289         29.04461469  1382         259          7            756          21           221        13            123             9              23               1                   
Code Review                    10976        3178         28.95408163  3290         21           1            2979         104          258        17            14              0              18               0                   
RPG                            6958         1984         28.51394079  2076         638          140          182          34           662        310           291             100            303              81                  
Windows Phone                  60           17           28.33333333  17           5            0            9            0            2          0             0               0              1                0                   
Arqade                         7344         2075         28.2543573   2657         1076         16           710          23           526        32            260             12             85               4                   
Philosophy                     2841         774          27.24392819  796          54           2            371          11           179        4             79              2              113              3                   
Aviation                       4132         1111         26.88770571  1147         296          14           332          32           224        43            179             9              116              8                   
Project Management             788          211          26.77664975  234          6            0            107          2            37         2             34              0              50               3                   
Arts & Crafts                  357          95           26.61064426  98           5            0            66           5            12         2             14              2              1                0                   
Biology                        4249         1130         26.59449282  1188         140          3            629          16           212        3             100             1              107              2                   
Islam                          2340         610          26.06837607  695          220          1            174          1            180        2             59              1              62               0                   
Music                          3933         1015         25.8072718   1103         201          9            477          7            144        6             116             2              165              2                   
Writing                        2002         512          25.57442557  532          96           3            298          22           43         2             55              3              40               4                   
Photography                    2548         649          25.47095761  671          249          13           262          2            102        4             36              2              22               1                   
Veganism & Vegetarianism       110          28           25.45454545  28           6            0            12           1            3          1             4               0              3                0                   
Mathematics Educators          413          105          25.42372881  115          6            0            70           1            19         0             12              1              8                0                   
Arduino                        5358         1352         25.23329601  1388         173          0            460          12           450        15            287             1              18               0                   
Internet of Things             539          136          25.23191095  137          4            0            45           0            28         1             51              0              9                1                   
UX                             2514         631          25.09944312  667          61           0            272          2            79         1             85              1              170              1                   
GIS                            20679        5180         25.04956719  6002         793          30           2259         221          1318       159           1432            190            200              7                   
Android Enthusiasts            7279         1823         25.04464899  1937         408          11           1187         44           252        21            60              3              30               1                   
Cross Validated                34871        8651         24.8085802   9591         1534         48           4004         182          3356       399           620             50             77               5                   
Poker                          222          55           24.77477477  57           36           0            11           0            8          1             2               0              0                0                   
Sound Design                   630          148          23.49206349  167          11           0            123          2            14         1             9               1              10               0                   
Electrical Engineering         25688        5932         23.09249455  6177         551          8            2467         49           1665       60            1324            25             170              2                   
German Language                1968         454          23.06910569  465          89           4            261          28           64         13            35              1              16               2                   
Science Fiction & Fantasy      7331         1690         23.05278952  1873         844          55           380          59           216        43            175             38             258              48                  
Drupal Answers                 7628         1745         22.87624541  2391         203          5            557          11           605        8             934             10             92               3                   
Area 51 Discussions            282          63           22.34042553  66           29           1            34           1            3          0             0               0              0                0                   
Computer Science               8271         1838         22.22222222  1883         328          6            835          13           555        25            114             4              51               1                   
Russian Language               607          133          21.91103789  136          13           1            89           8            22         7             11              2              1                0                   
Mi Yodeya                      4540         991          21.82819383  1090         444          15           356          39           185        46            65              16             40               4                   
DBA                            14016        3055         21.79651826  3528         372          14           1263         10           1215       36            554             4              124              2                   
Web Applications               5746         1238         21.5454229   1368         218          2            698          3            302        11            121             1              29               0                   
Mathematica                    10381        2217         21.35632405  2313         459          9            1595         33           216        10            36              3              7                3                   
Pets                           947          201          21.2249208   209          140          2            34           1            25         0             6               0              4                1                   
Bitcoin                        3854         810          21.01712506  1060         172          4            698          2            107        2             50              1              33               0                   
Hinduism                       2735         573          20.95063985  590          273          15           163          5            38         8             29              2              87               11                  
Japanese Language              3392         705          20.78419811  713          251          10           406          8            28         4             8               1              20               0                   
Constructed Languages          68           14           20.58823529  14           2            0            4            1            1          1             4               0              3                0                   
Software Quality Assurance & T 1896         389          20.51687764  416          48           1            132          1            140        4             71              4              25               3                   
DevOps                         1774         360          20.29312289  478          17           1            54           3            294        16            77              6              36               5                   
Seasoned Advice                2377         476          20.0252419   499          204          5            133          5            71         3             52              3              39               2                   
Theoretical Computer Science   1289         253          19.62761831  258          7            1            223          4            19         0             8               0              1                0                   
Economics                      2906         567          19.51135582  581          32           0            362          0            122        0             49              0              16               0                   
Server Fault                   26750        5127         19.16635514  5368         509          14           3754         79           717        59            308             7              80               2                   
Chess                          894          171          19.12751678  205          56           5            59           4            15         2             25              2              50               1                   
Ask Ubuntu                     51130        9698         18.96733816  10478        4950         89           3379         65           1693       69            249             6              207              9                   
MathOverflow                   16523        3103         18.77988259  3144         66           4            2710         21           287        3             57              0              24               1                   
Money                          5106         955          18.70348609  1014         241          11           536          17           113        10            52              1              72               2                   
WordPress Development          17085        3143         18.39625402  3287         126          3            2678         6            202        4             252             2              29               0                   
Sitecore                       3394         621          18.2969947   647          151          8            303          30           60         7             113             9              20               1                   
Astronomy                      2046         372          18.18181818  379          110          2            135          11           88         2             26              1              20               0                   
"Beer                           Wine & Spir 88           16           18.18181818  17           2            0            3            0          1             0               5              0                6                  0
Super User                     72297        12881        17.81678355  13188        1128         43           6972         106          2133       79            2629            72             326              7                   
Biblical Hermeneutics          1381         246          17.81317886  261          40           0            152          5            37         2             10              1              22               1                   
Genealogy & Family History     484          86           17.76859504  96           50           0            14           2            14         0             16              0              2                0                   
Music Fans                     663          117          17.64705882  176          13           2            122          1            10         0             10              0              21               0                   
Community Building             86           15           17.44186047  19           0            0            13           0            2          0             3               0              1                0                   
Salesforce                     21931        3798         17.31795176  3879         880          15           1505         20           878        11            521             9              95               1                   
Puzzling                       4043         698          17.26440762  708          135          12           433          43           74         7             55              4              11               0                   
Robotics                       1067         180          16.86972821  192          14           1            35           1            50         11            32              2              61               3                   
Board & Card Games             1555         262          16.8488746   292          133          12           45           1            44         6             33              3              37               4                   
Engineering                    2751         458          16.64849146  463          19           0            129          3            162        17            132             5              21               0                   
Literature                     841          140          16.64684899  142          11           0            77           6            15         3             23              3              16               0                   
Reverse Engineering            1437         235          16.35351427  241          15           1            109          1            70         0             37              0              10               0                   
Ask Different                  14028        2294         16.35300827  2458         884          61           621          55           635        132           223             39             95               11                  
Bicycles                       1916         301          15.70981211  316          101          1            125          5            55         2             18              1              17               0                   
Unix & Linux                   30934        4817         15.57186268  5077         1540         64           995          16           1575       56            767             17             200              7                   
Game Development               5735         892          15.55361813  957          158          4            462          23           98         7             169             10             70               3                   
Quantitative Finance           3312         515          15.54951691  523          55           0            261          5            112        2             64              3              31               0                   
Stack Overflow на русском      78086        12057        15.44066798  12479        1798         45           5128         188          3497       88            1107            29             949              7                   
Mathematics                    206635       31674        15.32847775  34162        8776         230          20595        611          4043       146           484             14             264              6                   
Open Source                    676          103          15.23668639  103          32           0            48           1            13         0             3               0              7                0                   
Law                            4722         715          15.14188903  747          104          3            418          19           113        7             89              5              23               2                   
Graphic Design                 5966         896          15.01843781  929          225          5            346          7            134        7             172             3              52               1                   
Signal Processing              4095         594          14.50549451  601          49           1            204          3            212        9             121             1              15               0                   
Martial Arts                   229          33           14.41048035  38           9            0            13           0            6          0             3               0              7                0                   
Stack Overflow en español      49704        7127         14.33888621  7478         819          13           2585         101          1508       42            1462            28             1104             15                  
Ask Patents                    398          57           14.32160804  57           8            0            44           2            5          0             0               0              0                0                   
TeX - LaTeX                    25433        3582         14.08406401  4137         1864         91           1090         27           969        25            156             13             58               2                   
English Language Learners      16793        2306         13.73191211  2415         356          10           1561         108          203        17            166             8              129              1                   
Sustainable Living             236          32           13.55932203  35           6            0            11           0            7          0             9               0              2                0                   
Data Science                   11298        1503         13.30323951  1525         54           0            581          3            328        16            477             6              85               0                   
The Great Outdoors             592          78           13.17567568  80           22           2            31           3            11         1             9               4              7                0                   
Spanish Language               1109         146          13.16501353  151          66           2            60           6            15         0             7               0              3                0                   
Space Exploration              2909         375          12.89102784  383          124          7            119          21           60         9             52              8              28               4                   
Ethereum                       6134         789          12.86273231  834          212          1            217          1            232        3             137             0              36               1                   
Retrocomputing                 944          119          12.6059322   123          14           2            52           9            20         6             25              3              12               1                   
Blender                        19177        2389         12.45763154  2526         1431         51           448          8            388        25            130             6              129              0                   
Computational Science          1338         164          12.25710015  204          11           0            107          2            74         0             12              0              0                0                   
Raspberry Pi                   5969         731          12.24660747  780          113          1            267          4            248        34            122             4              30               1                   
Stack Overflow                 2717332      320314       11.78781246  340072       138952       5401         79169        1643         44058      1342          67314           1152           10579            150                 
Mythology & Folklore           237          27           11.39240506  28           5            0            11           0            3          0             7               0              2                0                   
History of Science and Mathema 508          57           11.22047244  57           14           0            26           1            8          0             5               0              4                0                   
Quantum Computing              1518         170          11.19894598  178          33           2            34           4            65         12            29              5              13               3                   
3D Printing                    1078         118          10.94619666  121          35           5            39           1            30         5             8               0              9                0                   
French Language                1731         183          10.57192374  185          70           2            62           4            19         4             22              1              12               1                   
Monero                         565          58           10.26548673  63           54           0            5            0            2          0             1               0              1                0                   
Buddhism                       1069         108          10.10289991  109          26           4            33           2            30         7             3               1              17               0                   
Open Data                      730          72           9.863013699  80           30           2            35           3            15         0             0               0              0                0                   
Amateur Radio                  995          98           9.849246231  99           15           1            37           6            28         8             11              2              8                8                   
Русский язык                   3179         307          9.657124882  318          48           1            143          6            68         7             25              3              34               1                   
Ebooks                         173          16           9.248554913  16           1            0            13           0            1          0             0               0              1                0                   
Motor Vehicles                 3979         337          8.46946469   349          61           0            120          3            98         1             34              1              36               0                   
Tezos                          907          76           8.379272326  76           30           1            12           0            12         1             19              0              3                0                   
Artificial Intelligence        3179         259          8.147216106  280          31           0            161          4            46         5             35              1              7                0                   
Vi and Vim                     1771         143          8.074534161  152          77           1            43           1            22         1             8               0              2                0                   
Operations Research            657          53           8.066971081  53           8            1            19           5            6          2             14              6              6                4                   
Tor                            803          64           7.97011208   81           29           0            13           0            37         0             2               0              0                0                   
Iota                           88           7            7.954545455  7            0            0            1            0            3          0             3               0              0                0                   
Woodworking                    430          34           7.906976744  35           8            0            14           1            5          1             8               0              0                0                   
elementary OS                  1575         124          7.873015873  343          93           4            225          11           17         0             6               0              2                0                   
Expatriates                    1214         94           7.742998353  99           22           0            21           0            23         1             16              0              17               0                   
Stellar                        456          35           7.675438596  36           11           0            9            2            7          0             7               1              2                0                   
Bricks                         482          36           7.468879668  38           17           0            8            0            5          0             7               0              1                0                   
Ukrainian Language             264          19           7.196969697  19           1            0            7            0            5          1             6               2              0                0                   
Joomla                         713          50           7.012622721  69           11           0            22           2            14         0             20              2              2                0                   
Portuguese Language            236          16           6.779661017  16           4            0            7            0            2          1             3               0              0                0                   
Home Improvement               9539         627          6.573016039  696          110          3            395          2            89         1             64              0              38               0                   
Bioinformatics                 1078         69           6.400742115  70           8            1            23           0            11         0             22              1              6                0                   
Chinese Language               1238         79           6.381260097  83           17           1            59           0            7          2             0               0              0                0                   
Computer Graphics              597          37           6.197654941  37           0            0            25           0            10         1             1               0              1                0                   
EOS.IO                         751          46           6.125166445  57           37           0            11           0            5          0             2               0              2                0                   
SharePoint                     8594         522          6.07400512   556          44           1            186          1            220        17            86              7              20               0                   
Emacs                          3380         180          5.325443787  205          95           4            36           1            48         8             21              3              5                0                   
Coffee                         137          7            5.109489051  7            2            0            2            0            2          0             0               0              1                0                   
Italian Language               512          25           4.8828125    25           11           2            10           1            2          0             0               0              2                0                   
Magento                        20532        937          4.563608026  993          212          10           311          6            268        13            159             7              43               3                   
Video Production               1388         60           4.322766571  64           10           0            30           0            7          0             12              0              5                0                   
Gardening & Landscaping        2153         88           4.087320019  91           11           0            39           2            25         3             13              3              3                1                   
Latin Language                 859          33           3.841676368  34           8            0            15           0            7          0             3               0              1                0                   
スタック・オーバーフロー          4993         168          3.364710595  170          18           0            84           14           46         3             16              0              6                0                   
Korean Language                240          8            3.333333333  8            1            0            2            0            4          0             0               0              1                0                   
CS50                           1119         35           3.127792672  41           18           1            7            0            12         1             2               0              2                0                   
Esperanto Language             171          5            2.923976608  5            2            0            1            0            0          0             0               0              2                1                   
Homebrewing                    265          7            2.641509434  10           5            0            4            0            1          0             0               0              0                0                   
Augur                          43           1            2.325581395  1            0            0            1            0            0          0             0               0              0                0                   
ExpressionEngine® Answers      404          8            1.98019802   8            0            0            6            0            2          0             0               0              0                0                   
Craft CMS                      1762         22           1.248581158  22           6            0            11           0            3          0             2               0              0                0                   
CiviCRM                        2064         22           1.065891473  23           18           0            3            0            2          0             0               0              0                0                   
Tridion                        434          1            0.2304147465 1            1            1            0            0            0          0             0               0              0                0
```

Data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T2X7kdeYgil2hd_LBqdXz4DVqn5kub5lmk4s8CM1ZLU/edit?usp=sharing (same as in [2019: a year in closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341507/178179)).

[Rob](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/282094/rob) also pointed to previous years:

- [2018: a year in closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321318/178179)
- [2016: a year in closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289797/178179)