# Who is handling Very Low Quality flags?

Tags: support, review, flags, low-quality-posts

If I flag a post as Very Low Quality, how it is determined who will handle it?

From what I've noticed, sometimes they land in Low Quality Queue, but sometimes they are handled by moderators.

Is it, for example, a given amount of time, in which the moderator can take care of the flag, and otherwise they will land in review queue? I've noticed, too, that Low Quality Rewiev Queue is populated in batches...

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190639/189840

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Moderators can *always* handle them from the flags queue, whether they're in the Low Quality Posts queue or not.

Flags are only pushed to the queue when:

- The flag has been active for at least 15 minutes.
- The post has not been through the queue previously.
- It is not an accepted answer.

Review items are disputed and require moderator intervention if:

- The post has a positive score but receives delete votes.
- The post gets more recommend delete responses than looks goods responses.
- The post is subsequently undeleted by its author.

Also keep in mind that VLQ flags get automatically dismissed if someone edits the post, or the post gets closed.

Comment: Is this somewhere in the FAQ or Help Center? I was flipping through both trying to make an answer of my own and didn't see this.

Comment: Well, I'm a moderator, so I see exactly all the things that get left behind for us to handle. The 15-minute thing is a general rule that applies to the population of all queues.

Comment: @DennisMeng The innards of the mod tooling isn't really faq-worthy, mostly because the mod tools are such a moving target to document. The best take away would be, stuff gets in front of them any time the system detects that the community has reached a point of contention, or failed to act entirely, etc.

Comment: @TimPost Sure. (I was asking mostly about the stuff that wasn't moderator-specific though)

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, VLQ flags by default go to the review queue. If the same post is flagged again, it goes to the moderators' flag queue.

Also, if the flag is disputed (has several "looks good" and several "delete" or "recommend deletion" votes, it also goes to the moderators' queue.